# ¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

El objetivo de la pregunta es tener una o varias respuestas bien elaboradas que sirvan como referencia cuando se esté usando la extensión `mysql_*` en el código.

Respondiendo a preguntas aquí en Stackoverflow me sorprendo de la cantidad de usuarios que siguen manteniendo código que incluye la API o extensión `mysql_*` para manejar las datos, a pesar de que en el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php) dice lo siguiente:

> Esta extensión está obsoleta a partir de PHP 5.5.0, por lo que ha sido
>   eliminada a partir de PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar, se debería utilizar la
>   extensión [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) o [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Véase también la Información general de
>   la API de MySQL para obtener ayuda al elegir una API de MySQL.

Eso significa que las funciones:

- `mysql_result`
- `mysql_select_db`
- `mysql_num_rows`
- `mysql_connect`
- `mysql_db_query`
- `mysql_fetch_assoc`
- `mysql_*... todas las que empiecen así ...`.

Todas estas funciones, y muchas otras [enumeradas aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysql.php), deberían evitarse.

Para colmo de males, las funciones son casi *idénticas* a aquellas de la extensión `mysqli`, las cuales sí son recomendables junto con PDO. La única diferencia entre las funciones obsoletas listadas más arriba y las de MySQLi, es la letra `i` antes del guión bajo `_` .

Entonces la pregunta es la siguiente: **¿Cuáles son los principales motivos graves por los que debería dejar de usar la extensión `mysql_*` para consultar mis datos?**

PD: Estoy dispuesto a recompensar una o varias buenas respuestas.

Comment: Simple, Inyección SQL, no es necesario hacer todo un ensayo sobre el porque

Comment: Ojo. Si se usan las funcionas `mysqli_*` de la misma forma que se usan las `mysql_*` son exactamente igual de peligrosas. Considerar que el código es más seguro simplemente por usar `mysqli_*` o `PDO` es un grave error.

Comment: Exacto @AlvaroMontoro y lo mismo ocurre si se usa PDO como un simple _ayudante_. Todo ello sería tema interesante para una buena respuesta, al menos eso creo. El caso de PDO mal usado [está ampliamente explicado aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967).

Comment: El caso de PHP es sangrante, un porcentaje considerable de preguntas PHP+MySQL en esSO tienen ese problema... pero no es el único: las preguntas con graves problemas de seguridad y en concreto inyección SQL por usar sentencias dinámicas en otros lenguajes no se queda muy atrás.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Los principales inconvenientes de las funciones `mysql_*`:

1. **Son inseguras por naturaleza**: no se pueden usar sentencias preparadas, sólo se pueden crear sentencias SQL dinámicas (concatenando cadenas), lo que abre la puerta a la inyección SQL. Habrá usuarios que digan que usando `mysql_real_escape_sting`, `addslashes` o `htmlspecialchars` se soluciona ese problema, pero se ha probado que pueden fallar en algunos casos (p.e. con [juegos de caracteres diferentes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/3695983) o con [ciertos valores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/3695983)).
2. **Son propensas a errores**: al generarse las sentencias SQL concatenando cadenas, es fácil equivocarse al escribirlas (p.e. abrir unas comillas y olvidarse de cerrarlas) lo que llevará a errores en la base de datos y a perder tiempo depurando.
3. **Van a dejar de funcionar**: como pones en la pregunta y debido a los puntos anteriores, se consideran obsoletas a partir de la versión 5.5 de PHP y dejarán de funcionar completamente en la versión de PHP7.
4. **No están orientadas a objetos**: esto realmente no es un problema para justificar su eliminación, pero más un inconveniente a la hora de programar. `MySQLi` tiene modo procedimental y modo orientado a objetos y `PDO` es orientado a objetos.

---

Y ahora una advertencia que ponía en los comentarios: si se usan las funciones `MySQLi` o `PDO` de la misma forma que se usan las `mysql_*` (concatenando cadenas) son exactamente igual de peligrosas. Hay que usar las herramientas correctamente (sentencias preparadas) para que sean seguras. Considerar que el código es más seguro simplemente por usar `MySQLi` o `PDO` es un grave error.

Resumiendo: **La gran ventaja de `mysqli_*` y `PDO` es que se pueden usar sentencias preparadas o parametrizadas**. Gracias a éstas se pasa la complejidad y responsabilidad a la base de datos en sí... pero no deja de ser la responsabilidad del desarrollador usar esas herramientas correctamente.

Answer (score 10):

Como complemento a la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro, quisiera mostrar las dos posibilidades de conexión que ofrece PHP basada en la API `mysqli` y en la clase PDO.

Cualquiera de ellas es válida al momento de tener que migrar de `mysql_` (obligatorio a partir de PHP 7).

## 1. mysqli

Tiene **dos estilos** de código. El estilo *orientado a objetos*, que es más claro y más moderno y el *estilo procedural*, que es más largo, más verboso, produciendo código más difícil de leer en consecuencia<sup>1</sup>.

Cualquiera de los dos estilos es válido, pero no se recomienda mezclar estilos.

Veamos ahora la forma de conectar usando los dos estilos.

### *a. Conexión a mysqli con estilo orientado a objetos (recomendado)*

[`mysqli` es una clase](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), por eso se puede usar con el estilo orientado a objetos. En ese caso se usa `new`, como en todas las clases. El constructor admite cuatro parámetros:

1. El host
2. El nombre de usuario
3. La constraseña
4. El nombre de la base de datos <sup>2</sup>

Haciendo simplemente esto, ya tendremos un objeto de conexión disponible para interactuar con la base de datos:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "password", "basedatos");
```

> **Recomendaciones:**
>
> 1. Muchas veces, cuando nuestros datos tienen acentos, `ñ` o caracteres especiales, los datos vienen deformados, con
>    codificación extraña o con el caracter inspector. Para evitar esto a
>    nivel de la conexión conviene, una vez creado el objeto, establecer un
>    charset adecuado, esto se hace mediante el uso de [`set_charset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php), una
>    vez creada la conexión:
>
>    ```
>     $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
>    ```
> 2. Podría ser interesante, para evitar conectar donde quiera que necesitemos acceder a la base de datos, crear una clase que gestione nuestra conexión.

Ya sólo nos queda usar nuestro objeto `$mysqli` donde lo necesitemos.

---

### *b. Conexión a mysqli con estilo procedural (no recomendado)*

---

**IMPORTANTE**: Aunque el estilo procedural está muy extendido, y el Manual de PHP muestra siempre ejemplos también en este estilo (aunque en último término), **debería evitarse programar en este estilo**. El mismo es más verboso y menos claro que el estilo orientado a objetos y aparte de eso, algunas de sus funciones, incluyendo a `mysqli_connect`, están en una [lista de funciones obsoletas, desde PHP 5](https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php5/en/ref.mysqli).

No obstante, muestro la forma de conectar.

---

La conexión es casi idéntica al estilo orientado a objetos, con los mismos cuatro parámetros:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'password', 'basedatos');
```

En la conexión se nota poco la *verbosidad* referida anteriormente. El asunto se nota cuando empezamos a usar las funciones, sobre todo cuando hay que trabajar con consultas preparadas y usar los métodos de binding..., etc.

Veamos ahora el asunto del charset:

```
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
```

Listo, ahora sólo nos queda usar `$mysqli`.

---

## 2. PDO

PDO sólo tiene estilo orientado a objetos. Una de las grandes ventajas de PDO es que casi con el mismo código, cambiando solamente el DSN y las credenciales de conexión, podemos cambiar de manejador de base de datos (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql...)  sin cambiar nada más en todo el código interno que consulta los datos en los diferentes puntos de una aplicación (a no ser que la forma de escribir las consultas varíe, en cuyo caso debemos escribirlas conforme al manejador de base de datos correspodiente).

Igual que lo indicado en (A), la conexión a PDO se crea con `new`, porque [PDO también es una clase](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). Pero el constructor de PDO es más completo y admite varios parámetros interesantes:

1. El DSN. Son las iniciales de *Data Source Name* (Nombre de Origen de Datos). En general, el DSN consiste en el nombre del controlador de PDO, seguido por dos puntos, seguido por la sintaxis específica del controlador de PDO para la conexión. En esa información suele ir el nombre de la base de datos, el host y también podemos poner el charset. Eso lo veremos más adelante.
2. El nombre e usuario.
3. La contraseña
4. Un array de opciones. Esto es interesante y novedoso. La configuración de PDO es algo delicada en algunos aspectos por lo que conviene saber usar este cuarto parámetro.

Veamos entonces cómo se crea la conexión. Usaremos variables para mayor claridad.

La conexión más simple que existe sería esta, y es la que muestra el Manual de PHP:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$usr = 'usuario_bd';
$pwd = 'password_bd';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Como se puede ver, la conexión se maneja dentro de un bloque `try ... catch`, porque cualquier fallo al invocar `new PDO()` levantaría una excepción que rompería el código. Por eso hay que capturar las excepciones.

**PERO** este código básico tiene varios problemas, así que conviene mejorarlo. PDO es genial, pero tiene algunos inconvenientes que hay que resolver en la configuración:

1. Si dejamos el código como está más arriba. Esta línea es problemática: `echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();`  Pues al invocar a `$e->getMessage()`, ante una excepción PDO estaría revelando las credenciales de conexión, contraseña incluida. Y eso podría quedar escrito en el log de errores, que es uno de los archivos favoritos de los hackers... No hay que alarmarse, vamos a solventar eso más adelante.
2. PDO trae por defecto las preparaciones emuladas encendidas. En algunos escenarios un hacker podría recurrir a ellas para colarnos una *Inyección SQL*, por lo que conviene apagar dicha opción.

Visto eso, podemos pasar a mejorar nuestra conexión. Los cambios son los siguientes:

1. En `$dsn` vamos a indicar el charset. A diferencia de `mysqli`, no tenemos que usar una función aparte para esto. Lo podemos pasar como un dato más del DSN.
2. Vamos a crear un array `$options` con todas las configuraciones que querramos para la conexión. Dado que PDO tiene métodos `setAttribute` para modificar su configuración, muchos usuarios crean primero la conexión y luego la modifican con esos métodos. Desde el punto de vista del rendimiento es mucho mejor crear la conexión ya configurada con todo lo que querramos en vez de modificarla una vez creada con `setAttributes`. Precisamente para eso PDO admite ese cuarto parámetro de opciones.
3. En el `catch` evitaremos hacer público mensajes de error internos. De todos modos, con respecto a la contraseña, conviene usar siempre una contraseña larga de entre 30 y 50 caracteres. De modo que si ésta se revela por descuido en algún log de errores o en la pantalla, al ser larga, ésta quedaría truncada.

Conexión mejorada:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8';
$usr = 'usuario_bd';
$pwd = 'password_bd';

$options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
);

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $errMsg='Falló la conexión. Revise las credenciales (u otro mensaje)';
    #Puedes hacer echo de un error personalizado
    echo $errMsg;
    #y/o escribirlo en el log de errores
    error_log($errMsg);
    #Aquí puedes optar también por escribir $e->getMessage() en un archivo protegido        
}
```

Ya sólo nos queda usar nuestro objeto `$pdo`.

Como recomendamos en (1). Conviene gestionar la conexión a PDO en una clase, la cual invocaremos cada vez que necesitemos conectar.

---

### Enlaces

- [Página de mysqli en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)
- [Página de PDO en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php)

---

### Notas

1. A título personal, recomiendo usar el estilo orientado a objetos
2. Esta es una novedad importante con respecto a la vieja `mysql_` en la cual este parámetro no existe. En los viejos manuales se repandió el uso de `mysql_select_db()`  después de conectar y muchos usuarios continúan esta práctica innecesaria al migrar a la nueva `mysqli`