# ¿como insertar varios datos al mismo tiempo en mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero insertar varios valores al mismo tiempo en una tabla mysq, tengo dos INSERT'S pero solo funciona el primero (formatod), el otro esta constituido por un ciclo for porque se inserta tres veces pero no funciona(pedidos) este es el codigo php:

```
<?php
//conectamos con el servidor
    $conectar= mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    //verificamos la conexion
    if(!$conectar){
        echo"No se pudo conectar con el servidor";

    }else{

$base=mysql_select_db('direccion');
    if(!$base){
        echo"No se encontro la base de datos";

    }

    }
//recuperar las variables

    $area=$_POST['area'];
    $numerointerno=$_POST['numerointerno'];
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
    $folio=$_POST['folio'];
    $partida=$_POST['partida'];
    $pedidos=$_POST['pedidos'];
    $concargo=$_POST['concargo'];
    $lote1=$_POST['lote'];
    $cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
    $unidad=$_POST['unidad'];
    $conceptos=$_POST['conceptos'];
    $costo=$_POST['costo'];


//hacemos la sentencia de sql
    $sql="INSERT INTO formatod   VALUES('$area','$numerointerno','$fecha','$folio','$partida','$pedidos','$concargo')";

    $sql1="INSERT INTO pedidos (lote,cantidad,unidad,conceptos,costo) VALUES";


for ($i = 0; $i < count($lote1); $i++){
    $sql1.="('".$lote1[$i]."','".$cantidad[$i]."','".$unidad[$i]."','".$conceptos[$i]."','".$costo[$i]."'),";

    echo "<center><strong><h4>Â¡INSERCIÃ“N EXITOSA!<br><a href='table.php'></a></strong></h4></center>";

}

?>
```

ojala me puedan ayudar

Comment: Creo que una primera ayuda sería decirte que estás usando código obsoleto, y que si sigues con él ocurrirán varias cosas. 1. Tus datos correrán peligro de [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967), 2. Tu código no funcionará en PHP versión 7, y otras más. Te recomiendo que leas esto: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_.* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967) y que pases a PDO o a mysqli, que no es lo mismo que mysql **sin la i al final**.

Comment: ok gracias por el consejo, la verdad estoy aprendiendo. :)

Comment: Si te interesa puedes probar [esta clase: PHP-PDO](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO), que maneja las conexiones usando PDO de forma segura. Una vez configurada, es muy fácil de usar, como se muestra en los ejemplos.

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias formas de introducir datos

**PDO**

Para introducir datos en una base de datos, primero hay que tener en cuenta que tiene un proceso:

```
$sentencia = $mbd->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$sentencia->bindParam(':name', $nombre);
$sentencia->bindParam(':value', $valor);

// insertar una fila
$nombre = 'uno';
$valor = 1;
$sentencia->execute();

// insertar otra fila con diferentes valores
$nombre = 'dos';
$valor = 2;
$sentencia->execute();
```

[Fuente](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

**Cosas a tener en cuenta**

1. Si te fijas , en el código de arriba , primero inserta la consulta mysql , con `:nombreVariable` , en el prepare , donde prepara la sentencia PHP , para adjuntarle a cada `:valor` su correspondiente valor con el `bindParam`.
2. Asigna los valores.
3. Realiza el execute.

Comentar que bindParam , tiene los parámetros de `bindParam(':nombre`,$nombre);` siendo el primero el que defines en la sentencia mysql y el segundo el que defines en la variable.

**Clásica**

Lo que haces tu, lo haces de forma correcta :

```
$consulta = "insert into tabla_d value (a,b,c,d)";

for($x = 0 ; $x <= 3 ; $x++){
  $sql.= "(a,b,c,d),"
  if($x == 3){
     $sql.= "(a,b,c,d);"
  }
}
```

Solución :

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO pedidos (lote,cantidad,unidad,conceptos,costo) VALUES";


for ($i = 0; $i < count($lote1); $i++){
   if(($i+1) == count($lote1)){
    $sql1.="('".$lote1[$i]."','".$cantidad[$i]."','".$unidad[$i]."','".$conceptos[$i]."','".$costo[$i]."');";

   }else{
    $sql1.="('".$lote1[$i]."','".$cantidad[$i]."','".$unidad[$i]."','".$conceptos[$i]."','".$costo[$i]."'),";

   }
}
    echo "<center><strong><h4>Â¡INSERCIÃ“N EXITOSA!<br><a href='table.php'></a></strong></h4></center>";
```

La cuestión que yo miro , el `;` que no pones al final no te termina la consulta , lógicamente esto lo hice sin ponerme a comprobarlo , pero creo que sirve para que te guíes.

Por cierto : **Curiosidad**

Insertar varios datos a la vez en la misma tabla con mysql y php, no es posible, porque ya Mysql controla que no se edite exactamente los datos a la vez , nos abstrae de problemas en la base de datos en temas de consistencia de los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar hacerlo algo así:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lote1); $i++){
$sql1="INSERT INTO pedidos (lote,cantidad,unidad,conceptos,costo) VALUES '".$lote1[$i]."','".$cantidad[$i]."','".$unidad[$i]."','".$conceptos[$i]."','".$costo[$i]."')";
}
```

Y recuerda la ejecución de tu query debe de ir dentro de `for` para que se aplique en cada iteración.

Como ya te mencionaron no es una buena practica utilizar la **API mysql** cuando el mismo **PHP** en su documentación la marca como obsoleta e insegura, deberias de utilizar lo que marca **PHP** como activo y recomendable.

Comment: gracias lo intentare

Comment: Al menos indica que ese código es vulnerable. No sé cómo algunos son capaces de responder a problemas con otro problema mayor. Construir consultas de la manera en que muestras en la respuesta  es una **pésima práctica**.

Comment: Creo que tienes razón hasta cierto punto, pero igual ya queda a criterio de quien lo consulta, por eso es que se contesta en base a lo que se esta preguntando.

Comment: Es gracias a esas respuestas que el código erróneo, obsoleto y peligroso sigue propagándose en la red. Aparte de que en realidad el problema no queda resuelto... lo veremos cuando el OP pase a PHP 7 o cuando, en el peor de los casos, sea víctima de una Inyección SQL que borre todas las tablas de su BD. Hacer funcionar un código peligroso más que una solución es responder a un problema con otro problema mayor. Es mi opinión, en lo particular.

Comment: Como norma, **nunca** escribiría en ninguna respuesta una consulta como esta: `$sql1="INSERT INTO pedidos (lote,cantidad,unidad,conceptos,costo) VALUES '".$lote1[$i]."','".$cantidad[$i]."','".$unidad[$i]."','".$conceptos[$i]."','".$costo[$i]."')";` o parecida. Para eso existen las consultas preparadas.