# Codigo Php no inserta datos

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes tengo este codigo php para un formulario el cual graba el campo clientes pero no el ingreso de inspeccion. Gracias de antemano con la ayuda...

```
if ($cod_asegurado == "1"){
    echo "Valido, sigue tu camino";
    $insertar_clientes = ("INSERT INTO clientes(id_cliente,asegurado,rut,dv_rut,telefono_uno,telefono_dos,email_cliente,direccion_comercial,persona_contacto,giro_actividad,jornada_laboral,num_empleados,relacion_laboral,otras_ubicaciones,id_cia) VALUES (NULL,'$asegurado','$rut','$dv_rut','$telefono_uno','$telefono_dos','$email_cliente','$direccion_comercial','$persona_contacto','$giro_actividad','$jornada_laboral','$num_empleados','$relacion_laboral','$otras_ubicaciones','$cia')");
    $insertar_cliente_s = mysql_query($insertar_clientes,$conexion);
    //recibo el último id
    $cod_asegurado = mysql_insert_id($conexion);    
} else {
    $insertar_clientes = ("UPDATE clientes SET asegurado='$asegurado',rut='$rut',dv_rut='$dv_rut',telefono_uno='$telefono_uno',telefono_dos='$telefono_dos',email_cliente=$'email_cliente',direccion_comercial='$direccion_comercial',persona_contacto='$persona_contacto',giro_actividad='$giro_actividad',jornada_laboral='$jornada_laboral',num_empleados='$num_empleados',relacion_laboral='$relacion_laboral',otras_ubicaciones='$otras_ubicaciones',id_cia='$cia' WHERE id_cliente='$cod_asegurado'");
    $insertar_cliente_s = mysql_query($insertar_clientes,$conexion);
}

$incertara = ("INSERT INTO inspeccion(id_inspeccion,num_solicitud,num_propuesta,direccion_riesgo,regiones,provincias,ciudades,comunas,motivo_inspec,tipo_siniestros,fecha_solicitud,id_cia) VALUES (NULL,'$num_solicitud','$num_propuesta','$direccion_riesgo','$cod_region','$cod_provincia','$cod_comuna','$cod_localidad,'$tipo_prog_mantencion','$tipo_siniestros','$fecha_solicitud','$cia')");
$insert = mysql_query($incertara,$conexion);
```

Comment: Hola Francisco, te invito a que te des el [tour], lees la sección [ask] y luego de ello podrás [edit] tu pregunta para que sea más legible, saludos

Comment: Jorius muchas gracias por la correcion

Comment: Soy daltónico pero podría jurar que $insert tiene otro color?  no será una palabra reservada del lenguaje y por eso genera problemas?

Comment: Creo que no te esta insertando porque estas enviando NULL al id_inspeccion, lo cual imagino es tu llave primaria

Comment: Por otro lado,`mysql_query` fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL.Consulta el manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise tu pregunta y es muy probable que esta no este ingresando datos porque a `cod_localidad` le falta las comillas para cerrar `'cod_localidad'`, tambien borre el campo `id_inspeccion` ya que no es necesario que lo declares para asignarle null, este debe ser un int auto incrementable a continuación dejo el código con la consulta para que pueda ser ingresada sin errores:

```
if ($cod_asegurado == "1"){
    echo "Valido, sigue tu camino";
    $insertar_clientes = ("INSERT INTO clientes(id_cliente,asegurado,rut,dv_rut,telefono_uno,telefono_dos,email_cliente,direccion_comercial,persona_contacto,giro_actividad,jornada_laboral,num_empleados,relacion_laboral,otras_ubicaciones,id_cia) VALUES (NULL,'$asegurado','$rut','$dv_rut','$telefono_uno','$telefono_dos','$email_cliente','$direccion_comercial','$persona_contacto','$giro_actividad','$jornada_laboral','$num_empleados','$relacion_laboral','$otras_ubicaciones','$cia')");
    $insertar_cliente_s = mysql_query($insertar_clientes,$conexion);
    //recibo el último id
    $cod_asegurado = mysql_insert_id($conexion);    
} else {
    $insertar_clientes = ("UPDATE clientes SET asegurado='$asegurado',rut='$rut',dv_rut='$dv_rut',telefono_uno='$telefono_uno',telefono_dos='$telefono_dos',email_cliente=$'email_cliente',direccion_comercial='$direccion_comercial',persona_contacto='$persona_contacto',giro_actividad='$giro_actividad',jornada_laboral='$jornada_laboral',num_empleados='$num_empleados',relacion_laboral='$relacion_laboral',otras_ubicaciones='$otras_ubicaciones',id_cia='$cia' WHERE id_cliente='$cod_asegurado'");
    $insertar_cliente_s = mysql_query($insertar_clientes,$conexion);
}
INSERT INTO inspeccion(num_solicitud,num_propuesta,direccion_riesgo,regiones,provincias,ciudades,comunas,motivo_inspec,tipo_siniestros,fecha_solicitud,id_cia) VALUES('$num_solicitud','$num_propuesta','$direccion_riesgo','$cod_region','$cod_provincia','$cod_comuna','$cod_localidad','$tipo_prog_mantencion','$tipo_siniestros','$fecha_solicitud','$cia');
```

Comment: No es necesario también cuando metes variables php en la cadena de texto del INSERT concatenar? -> $incertara = ("INSERT INTO inspe [...] VALUES (NULL, ' . $num_solicitud . ', ' . $num_propuesta . ' [...]?

Comment: probé el código y ese era el error después de solucionarlo funciono el insert, saludos!

Comment: 720TA podrias por favor mandar el codigo que probaste, ya que hice la correcion pero sigue sin grabar la inspeccion. Gracias

Comment: INSERT INTO inspeccion(num_solicitud,num_propuesta,direccion_riesgo,regiones,provincias,ciudades,comunas,motivo_inspec,tipo_siniestros,fecha_solicitud,id_cia) VALUES('$num_solicitud','$num_propuesta','$direccion_riesgo','$cod_region','$cod_provincia','$cod_comuna','$cod_localidad','$tipo_prog_mantencion','$tipo_siniestros','$fecha_solicitud','$cia');

Comment: Gracias por la respuestas fueron de mucha ayuda

Comment: puedes poner la respuesta como solución si esta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, saludos espero te adentres en la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

No estás creando el `INSERT` de forma correcta :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

[Fuente](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Si te fijas , solo estás escribiendo la primera parte :

```
INSERT INTO <tabla>(<campo1>,...,<campoN>)
```

No estás a poner acto seguido el :

```
INSERT INTO <tabla>(<campo1>,...,<campoN>) 
VALUES
  (<valor1>,...,<valorN>),// Primer insert
  (<valor1>,...,<valorN>),// Segundo insert
  (<valor1>,...,<valorN>),// Tercero insert
  (<valor1>,...,<valorN>),// Cuerto insert
  (<valor1>,...,<valorN>);// Ultimo insert
```

Todos los values si te fijas acaban en `,`, menos el último que para que se haga efectivo tienes que añadir un `;`. [Tengo aquí explicado de forma más extensa este punto.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79305/como-insertar-varios-datos-al-mismo-tiempo-en-mysql-y-php/79378#79378)