# PHP mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, pdo, while

Estoy intentando mostrar resultados de mi base de datos, no sabia como hasta que vi esta forma de hacerlo `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result) {  //Code }` y despues vi que usar esta forma es algo obsoleto, por lo que tendria que optar por usar `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { //Code }`. 
Mi problema es, que no entiendo como funciona el while: ¿En que momento deja de ser cierto? ¿Cuales son los datos que itera? En pocas palabras ¿Como funciona este código?

Comment: Te recomiendo que comiences buscando información de como realizar consultas por PDO y de hay se comenzaran a aclarar tus dudas

Comment: Intento dar una observación general a todas las respuestas y digo... ¿Habéis oído hablar de **fetchAll()**? Ya que hace justamente lo que pretendes/pretendéis.

Comment: Estas usando una función obsoleta de PHP que pone en riesgo tus datos y que ya no funciona en PHP 7. En cuanto cambies a esa versión tendrás parte de código no funcionando. Para más detalles puedes ver esta pregunta: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**¿En que momento deja de ser cierto?** 
El while es un bucle que mientras Existan rows en la consulta seguirá siendo cierto una vez que la consulta se queda sin datos el bucle termina... es muy sencillo.

**¿Cuales son los datos que itera?**
Depende de los que tu solicitas en tu consulta; el indice puede ser literal o numérico. y los leerá por lineas.

**¿Como funciona este código?**

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{#Mientrastenga registros devuelve true
    #lectura para la fila actual
    echo $row['indice Litera de columna'];
    echo '<br>'; #Salto de linea
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es:

```
- while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result) {  //Code } =  forma procedural
- while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { //Code } esto es POO
```

Que seria lo mismo ha `while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` en forma procedural

Lo que hace el `While`, es que ejecuta mientras la condición sea verdad.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, básicamente lo que hace esta línea:

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { //Code }
```

Es devolver los datos de cada registro que la consulta que hiciste previamente obtuvo.

El ciclo While se detiene una vez el fetch deja enviar datos.

Podes acceder a lo datos de la siguiente manera

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
//usa este si estas obteniendo los datos en forma de objeto 
echo $row->nombredelcampo;
//usa este si estas obteniendo los datos en una matriz
echo $row["nombredelcampo"];
 }
```

P.d. remplaza "nombredelcampo" por los nombres de los campos que deseas manipular de tu tabla.

Answer (score 1):

A mi parecer y criterio, la forma más sencilla de consultar una tabla en la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=database", "admin", "12345");
$connection -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connection -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$age = 18;

$stmt = $connection -> prepare("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE AGE = :age");
$stmt -> bindParam(':age', $age);
$stmt -> execute();
$rows = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$stmt -> closeCursor();

foreach($rows as $user)
{
    echo $user -> NAME;
}

$connection = null;
```

Desde el punto de vista de seguridad y también desde el punto de vista de usar menos código y sea los más eficiente posible. Espero que sea de ayuda el código de arriba, si tienes alguna duda déjame un comentario y con gusto respondo.