# Cómo sumar los resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una página php en la que se muestra el nombre de un piloto en un eje y el número de veces que ha obtenido esa posición (entre primer puesto y tercero "<= 3"). Dejo la vista previa:
[vista previa página php](http://spark.byethost17.com/prem/?page=show_drivers)

El problema que tengo es que por cada equipo en el que haya estado o esté actualmente el piloto muestra una nueva fila repitiendo el nombre del piloto.

Por ejemplo el primer piloto "Inguni" se repite dos veces. Lo que pretendo conseguir es que sume en una única fila las veces que ha quedado primero, las veces que ha quedado segundo, las veces que ha quedado tercero.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
$sql_positions = "SELECT `team_driver`, `position` FROM race_driver WHERE `position` <= 3";
$exe_positions = mysql_query($sql_positions);
while ($positions = mysql_fetch_array($exe_positions)) {
    $position[$positions['team_driver']][$positions['position']]++;
}
mysql_free_result($exe_positions);

$sql_drivers = "SELECT `driver`.`id`, `driver`.`name`, `driver`.`driver_photo`, `team_driver`.`id` as teamDriverID FROM driver LEFT JOIN team_driver ON driver.id = team_driver.driver ORDER BY `driver`.`name` ASC";
$exe_drivers = mysql_query($sql_drivers);
if (!$exe_drivers) {
    show_error("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error() . "\n");
    return;
}

?>


<?

while ($sitem = mysql_fetch_array($exe_drivers)) {
    if ($sitem['driver_photo'] == '') { $url = 'images/helmet.png' ; } else { $url = $sitem['driver_photo']; } 
    $first_position = intval($position[$sitem['teamDriverID']][1]);
    $second_position = intval($position[$sitem['teamDriverID']][2]);
    $third_position = intval($position[$sitem['teamDriverID']][3]);
    ?>
    <tr class="w3-hover-green">
    <td><?= $sitem['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $first_position ?></td>
    <td><?= $second_position ?></td>
    <td><?= $third_position ?></td>
    <td><a><img src="<?=$url;?>" width="150" height="150"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?

}
mysql_free_result($exe_drivers);
?>
```

Estructura de las tablas:

driver

```
id  name   driver_photo
51  Flame   
50   InGuNi
```

team_driver

```
id  team    driver
82  19       51
75  17       50
```

race_driver

```
race    team_driver     grid    position    fastest_lap     laps    time    status
10            82          4           4           0          19     2478016      0
10            75          1           1           1          20     2335867     0
```

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Tú puedes obtener todos los datos en una sola consulta, juntando para ello tus tablas mediante `JOIN`, usando `SUM` para sumar y para que el piloto no se repita en cada línea, usas un `GROUP BY id_driver`. Quiero advertir que estás usando una función de mysql obsoleta, la cual pone seriamente en riesgo tus datos. Para más info: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)

Comment: @A.Cedano Conseguí agruparlos con el group by en `$sql_drivers`, pero no consigo hacer funcionar el `SUM`, entre otros probé con `$sql_positions = "SELECT `team_driver`, SUM(position)`

Las posicones las coge de `position` donde sean menor a 3, Luego en la columna de la tabla html  muestra `$first_position` los valores 1, y necesito no que sume, sino que haga un `COUNT` supongo que sería.
Así por ejemplo un piloto ha quedado 3 veces en posición 2 ha de mostrar 3 y no un 6 que es lo que daría sumando 2+2+2.

Comment: He añadido algunos valores a mi primer mensaje por si sirve de ayuda.

Lo de mysqli lo tengo pendiente, inicié el proyecto en github con un programador, pero ahora estoy solo y no encuentro colaboradores y yo no soy programador, he hecho muchas cosas pero lo que para un programador es media hora para mí son días. No sé tampoco dónde encontrar a alguien interesado en colaborar en un proyecto por hobby.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tu ha intentado utilizar DISTINCT?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `driver`.`id`, `driver`.`name`, `driver`.`driver_photo`, `team_driver`.`id` as teamDriverID FROM driver LEFT JOIN team_driver ON driver.id = team_driver.driver ORDER BY `driver`.`name` ASC"
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu aporte! En el sitio intentamos tener respuestas con la mayor calidad posible. La idea no es mostrar solamente un fragmento de código, sino además explicar por qué esto funcionaría. ¿Qué hace este código? ¿Por qué o cómo solucionaría el problema expuesto en la pregunta? En [answer] podrás leer algunos consejos. ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu respuesta agregando algo más de información?