# No guarda el registro en la BD - PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

El error básicamente radica en que no guarda la información el el servidor remoto, en local si realiza la consulta correctamente

No está ejecutando la consulta, utilizo consultas similares para cuando se cambia el registro de una tabla a otra el mismo inert y si lo hace, tambien para el registro de usuarios

[image: Validación en el lado del cliente de los datos requeridos]
[image: Validación en el lado del servidor y guardado]

Archivo del la validación y guardado en

```
<?php 
/*-------------------------
    Client Section
-------------------------*/
    //Folio
        @ $serialNumber = $_POST['serialNumber'];
    //Full cntract date
        @ $cDate = $_POST['cDate'];
    // Client information
        @ $fName = $_POST['fName'];
        @ $sName = $_POST['sName'];
        @ $lName = $_POST['lName'];
        @ $ifeNum = $_POST['ifeNum'];
        @ $hStreet = $_POST['hStreet'];
        @ $hNum = $_POST['hNum'];
        @ $hZip = $_POST['hZip'];
        @ $hSub = $_POST['hSub'];
        @ $hState = $_POST['hState'];
        @ $hCity = $_POST['hCity'];
        @ $pNum = $_POST['pNum'];
        @ $email = $_POST['email'];
        @ $dataForMkt = $_POST['dataForMkt'];
    // Co-owner informattion
        @ $coFName = $_POST['coFName'];
        @ $coSName = $_POST['coSName'];
        @ $coLName = $_POST['coLName'];
        @ $coHStreet = $_POST['coHStreet'];
        @ $coHNum = $_POST['coHNum'];
        @ $coHZip = $_POST['coHZip'];
        @ $coHSub = $_POST['coHSub'];
        @ $coHState = $_POST['coHState'];
        @ $coHCity = $_POST['coHCity'];
    // Beeneficiary information
        @ $beFName = $_POST['beFName'];
        @ $beSName = $_POST['beSName'];
        @ $beLName = $_POST['beLName'];
/*-------------------------
    Car Section
-------------------------*/
    // Car Status Information
        // Car Information
            @ $carBrand = $_POST['carBrand'];
            @ $carType = $_POST['carType'];
            @ $carVersion = $_POST['carVersion'];
            @ $carYear = $_POST['carYear'];
            @ $carCilinder = $_POST['carCilinder'];
            @ $carLiter = $_POST['carLiter'];
            @ $carGearBox = $_POST['carGearBox'];
            @ $carGearNum = $_POST['carGearNum'];
            @ $carColor = $_POST['carColor'];
            @ $carRof = $_POST['carRof'];
            @ $carOrigin = $_POST['carOrigin'];
            @ $carOwnerNum = $_POST['carOwnerNum'];
            @ $carSerie = $_POST['carSerie'];
            @ $carFacType = $_POST['carFacType'];
            @ $carFacNum = $_POST['carFacNum'];
            @ $carPayment = $_POST['carPayment'];
        // Right Side
            @ $carRBackBumper = $_POST['carRBackBumper'];
            @ $carRFuelCover = $_POST['carRFuelCover'];
            @ $carRBackTyre = $_POST['carRBackTyre'];
            @ $carRBackRin = $_POST['carRBackRin'];
            @ $carRBackDoorWindow = $_POST['carRBackDoorWindow'];
            @ $carRBackDoorHandle = $_POST['carRBackDoorHandle'];
            @ $carRBackDoor = $_POST['carRBackDoor'];
            @ $carRFrontDoorWindow = $_POST['carRFrontDoorWindow'];
            @ $carRFrontDoorHandle = $_POST['carRFrontDoorHandle'];
            @ $carRFrontDoor = $_POST['carRFrontDoor'];
            @ $carRRearMirror = $_POST['carRRearMirror'];
            @ $carRBlinker = $_POST['carRBlinker'];
            @ $carRFrontTyre = $_POST['carRFrontTyre'];
            @ $carRFrontRin = $_POST['carRFrontRin'];
            @ $carRFrontBumper = $_POST['carRFrontBumper'];
        // Front Side
            @ $carFWindow = $_POST['carFWindow'];
            @ $carFLeftWiper = $_POST['carFLeftWiper'];
            @ $carFRightWiper = $_POST['carFRightWiper'];
            @ $carFHood = $_POST['carFHood'];
            @ $carFLeftLight = $_POST['carFLeftLight'];
            @ $carFEmblem = $_POST['carFEmblem'];
            @ $carFGrate = $_POST['carFGrate'];
            @ $carFRightLight = $_POST['carFRightLight'];
            @ $carFLeftFogLight = $_POST['carFLeftFogLight'];
            @ $carFLicensePlate = $_POST['carFLicensePlate'];
            @ $carFRightFogLight = $_POST['carFRightFogLight'];
            @ $carFBumper = $_POST['carFBumper'];
        // Left Side
            @ $carLFrontBumper = $_POST['carLFrontBumper'];
            @ $carLFrontTyre = $_POST['carLFrontTyre'];
            @ $carLFrontRin = $_POST['carLFrontRin'];
            @ $carLBlinker = $_POST['carLBlinker'];
            @ $carLRearMirror = $_POST['carLRearMirror'];
            @ $carLFrontDoorWindow = $_POST['carLFrontDoorWindow'];
            @ $carLFrontDoorHandle = $_POST['carLFrontDoorHandle'];
            @ $carLFrontDoor = $_POST['carLFrontDoor'];
            @ $carLBackDoorWindow = $_POST['carLBackDoorWindow'];
            @ $carLBackDoorHandle = $_POST['carLBackDoorHandle'];
            @ $carLBackDoor = $_POST['carLBackDoor'];
            @ $carLFuelCover = $_POST['carLFuelCover'];
            @ $carLBackBumper = $_POST['carLBackBumper'];
            @ $carLBackTyre = $_POST['carLBackTyre'];
            @ $carLBackRin = $_POST['carLBackRin'];
        // Back Side
            @ $carBWindow = $_POST['carBWindow'];
            @ $carBLeftLight = $_POST['carBLeftLight'];
            @ $carBLeftEmblem = $_POST['carBLeftEmblem'];
            @ $carBTrunk = $_POST['carBTrunk'];
            @ $carBCenterEmblem = $_POST['carBCenterEmblem'];
            @ $carBTrunkHandle = $_POST['carBTrunkHandle'];
            @ $carBRightEmblem = $_POST['carBRightEmblem'];
            @ $carBRightLight = $_POST['carBRightLight'];
            @ $carBSecLeftLight = $_POST['carBSecLeftLight'];
            @ $carBPlate = $_POST['carBPlate'];
            @ $carBSecRightLight = $_POST['carBSecRightLight'];
            @ $carBLeftExhaust = $_POST['carBLeftExhaust'];
            @ $carBRightExhaust = $_POST['carBRightExhaust'];
            @ $carBBumper = $_POST['carBBumper'];
        // Top side
            @ $carTRoof = $_POST['carTRoof'];
            @ $carTSunRoof = $_POST['carTSunRoof'];
/*-------------------------
    Loan Section
-------------------------*/
    // Loan Information
        @ $appr = $_POST['appr'];
        @ $apprText = $_POST['apprText'];
        @ $loan = $_POST['loan'];
        @ $inter = $_POST['inter'];
        @ $term = $_POST['term'];
        @ $digs = $_POST['digs'];
        @ $startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
        @ $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];
        @ $tLimit = $_POST['tLimit'];


if(($fName != "") && ($sName != "") && ($lName != "") && ($ifeNum != "") && ($hStreet != "") && ($hNum != "") && ($hZip != "") && ($hSub != "") && ($hState != "") && ($hCity != "") && ($pNum != "") && ($email != "") && ($dataForMkt != "")){
    if(($carBrand != "") && ($carType != "") && ($carVersion != "") && ($carYear != "") && ($carCilinder != "") && ($carLiter != "") && ($carGearBox != "") && ($carGearNum != "") && ($carColor != "") && ($carRof != "") && ($carOrigin != "") && ($carOwnerNum != "" ) && ($carSerie != "") && ($carFacType != "") && ($carFacNum != "") && ($carPayment != "")){
        if(($appr != "") && ($apprText != "") && ($loan != "") && ($inter != "") && ($term != "") && ($digs != "") && ($startDate != "") && ($endDate != "") && ($tLimit != "")){

            //Data base connection
                require("connection.php");
            //Data base selection
                mysql_select_db("saedb");

            //Data for insert query
                //Client
                    //Id

                    //Folio
                        @ $iFolio = "serialNumber, ";
                    //Full date
                        @ $iCDate = "cDate, ";
                    //Client personal Info
                        @ $iPInfo = "fName, sName, lName, ifeNum, hStreet, hNum, hZip, hSub, hState, hCity, pNum, email, dataForMkt, ";
                    //Client Co-Owner Info
                        @ $iCInfo = "coFName, coSName, coLName, coHStreet, coHNum, coHZip, coHSub, coHState, coHCity, ";
                    //Client Beneficiary info
                        @ $iBInfo = "beFName, beSName, beLName, ";
                //Carinfo
                    //Car data
                        @ $iCarInfo = "carBrand, carType, carVersion, carYear, carCilinder, carLiter, carGearBox, carGearNum, carColor, carRof, carOrigin, carOwnerNum, carSerie, carFacType, carFacNum, carPayment, ";
                        //Car Right Side Status
                            @ $iRightSideInfo = "carRBackBumper, carRFuelCover, carRBackTyre, carRBackRin, carRBackDoorWindow, carRBackDoorHandle, carRBackDoor, carRFrontDoorWindow, carRFrontDoorHandle, carRFrontDoor, carRRearMirror, carRBlinker, carRFrontTyre, carRFrontRin, carRFrontBumper, ";
                        //Car Front Side Status
                            @ $iFrontSideInfo = "carFWindow, carFLeftWiper, carFRightWiper, carFHood, carFLeftLight, carFEmblem, carFGrate, carFRightLight, carFLeftFogLight, carFLicensePlate, carFRightFogLight, carFBumper, ";
                        //Car Left Side Status
                            @ $iLeftSideInfo = "carLFrontBumper, carLFrontTyre, carLFrontRin, carLBlinker, carLRearMirror, carLFrontDoorWindow, carLFrontDoorHandle, carLFrontDoor, carLBackDoorWindow, carLBackDoorHandle, carLBackDoor, carLFuelCover, carLBackBumper, carLBackTyre, carLBackRin, ";
                        //Car Back Side Status
                            @ $iBackSideInfo = "carBWindow, carBLeftLight, carBLeftEmblem, carBTrunk, carBCenterEmblem, carBTrunkHandle, carBRightEmblem, carBRightLight, carBSecLeftLight, carBPlate, carBSecRightLight, carBLeftExhaust, carBRightExhaust, carBBumper, ";
                        //Car Top Side Status
                            @ $iTopSideInfo = "carTRoof, carTSunRoof, ";
                //Loan Info
                    @ $iLoanInfo = "appr, apprText, loan, inter, term, digs, startDate, endDate, tLimit";
                //DB Fields for query
                    @ $iQDbFields = $iFolio . $iCDate . $iPInfo . $iCInfo . $iBInfo . $iCarInfo . $iRightSideInfo . $iFrontSideInfo . $iLeftSideInfo . $iBackSideInfo . $iTopSideInfo . $iLoanInfo;

            //Values To Insert
                //Client
                    //Folio
                        @ $vFolio = "'$serialNumber', ";
                    //Full date
                        @ $vCDate = "'$cDate', ";
                    //Client personal Info
                        @ $vPInfo = "'$fName', '$sName', '$lName', '$ifeNum', '$hStreet', '$hNum', '$hZip', '$hSub', '$hState', '$hCity', '$pNum', '$email', '$dataForMkt', ";
                    //Client Co-Owner Info
                        @ $vCInfo = "'$coFName', '$coSName', '$coLName', '$coHStreet', '$coHNum', '$coHZip', '$coHSub', '$coHState', '$coHCity', ";
                    //Client Beneficiary info
                        @ $vBInfo = "'$beFName', '$beSName', '$beLName', ";
                //Carinfo
                    //Car data
                        @ $vCarInfo = "'$carBrand', '$carType', '$carVersion', '$carYear', '$carCilinder', '$carLiter', '$carGearBox', '$carGearNum', '$carColor', '$carRof', '$carOrigin', '$carOwnerNum', '$carSerie', '$carFacType', '$carFacNum', '$carPayment', ";
                        //Car Right Side Status
                            @ $vRightSideInfo = "'$carRBackBumper', '$carRFuelCover', '$carRBackTyre', '$carRBackRin', '$carRBackDoorWindow', '$carRBackDoorHandle', '$carRBackDoor', '$carRFrontDoorWindow', '$carRFrontDoorHandle', '$carRFrontDoor', '$carRRearMirror', '$carRBlinker', '$carRFrontTyre', '$carRFrontRin', '$carRFrontBumper', ";
                        //Car Front Side Status
                            @ $vFrontSideInfo = "'$carFWindow', '$carFLeftWiper', '$carFRightWiper', '$carFHood', '$carFLeftLight', '$carFEmblem', '$carFGrate', '$carFRightLight', '$carFLeftFogLight', '$carFLicensePlate', '$carFRightFogLight', '$carFBumper', ";
                        //Car Left Side Status
                            @ $vLeftSideInfo = "'$carLFrontBumper', '$carLFrontTyre', '$carLFrontRin', '$carLBlinker', '$carLRearMirror', '$carLFrontDoorWindow', '$carLFrontDoorHandle', '$carLFrontDoor', '$carLBackDoorWindow', '$carLBackDoorHandle', '$carLBackDoor', '$carLFuelCover', '$carLBackBumper', '$carLBackTyre', '$carLBackRin', ";
                        //Car Back Side Status
                            @ $vBackSideInfo = "'$carBWindow', '$carBLeftLight', '$carBLeftEmblem', '$carBTrunk', '$carBCenterEmblem', '$carBTrunkHandle', '$carBRightEmblem', '$carBRightLight', '$carBSecLeftLight', '$carBPlate', '$carBSecRightLight', '$carBLeftExhaust', '$carBRightExhaust', '$carBBumper', ";
                        //Car Top Side Status
                            @ $vTopSideInfo = "'$carTRoof', '$carTSunRoof', ";
                //Loan Info
                    @ $vLoanInfo = "'$appr', '$apprText', '$loan', '$inter', '$term', '$digs', '$startDate', '$endDate', '$tLimit'";
                //Form Values for Query
                    @ $vQFrmValues = $vFolio . $vCDate . $vPInfo . $vCInfo . $vBInfo . $vCarInfo . $vRightSideInfo . $vFrontSideInfo . $vLeftSideInfo . $vBackSideInfo . $vTopSideInfo . $vLoanInfo;

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO loanrecord($iQDbFields) VALUES($iQFrmValues)");

            $insRows = mysql_affected_rows();
            if($insRows == 1){
                echo '
                    <div class="statusMsg successMsg" id="statusMsg">
                        <div class="msgContainer">
                            <div class="msgHead" id="msgHead">
                                <p class="msgTitle msgHeadSuccess" id="msgTitle">

                                    <span id="msgStatus">Guardado correctamente :)</span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="msgClose" id="msgClose" title="Cerrar cuadro de dialogo">X</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="msgContent" id="msgContent">La informacion del contrato de <b>' . $fName . " " . $sName . ' </b>se ha guardado correctamente en la base de datos <a class="msgHead msgContainer" href="listClient.php">Ver</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ';
            }else{
                echo '
                    <div class="statusMsg errorMsg" id="statusMsg">
                        <div class="msgContainer">
                            <div class="msgHead" id="msgHead">
                                <p class="msgTitle msgHeadError" id="msgTitle">

                                    <span id="msgStatus">Error en el guardado (AR=0x01)</span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="msgClose" id="msgClose" title="Cerrar cuadro de dialogo">X</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="msgContent errorMsg" id="msgContent">La informacion del contrato no pudo guardarse correctamente, revise los datos y vuelva a intentar</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ';
            }
            // mysql_close();

            //header("refresh:4; url=listClient.php");
        }else{
            echo '
                <div class="statusMsg errorMsg" id="statusMsg">
                    <div class="msgContainer">
                        <div class="msgHead" id="msgHead">
                            <p class="msgTitle msgHeadError" id="msgTitle">

                                <span id="msgStatus">Error en el guardado (SPx01)</span>
                            </p>
                            <p class="msgClose" id="msgClose" title="Cerrar cuadro de dialogo">X</p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="msgContent errorMsg" id="msgContent">La informacion del contrato no pudo guardarse correctamente, revise los datos y vuelva a intentar</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';
        }
    }else{
        echo '
            <div class="statusMsg errorMsg" id="statusMsg">
                <div class="msgContainer">
                    <div class="msgHead" id="msgHead">
                        <p class="msgTitle msgHeadError" id="msgTitle">

                            <span id="msgStatus">Error en el guardado (SAx01)</span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="msgClose" id="msgClose" title="Cerrar cuadro de dialogo">X</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="msgContent errorMsg" id="msgContent">La informacion del contrato no pudo guardarse correctamente, revise los datos y vuelva a intentar</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}else{
    echo '
        <div class="statusMsg errorMsg" id="statusMsg">
            <div class="msgContainer">
                <div class="msgHead" id="msgHead">
                    <p class="msgTitle msgHeadError" id="msgTitle">

                        <span id="msgStatus">Error en el guardado (SUx01)</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="msgClose" id="msgClose" title="Cerrar cuadro de dialogo">X</p>
                </div>
                <p class="msgContent errorMsg" id="msgContent">La informacion del contrato no pudo guardarse correctamente, revise los datos y vuelva a intentar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿De dónde has sacado tu código? Parece un código de la Edad Media. Tantas @ hacen mal a la vista y te impedirán ver muchos mensajes de error que pueden ser relevantes para depurar y corregir el problema. Por otro lado, las extensiones como esta son obsoletas: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO loanrecord($iQDbFields) VALUES($iQFrmValues)");` Ver: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967) Creo que debes ver el error_log para depurar un código tan antiguo y complejo y actualizarlo si es posible.

Comment: Y eso sin contar que a esto le pones una cadena medio mala y te destroza la base de datos al ser vulnerable a ataques de inyección sql.

Comment: considera hacer tu conexion e insercion de datos en sql con pdo!

Comment: Más de lo mismo que te han comentado, utilizar @ es una mala práctica, utilizas una librería antigua **mysql_query( )** y obsoleta, la cantidad ingente de parámetros post esperados me lleva a pensar que hay una mala implementación. Sinceramente no creo que esta pregunta reciba una respuesta seria.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios, si de hecho se va a migrar a algún framework PHP todavía no se decide cual (¿alguna recomendacion?), pero este codigo por lo pronto tiene que estar funcionando para ya, es un sistema que funcionara en una intranet asi que tambien la seguridad debe de ser un factor importante, gracias :) <3