# crear un sistema de login con php

Tags: php, mysql, login

Necesito hacer un sistema de login con PHP, encontre un pagina donde hay una guia. Esta funciona bien pero no se si es la forma mas correcta y segura de crear el login.

link: [Guia creacion de login PHP](http://www.taringa.net/posts/hazlo-tu-mismo/14629402/Tutorial-Crear-un-sistema-de-Login-con-PHP-y-MySQL.html)

**base de datos**

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `idusuario` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idusuario`)
)
```

**index.php**

```
 <?php
session_start();
include_once "conexion.php";

function verificar_login($user,$password,&$result) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$user' and password = '$password'";
    $rec = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
    {
        $count++;
        $result = $row;
    }

    if($count == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        if(verificar_login($_POST['user'],$_POST['password'],$result) == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $result->idusuario;
            header("location:index.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="error">Su usuario es incorrecto, intente nuevamente.</div>';
        }
    }
?>

<style type="text/css">
*{
    font-size: 14px;
}
body{
background:#aaa;
}
form.login {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F1F1F1;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 278px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px black;
    border-radius:10px;
}
form.login div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
form.login div label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 25px;
}
form.login div input[type="text"], form.login div input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    float: right;
    padding: 4px;
}
form.login div input[type="submit"] {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DEDEDE;
    border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4px 20px;
}
.error{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<form action="" method="post" class="login">
    <div><label>Username</label><input name="user" type="text" ></div>
    <div><label>Password</label><input name="password" type="password"></div>
    <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div>
</form>
<?php
} else {
    echo 'Su usuario ingreso correctamente.';
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
}
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();

    header('location: index.php');
?>
```

**conexion.php**

```
 <?php
// datos para la coneccion a mysql
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','TU_BASE_DE_DATOS');
define('DB_USER','TU_USUARIO');
define('DB_PASS','TU_CLAVE');

$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con);
?>
```

Comment: Borra esa página de tu historial, no la vuelvas a visitar y olvida todo lo que pienses que has aprendido de ella. Es una aberración que estaba mal incluso cuando las tecnologías que usa no estaban obsoletas. En serio, creo que no he visto un tutorial con más errores y vulnerabilidades graves que esa. Debería usarse como guía para lo que no hay que hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada yo te recomendaria que empezar estructurando tu proyecto, por ejemplo, en lugar de hacer todo en un solo archivo, crea varios archivos que puedas ir incluyendo segun necesites, por ejemplo, lo que hiciste con la conexion a la base de datos.

Por mi crearia lo siguiente.

RAIZ/index.php
En este archivo mandaria a llamar un header general y un footer general, asi no tendrias que repetir los estilos o el javascript, tambien desde aca podrias llamar a tus archivos de configuración como tu base de datos y esas cosas

```
<?php
    require_once('configuraciones.php'); //aqui podrian ir variables que usaras en todo el proyecto, como el titulo de la pagina y metadas, asi como rutas, y variables globales
    require_once('conexion.php'); // Tu conexion a la base de datos
    require_once('plantilla/header.php'); //este seria como tu Header general

    if($user_is_logged){
        require_once('plantilla/home.php');
    }else{
        require_once('plantilla/loginform.php');
    }
```

En el header pues podrias poner la comprobación de la sesion tambien, por ejemplo

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['logged'] == TRUE){
        $user_is_logged=TRUE;
    }elseif($_GET['login'] && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
        $login = verificar_login();
        if($login){
            $user_is_logged=TRUE;
        }else{
            $user_is_logged=FALSE;
            $login_error=TRUE;
        }
    }else{
        $user_is_logged=FALSE;
    }
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
            <title><?php echo $PageTitle; ?></title>
            etc....
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
```

el footer mas o menos igual

en el archivo **plantilla/home.php** simplemento pones el HTML del HOME o usas lo que quieras

y en el archivo de **plantilla/loginform.php** pues pones el formulario de registo.

Y asi será mas facil controlar todos los recursos.

Esepro te sirva de algo y siempre puedes usar otros recuros que ya existen, como frameworks para PHP que contruyen muchas cosas por vos.

Answer (score 0):

amigo solo un consejo la conexion de la BDD ya esta desactualizada desde PHP 5 te recomiendo usar este como ejemplo:

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos",);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Borra esa página de tu historial, no la vuelvas a visitar y olvida todo lo que pienses que has aprendido de ella**. Es una aberración que está mal casi de principio a fin. Lo que recomienda es inseguro y usa tecnologías obsoletas (sin justificación alguna porque esas tecnologías estaban ya obsoletas cuando se escribió el artículo).

Vamos a ver algunos de los fallos que presenta:

- **Usa tecnologías que están obsoletas y son potencialmente peligrosas**, como las funciones `mysql_*`. [Más sobre este tema en esta otra pregunta de SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/250).
- **No se sanean las entradas del usuario**, esto puede llevar a problemas de seguridad si dichas entradas se usan en la aplicación web.
- **Usa sentencias dinámicas (concatenando cadenas) en vez de sentencias preparadas**: combinado con los dos puntos anteriores, hace que las consultas a la base de datos sean [vulnerables a ataques de inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/250).
- **No se encriptan/hashean las contraseñas**: las contraseñas nunca se deberían guardar en texto plano, si algún usuario malicioso consigue acceso a tu base de datos (posible con los errores de arriba) tendría acceso directo a las contraseñas. Ni siquiera tú necesitas saber cuál es el valor de una contraseña, por eso usar hashing es importante.
- **La conexión a la base de datos está directamente en el código**. Debería estar fuera del código (en un fichero de configuración), e idealmente fuera de la carpeta que se sirve a la web (de ese modo sólo accesible a los ficheros del servidor pero no a usuarios fisgones).
- **No se controlan errores de conexión a la base de datos**. Dependiendo de la configuración del servidor, si ocurre algún error, se podrían mostrar los datos de conexión al usuario.
- **No ocurre nada si el usuario falla**. No hay ningún tipo de "castigo" por escribir mal la contraseña, no se bloquea la cuenta, o se congela el usuario por X tiempo, ni nada de nada. Un usuario malicioso podría probar suerte sin consecuencias.
- **La sesión no expira** o al menos no se ve en el código que se haga nada para que expire. Esto hace que el usuario que inicie sesión siga con la sesión iniciada aunque esté inactivo durante horas.
- **No se regeneran los IDs de sesión**. Esto es algo recomendable que se debería hacer cada vez que ocurre un cambio en el estado de la autentificación para evitar ataques de secuestro de sesión o de fijación de sesión (especialmente combinado con el punto anterior).
- **El código tiene errores y validará a usuarios incluso con la contraseña incorrecta**. En la pregunta aquí lo has puesto bien, pero en el tutorial pone `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$user' and '$password' = '$password'` que hará que la validación de contraseña pase siempre aunque no coincida con la de la base de datos.

---

Resumiendo: tecnologías obsoletas, errores en el código, vulnerabilidades claras de seguridad... Y eso son sólo algunos de los problemas que se ven a simple vista. Descarta ese tutorial y busca algo mejor.

Mi recomendación cuando veo preguntas en SOes sobre logins es siempre la misma: **usa alguna librería ya existente y desarrollada por expertos** antes que ponerte a hacer tu propio login. No digo que no lo hagas, pero antes de hacerlo deberías tener algunos conceptos de seguridad claros... y el autor del tutorial claramente no los tiene.