# ¿Cómo dejar seleccionado un dato de un ComboBox?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer un `combobox` que me traiga los valores de un departamento de la `bd`, para luego modificarlos, en el `combobox` se muestran todos los departamentos, y yo tengo un formulario en el que edito el departamento de los equipos, el problema es que no sé como dejar seleccionado el `combobox` con el departamento que esta en la base de datos.

No se selecciona y toma el primero de los departamentos. Este es el código que utilice para mostrar los combos. Quiero que me deje seleccionado el que esta en la bd, para luego modificarlo.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");

mysql_select_db("lfmt",$link);

$consulta=mysql_query("select * from depto")or die('Fallo Query: ' . mysql_error());


<?php
     echo '<select name= "Deptos">';

      do {

           echo '<option value=" ' .$row["idDepto"].' ">'.$row["Nombre"].'</option>';

         }

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta));

      echo "</select>";

 ?>
```

Comment: **El que esta en la `bd` ?**  es muy confusa esa parte, se supone que todos los datos que obtiene están el `bd`. al parecer le hace falta una parte  importante a su código. Por otra parte recomendar dejar de usar la extensión mysql por completo. [importante leer está pregunta y respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: obtengo el id del departamento a traves de una variable 'resedit[2]'

Comment: Te recomiendo muchísimo (aun si tu proyecto es puramente academico) atender el comentario de A. Cedano en mi respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar esa variable `resedit[2]` para verficar cual de los departamentos es el que necesitas que este seleccionado y usar la propiedad `selected` de `option`.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
    if($row["idDepto"] == $resedit[2])
      echo '<option selected value=" ' .$row["idDepto"].' ">'.$row["Nombre"].'</option>';
    else
      echo '<option value=" ' .$row["idDepto"].' ">'.$row["Nombre"].'</option>';
}
```

Con una comparación sabremos cual es el ID que ya has recuperado y solamente a ese le indicamos la propiedad `selected`.

Comment: Funciono muy bien, muchas gracias, ahora se mantiene seleccionado, en verdad que gracias!!

Comment: Dos cosas importantes en su código. **1.** `do while` en la primera iteración no reconocerá la variable `$row`. debería usar solo `while`  . **2.** `resedit[2]` es variable al parecer y se le antepone el `$.`

Comment: Gracias @Dev.Joel ya lo edite.

Comment: Gracias, mi variable se ve asi $resEditar[2]  y entonces remuevo el do?

Comment: Si @Jonathan, gracias a la recomendacion de Dev. Joel hazlo solo con while, y ya edite la respuesta para que te des una idea de como deberia de ser. Tambien, si la respuesta te ayudo, no olvides marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!

Comment: Si es posible @Jonathan actualiza el código que usas para manejar la base de datos. La extensión `mysql_*`  es obsoleta, no funciona a partir de PHP 7 y pone en riesgo tus datos. Ver: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967) Se recomienda usar `mysqli` o `PDO` para el manejo de los datos.

Comment: De acuerdo @A.Cedano lo cambiare a mysqli, no lo habia notado.

Comment: Ya, como consejo personal, @Jonathan , te recomendaría usar PDO en vez de MySQLi. Es más robusto y permite hacer las cosas de forma más sencilla. Lo más difícil es el principio, pero teniendo una clase dedicada a las conexiones, solamente creas tu objeto PDO, le pasas las consultas de forma segura y obtienes tus datos de manera limpia, fácil y clara. Puedes echarle un vistazo a **[esta clase](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO)** si quieres, la cual puedes usar si lo deseas.

Comment: Muy bien, entonces mejor utilizare con PDO, gracias por el consejo!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Kenny Barrera andube buscando una solución como esta por varias semanas para un caso parecido que tenia con unos `select` en un formulario de actualización de datos.

Comment: Que tal @Luis. Fijate que estás usando la sección de respuestas para dejar tu comentario. Si quieres pedir aclaraciones puedes usar la sección de comentarios de la pregunta. Recuerda revisar las normas del sitio. Suerte.