# llamada a la función no definida mysql_connect () PhP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo este error en mi proyecto:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ams\config.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ams\index.php(9): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ams\config.php on line 11
```

**index.php: **

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
define('DIR_APPLICATION', str_replace('\'', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/');
if(!file_exists("config.php")){
    header("Location: install/index.php");
    die();
}
include(DIR_APPLICATION."config.php");
$msg = 'none';
$sql = '';
if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != '' && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] != ''){
    if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '1'){
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT *,b.branch_name FROM tbl_add_admin aa left join tblbranch b on b.branch_id = aa.branch_id WHERE aa.email = '".make_safe($_POST['username'])."' and aa.password = '".make_safe($_POST['password'])."'",$link);
    }
    if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '2'){
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT *,b.branch_name FROM tbl_add_owner o left join tblbranch b on b.branch_id = o.branch_id WHERE o.o_email = '".make_safe($_POST['username'])."' and o.o_password = '".make_safe($_POST['password'])."'",$link);
    }
    if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '3'){
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT *,b.branch_name FROM tbl_add_employee e left join tblbranch b on b.branch_id = e.branch_id WHERE e.e_email = '".make_safe($_POST['username'])."' and e.e_password = '".make_safe($_POST['password'])."'",$link);
    }
    if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '4'){
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT *,b.branch_name FROM tbl_add_rent ad left join tblbranch b on b.branch_id = ad.branch_id WHERE ad.r_email = '".make_safe($_POST['username'])."' and ad.r_password = '".make_safe($_POST['password'])."'",$link);
    }
    if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '5'){
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT *,(select branch_name from tblbranch where branch_id = $_POST[ddlBranch]) as branch_name FROM tblsuper_admin WHERE email = '".make_safe($_POST['username'])."' and password = '".make_safe($_POST['password'])."'",$link);
    }
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        //here success
        if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '5'){
            $arr = array(
                'user_id'       => $row['user_id'],
                'name'          => $row['name'],
                'email'         => $row['email'],
                'password'      => $row['password'],
                'branch_id'     => $_POST['ddlBranch'],
                'branch_name'   => $row['branch_name'],
                'added_date'    => $row['added_date']
            );
            $_SESSION['objLogin'] = $arr;
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['objLogin'] = $row;
        }

        $_SESSION['login_type'] = $_POST['ddlLoginType'];

        if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '1' || $_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '5'){
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
            die();
        }
        else if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '2'){
            header("Location: o_dashboard.php");
            die();
        }
        else if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '3'){
            header("Location: e_dashboard.php");
            die();
        }
        else if($_POST['ddlLoginType'] == '4'){
            header("Location: t_dashboard.php");
            die();
        }
    }
    else{
        $msg = 'block';
    }

}
function make_safe($variable)
{
   $variable = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable)));
   return $variable;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Sistema de Gestion de Apartamentos</title>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP STYLES-->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- FONTAWESOME STYLES-->
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- CUSTOM STYLES-->
<link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!-- SCRIPTS -AT THE BOTOM TO REDUCE THE LOAD TIME-->
<!-- JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="row text-center ">
    <div class="col-md-12"><br/>
      <span style="font-size:35px;font-weight:bold;color:red;">CompuBinario</span> <span style="font-size:18px;">Sistema de Gestion de Apartamentos</span></div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
      <div style="margin-bottom:8px;padding-top:2px;width:100%;height:25px;background:#E52740;color:#fff; display:<?php echo $msg; ?>" align="center">Wrong login information</div>
      <div class="panel panel-default" id="loginBox">
        <div class="panel-heading"> <strong> Ingrese Credenciales </strong> </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form onSubmit="return validationForm();" role="form" id="form" method="post">
            <br />
            <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-tag"  ></i></span>
              <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="E Mail" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"  ></i></span>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Coontraseña" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"  ></i></span>
              <select name="ddlLoginType" onChange="mewhat(this.value);" id="ddlLoginType" class="form-control">
                <option value="">--Select Tipo--</option>
                <option value="1">Admin</option>
                <option value="2">Owner</option>
                <option value="3">Employee</option>
                <option value="4">Renter</option>
                <option value="5">Super Admin</option>
              </select>
            </div>
             <div id="x_branch" style="display:none;" class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-plus"  ></i></span>
              <select class="form-control" name="ddlBranch" id="ddlBranch">
              <option value="">--Select Branch--</option>
              <?php
                    $result_branch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblbranch order by branch_name ASC",$link);
                    while($row_branch = mysql_fetch_array($result_branch)){?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_branch['branch_id'];?>"><?php echo $row_branch['branch_name'];?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="checkbox-inline"> </label>
              <span class="pull-right"> <a href="<?php echo WEB_URL;?>forgetpassword.php" >Recuperar Contraseña </a> </span> </div>
            <hr />
            <div align="center">
              <button style="width:100%;" type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-user"  ></i>&nbsp;Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validationForm(){
    if($("#username").val() == ''){
        alert("Email Required !!!");
        $("#username").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(!validateEmail($("#username").val())){
        alert("Valid Email Required !!!");
        $("#username").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if($("#password").val() == ''){
        alert("Password Required !!!");
        $("#password").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if($("#ddlLoginType").val() == ''){
        alert("Select User Type !!!");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function mewhat(val){
    if(val != ''){
        if(val == '5'){
            $("#x_branch").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#x_branch").hide();
        }
    }
    else{
        $("#x_branch").hide();
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
define('CURRENCY', '$');
define('WEB_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/ams/');
define('ROOT_PATH', 'C:\AppServ\www\ams/');


define('DB_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'rarg');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'rarg777');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'ams_db');
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link) or die(mysql_error());?>
```

Comment: La extensión `mysql_*` es actualmente obsoleta y fue sacada del core de PHP 7, por lo tanto, si tu versión de PHP es la 7, deberás pasar absolutamente a la extensión `mysqli` o a PDO para conectar a la base de datos. Puedes consultar [más detalles sobre cómo hacer la migración en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92777/29967)

Comment: index.php y Config.php estan en la carpeta install?
cual es el nombre de la base de datos?

Comment: los dos estan en la carpeta raiz, la de inicio, el nombre de la db es ams_db

Answer (score 2):

La función mysql_connect fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzar las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL.

Puede obtener más información de MySQLi en http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php

Y de PDO en http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

espero que estés muy bien, he aquí una aclaratoria:

- La extensión MYSQL ya quedó obsoleta, en su lugar puedes utilizar MYSQLI o si gustas también tienes la opción de utilizar la extensión PDO, le dejaré unos enlaces provenientes de la página oficial de php, ya depende de usted la elección:
- Extensión mysqli -> [Click aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- Extensión pdo -> [Click aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

  Continuando con su código amigo mío en su archivo **config.php** debes corregir lo siguiente, su código está así:

  `$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link) or die(mysql_error());`

Debe corregirlo agréguele la letra **i** a **mysql_connect** en conjunto con **mysql_select_db** y **mysql_error** quedaría así:

```
   `$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());mysqli_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link) or die(mysqli_error());`
```

Espero haberlo ayudado, hasta luego mi hermano.

Answer (score 0):

El esta usando AppServ por lo que su version de php es 5.2 asi que debe usar la extension mysql_* aunque ya actualmente este obsoleta.

Yo particularmente uso esta conexion si uso appserv:

```
<?php 
function Conectarse() 
{ 
if(!(@$conec=mysql_connect("localhost","rarg","rarg777"))) 
{ 
?>
<script language="javascript"> alert("ERROR: Conectando a la base de datos");window.location="Index.php";</script>
<?php
exit();     
} 
if(!mysql_select_db("ams_db",$conec)) 
{    
?>
<script language="javascript"> alert("ERROR: al Buscar la base de datos");window.location="Index.php";</script> 
<?php
exit();     
} 
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$conec);
return $conec; 
} 
?>
```

para usarlo en index.php debes hacerlo asi:

```
 include("config.php");
 $conec=Conectarse();

 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from tabla",$conec);
```

espero te sirva