# 2 conexiones a Mysql en un mismo PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo un problema con las conexiones hacia mysql
actualmente desde un PHP establezco las conexiones hacia mysql de la siguiente manera

```
<?php 
  $date = strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); //FECHA
  function conectarse($host,$usuario,$password,$BBDD){ 
    $link=@mysql_connect($host,$usuario,$password) or die (mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($BBDD,$link) or die (mysql_error()); 
    return $link; 
  } 

  $link=conectarse("localhost","usuario1","123456","basededatos");  

  $con_at = "select * from tabla";
  $con_at = mysql_query($con_at,$link);
  $con = mysql_fetch_array($con_at);
  $atdb_server = $con['at_dbserver'];
  $atdb_user = $con['at_dbuser'];
  $atdb_pass = $con['at_dbpass'];

  function conectarse2($host,$usuario,$password,$BBDD){ 
    $link2=@mysql_connect($host,$usuario,$password) or die ('error 2da db'); 
    mysql_select_db($BBDD,$link2) or die (mysql_error()); 
    return $link2; 
  } 
  $link2=conectarse2($atdb_server,$atdb_user, $atdb_pass,"base2");  

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM config_camp where cp_tipo = '0' ";
  $data =mysql_query($sql, $link);
  $afectadas = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql, $link));
```

El problema es que la consulta ($sql) no funciona, (la hace hacia la primera conexion). Pero si borro la segunda conexion si funciona. Necesito mantener ambas conexiones puesto que mas adelante debo hacer consultas a una y otra. Alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo?
Espero se entienda. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ya has probado cerrar esa coneccion ? con mysqli_close, asi luego puedes abrir la otra ?

Comment: En la segunda consulta estás usando `$link`  en vez de usar `$link2`, por eso usa la primera conexión, pues es lo que le estás indicando.

Comment: mi idea no es cerrar las conexiones, puesto que luego debo usarlas. uso $link porque es la consulta a la primera base de datos. Pero no funciona puesto que se "marea" con la segunda conexion a la base de datos

Comment: Aclara qué es lo que quieres hacer. Si en la 2ª consulta quieres usar `$link2` debes pasar ese objeto a todas las funciones que usen la conexión. Es imposible que use la 2ª conexión si le estás pasando la 1ª. No sé lo que quieres decir con que se *marea*. Puede que sea el código el que te tenga *mareado* a ti. Así que toma control de tu código, aclárate en lo que quieres hacer, depura tus variables y encontrarás el error.

Comment: en que segunda consulta? solo hay una consulta

Select * from config_camp where cp_tipo = '0' 

Esa consulta la hace hacia la primera funcion que es $link.
El caso es que la segunda funcion "conectarse2" debe quedar porque la utilizo en otra consulta mas abajo. Pero al estar la funcion conectarse2 sobre la consulta mysql esta no funciona.

Comment: Qué valores tienen `$atdb_server,$atdb_user, $atdb_pass`? Por casualidad es el mismo host y mismo usuario?

Comment: te sugiero usar mysqli : http://be2.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php   y si te  interesa usar PDO que es mejor : http://be2.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php y mas info aquii: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92771/como-cambiar-de-mysql-query-a-mysqli-query

Comment: ¿En que segunda consulta?  ...  lo dije, que el código te tiene mareado. Mira, esta es la 1ª consulta: `$con_at = "select * from tabla";`  y esta es la 2ª consulta: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM config_camp where cp_tipo = '0' ";` ¿Qué es lo que quieres, usar `$link2` para la 2ª consulta, o sea para `$sql`?  Si es eso, pues estás usando `$link`  y no `$link2`, aquí: `$afectadas = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql, $link)); `  ... es aso a lo que me refiero.

Comment: @Lusagsilva Estimado, encontraste alguna solución? estoy en el mismo caso con php 5.1

Answer (score 2):

Primero, es mi deber señalarte que la extensión `mysql` está obsoleta y no se puede usar en versiones modernas de php. Eso además de tener varias fallas de seguridad.

Segundo, la función `mysql_connect`, cuando se ejecuta por segunda vez a un mismo servidor (aunque sean distintas bases de datos o schemas) puede devolverte el primer recurso de conexión en vez de crear uno nuevo. En teoría eso sólo ocurriría si usas el mismo usuario, pero aparentemente hay casos de borde.

Si este fuera el caso, lo que está ocurriendo es:

- Creas la conexión 1
- Fijas la base de datos 1 para la conexión 1
- Creas la conexión 2 pero PHP te devuelve una referencia a la conexión 1
- Fijas la base de datos 2 para la conexión 2 lo cual implica que por debajo cambiaste la base de datos para la conexión 1.

Una solución corta y sucia sería usar el cuarto parámetro que admite `mysql_connect` que indica si quieres forzar la creación de un link nuevo:

```
$link2=@mysql_connect($host,$usuario,$password, true) or die ('error 2da db');
```

No me consta que funcione y no tengo como probarlo porque todos los sitios con PHP que manejo ya corren en PHP 7. Como sea, el comportamiento por defecto de las funciones `mysql_xxxx()` cuando no pasas el recurso de conexión es asumir como conexión la última conexión válida que obtuviste con `mysql_connect`. Puede que en alguna parte de tu código no estés espeficicando el recurso de conexión. Sin ir más lejos, cuando llamas a `mysql_error()` estás omitiendo el resource.

Yo en tu caso evaluaría seriamente cambiarme a un driver más moderno. Por ejemplo, **PDO_MySQL soporta espeficicar la base de datos en el DSN de la conexión**, incluso si estás usando el mismo usuario y password.

```
$link1 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name",'usuario1','password1');
$link1->setAttribute("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$link2 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name2",'usuario1','password1');
$link2->setAttribute("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$res1 = $link1->query("SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='siteurl'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$res2 = $link2->query("SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='siteurl'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

El cambio de un driver a otro puede ser tedioso si tu base de código es muy grande, pero puedes implementarlo gradualmente.