# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in

Tags: php, wamp, msql

intento subir archivo local hacia una BD mysql. Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\wamp64\www\ManualesTIENDA\Departamentos\upload.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\ManualesTIENDA\Departamentos\upload.php on line 27**

mi código es:

```
<?php
    include_once 'conexionpdf.php';
    if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
    {    
         
     $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
     $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
     $folder="C:/wamp64/uploads/";
     

     $new_size = $file_size/1024;  

     

     $new_file_name = strtolower($file);

     
     $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
     
     if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) 
     { 
    
      $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
     
      mysql_query($sql);  //------------------LINEA DEL ERROR 
      ?>
```

La ultima linea me arroja el error.
El archivo si me lo guarda en la carpeta temporal UPLOADS.
Espero puedan orientarme. Gcs

Comment: Estas usando código obsoleto (php 5.5+) o posiblemente removido (php 7+), `mysql_*`. Quizás esto te pueda ayudar [cambiar de mysql_query a mysqli_query](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92771/como-cambiar-de-mysql-query-a-mysqli-query)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql\_\* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75123/por-qu%c3%a9-no-se-debe-usar-la-api-mysql-en-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veo varios errores:

1 - en mysql_query coloca la conexión a la Base de datos de la siguiente manera: mysqli_query(sql,conex) o como tu estas en la versión obsoleta pon el sql después de la conexión

2 - mysql_query esta obsoleto te sugiero que leas como se utiliza [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

> En este ejemplo la variable se llama conex

```
<?php
   $conex=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","DataBase");
   if($conex){
     $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
     $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
     $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
     $folder="C:/wamp64/uploads/";
 

     $new_size = $file_size/1024;  

 

     $new_file_name = strtolower($file);

 
     $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
 
 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) 
 { 
      $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
     $query=mysqli_query($conex,$sql); // almacenado en una variable para confirmar envio
     if($query){
        echo "enviado correctamente";
     }else{ echo "no de pudo enviar el archivo a la Base de datos"; }
 }else{
   echo "no se pudo subir el archivo";
 }

   }else{
      echo "error al conectar a la DataBase";
   }

?>
```

Tambien te sugiero que leas [la conexión a Base de Datos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect) si no sabes como funciona [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect)

Casi ninguna condicional es obligatoria solo que me gusta confirmar que cada parte de la página funcione correctamente

Comment: Efectivamente era mi error, en todas las conexiones le tenia mysqli, pero aqui le deje mysql. Igual manera revise el codigo que me proporcionas y funciona como indicas. SOlo que en la parte $query=mysqli_query($sql,$conex)   primero iria la variable $conex y luego $sql
Genial amigo! gcs

Comment: de nada, Aqui estamos para ayudar. En eso me equivoque cambiando la parte obsoleta a mysqli_* Y disculpa por eso. Ademas si pones mysql_* nadie te respondera o se tardaran en hacerlo ya que en los comentarios te diran que mysql es obsoleto y que leas sobre el tema