# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Tags: php

Requiero mostrar los datos ingresados por un usuario en una modal, la cual tiene un dato `select` e ingresa un monto, estos datos deben ser mostrados en una tabla después de ser guardados en la `DB`

Al guardarlos, el error que obtengo es:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in....

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                           <tr> <th>Código</th>
<th>Descripción del Gasto</th>
<th width="150" height="45"> Monto  Generado</th>
<th width="150" height="45">Pago por Apartamento</th>  <th width="120" height="45">Opciones</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<?php
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM gasto_g";
                            $consulta = mysql_query($conexion,$sql);
                             if($consulta>0){
                            while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
                            ?> 


<tr>

 <td><?php echo $resultado['id_gasto_g']; ?></td> 


<td><?php echo $resultado['descripcion']; ?> </td> 


<td width="7" height="7"><?php echo $resultado['monto']; ?>  </td> 

<td>  </td>  
<td>   <!--Boton agregar -->

    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-0">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="sesion" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registro"  rel="tooltip-left" title="Editar">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>

                                        </button>
    </div>
</div><br>
<!--Boton agregar -->  </td>


</tr>

 <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                        <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                    </table>


               </div>
           </div>
    </div><!--/content-body -->
</div><!--/content -->
```

Comment: Veo que estás usando la extensión `mysql`.  Ten en cuenta que está **declarada obsoleta**, y que no se usa como muestras en tu código, sólo se le pasa la instrucción `$sql` la variable `$conexion` no se le pasa: [ver en el Manual como se usa](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Si en verdad usas `mysql_` es mejor cambiar a MySQLi o a PDO, si es posible (ver [el por qué en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)).

Comment: [Aquí tienes un ejemplo usando MySQLi](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ck5y-jc3j), que hace exactamente lo mismo que quieres hacer, y [este es otro ejemplo usando PDO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tcy5-b093). En ambos casos se crea de forma _elegante_ una tabla a partir del conjunto de resultados. Lo puedes probar pulsando en **`Run - F9`**. El código está comentado pensando en quieres migran o empiezan con MySQLi o con PDO. Espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias por la información Marcos, requiero que como esto es una especie de recibo que se llena mensualmente el gasto seleccionado en la modal sea mostrado al darle registrar ese gasto y no todos los datos de la bd, de antemano gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se debe a que a la función [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) le estas pasando como primer parámetro `$conexion` y luego `$sql`, cuando lo correcto es hacerlo al revés.

Ejemplo:

```
mysql_query($sql, $conexion);
```

-

**PD**: La extensión `MySQL` fue **declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0`** y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0`. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) o [`PDO_MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la version de mysql se manejan las funciones

en este caso
debes cambiar de msql_query(); a msqli_query()

Desde php 5.5.0 ya  msql_query() fue declarada obsoleta

msqli_query() permite recibir 2 parametros

$conexion._ es la variable que almacena la coneccion de tu base de datos

$query="INSERTE CONSULTA"

msqli_query($conexion, $query);

espero me haya hecho entender