# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in FICHERO on line 22

Tags: php, mysql

¿porqué me genera error en la línea 22 si lo comparo con otros PHP y los tengo bien?

En la línea 22 tengo lo siguiente:

```
while($rowHorEmp = mysql_fetch_array($resHorEmp))
```

Y la variable $resHorEmp viene de la siguiente consulta:

```
$sqlHorEmp = "SELECT t.Nombre, t.Documento, t.Dia, MAX(t.Entrada) Entrada, MAX(t.Salida) Salida, t.Horario FROM ( SELECT u.Nombre, u.Documento, r.Dia, IF(r.Tipo = 'Entry', r.Hora, NULL) Entrada, IF(r.Tipo = 'Exit', r.Hora, NULL) Salida, CONCAT(h.Entrada, "-", h.Salida) Horario FROM USUARIOS u INNER JOIN relacion_colaborador_horario rh ON (u.Id_Usuario = rh.Id_Usuario) INNER JOIN horarios h ON (rh.Id_Horario = h.Id_Horario) INNER JOIN ( SELECT Documento, Tipo, Dia, IF(Tipo = 'Entry', MIN(Hora), MAX(Hora)) Hora FROM REGISTROS GROUP BY Documento, Tipo, Dia ) r ON(r.Documento = u.Documento) WHERE (r.Tipo = 'Entry' AND r.Hora > h.Entrada) OR (r.Tipo = 'Exit' AND r.Hora < h.Salida) ) t GROUP BY t.Nombre, t.Documento, t.Dia, t.Horario ORDER BY t.Dia DESC, t.Nombre ASC";

$resHorEmp = mysql_query($sqlHorEmp,$con);
```

Comment: He borrado mi respuesta porque claramente no ayuda en tu pregunta. Tienes problemas en alguna otra parte de tu codigo o solo en esta parte? Es posible que sea la conexion?

Comment: Solamente es en esa parte, en el while. La consulta la puse más arriba y la verdad no me arroja error... Sólo cuando la voy a **DECLARAR**

Comment: Es posible que haya algún error en la consulta. Controla el flujo del código para saberlo. Ejemplo: `$resHorEmp = mysql_query($sqlHorEmp,$con_mysql);
 or die(mysql_error());

while($rowHorEmp = mysql_fetch_array($resHorEmp))
{...código dentro del while.. }` **Nota**: Considera que estás usando una extensión obsoleta de MySQL, si es posible, se recomienda cambiar a MySQLi o a PDO. **[Ver esta pregunta y su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es provocado por las comillas de la consulta. Dentro de la consulta tienes `"-"`, debería ser `'-'`.

El código sería este:

```
$sqlHorEmp = "SELECT t.Nombre, t.Documento, t.Dia, MAX(t.Entrada) Entrada, MAX(t.Salida) Salida, t.Horario FROM ( SELECT u.Nombre, u.Documento, r.Dia, IF(r.Tipo = 'Entry', r.Hora, NULL) Entrada, IF(r.Tipo = 'Exit', r.Hora, NULL) Salida, CONCAT(h.Entrada, '-', h.Salida) Horario FROM USUARIOS u INNER JOIN relacion_colaborador_horario rh ON (u.Id_Usuario = rh.Id_Usuario) INNER JOIN horarios h ON (rh.Id_Horario = h.Id_Horario) INNER JOIN ( SELECT Documento, Tipo, Dia, IF(Tipo = 'Entry', MIN(Hora), MAX(Hora)) Hora FROM REGISTROS GROUP BY Documento, Tipo, Dia ) r ON(r.Documento = u.Documento) WHERE (r.Tipo = 'Entry' AND r.Hora > h.Entrada) OR (r.Tipo = 'Exit' AND r.Hora < h.Salida) ) t GROUP BY t.Nombre, t.Documento, t.Dia, t.Horario ORDER BY t.Dia DESC, t.Nombre ASC";
```

Comment: EXCELENTE, ¡MUCHAS GRACIAS! Yo vi eso pero la descarté no sé porqué... Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Seguramente se debe a un error en la consulta guardada en la variable `$sqlHorEmp`, ya que [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) devuelve `FALSE` en caso de error.

Para averiguar la cual es es error puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$resHorEmp = mysql_query($sqlHorEmp,$con_mysql);
// Si la consulta fallo
if (!$resHorEmp) {
   die(mysql_errno($con_mysql) . ":" . mysql_error($con_mysql));
}
```

Donde:

- [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-error.php): Devuelve el texto del mensaje de error de la operación `MySQL` anterior.
- [`mysql_errno`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-errno.php): Devuelve el valor numérico del mensaje de error de la última operación `MySQL`.

-

**PD**: La extensión `MySQL` fue **declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0`** y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0`. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) o [`PDO_MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: En el mysql me está imprimiendo la consulta correctamente. Y hago otras consultas en PHP sobre otras consultas y me funciona perfectamente con el **mysql_query**

Comment: @ceortiz, que la extensión `MySQL` este deprecada, no significa que no funcione, sino en un futuro que va a dejar de funcionar.