# No puede conectarse a la base de datos en php

Tags: php

Hola estoy intentando que mi fichero de administración se conecte a mi base de datos. el fichero es el siguiente:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,700,700italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<?php
$filename = 'install.php';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo ("<center><font color='red'><b>/install.php still exists<br>
After installing please delete install.php</center></font></b>");
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['Login'])){
    include('SqlConnect.php');
        if (!mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) die("Can't connect to database");
        if (!mysql_select_db($db_name)) die("Can't select database");
        $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
        $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
        $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count >= 1){
            session_start();
                    $_SESSION["myusername"] = $_POST['myusername'];
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION["mypassword"] = $_POST['mypassword'];
        header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            echo "<center><font color='red'><b>Wrong Username or Password</center></font></b>";
        }
    }
?>
<br>
<form method="post" action=""><td>
<table width="325" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#212121">
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#404040"></td>
<tr colspan="3"><strong><center> <font color="ECECEC"> Admin Login </font></center></strong></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<font color="ECECEC">Username </font><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername">
<font color="ECECEC">Password </font><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword">
</td>
<center><td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"></td></center>
</table></table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Y donde conecto es al fichero sqlconnect, pongo la direccion ip del sitio:

```
<?php
$host="http://198.54.116.113/"; 
$username="nulltbzc_A"; 
$password="password"; 
$db_name="nulltbzc_DS"; 
$tbl_name="members"; 
$table="Account"; 
?>
```

Pero aun así siempre me devuelve el mismo error.

```
Can't connect to database
```

Comment: Hola, prueba quitando el http:// de la variables $host, solo deja la IP

Comment: me pasa lo mismo puse la ip del dominio .

Comment: ¿`SqlConnect.php` lo tienes en el mismo directorio? ¿El cortafuegos del servidor te tiene dado permisos para poder acceder? Por otra parte la función `mysql_connect`está obsoleta y es peligrosa, tu código es vulnerable a inyección sql, te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a este artículo en SOes: [Cómo evitar inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: si pero primero intentaba arreglar el error y luego optimizarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Dónde tienes el mysql_connect?
Veo los datos en variables en el SqlConnect.php donde no hay un mysql_connect para realizar la conexión, y en la página tampoco. Sólo veo un condicional con la negación "!" del mysql_connect.

Prueba poner esto después del include y sabrás si te conecta:

```
//CONEXION
    $enlace =  mysql_connect('$host', '$username', 'password');
    if (!$enlace) {
        die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Conectado satisfactoriamente';
//CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$enlace) OR DIE ("Error: No es posible establecer la conexión a la base de datos"
);
```

Ah al final añade la desconexión (justo antes de finalizar el php "?>" incluye:

```
mysql_close($enlace);
```

Nos cuentas a ver...

Saludos.

Comment: me devuelve el error No pudo conectarse: Unknown MySQL server host '$host' (-2) cuando hice eso que me pusistes debería reconocer $host ya que esta en sqlconnect pero cuando lo pongo a mano No pudo conectarse: Access denied for user 'nulltbzc_A'@'server231-4.web-hosting.com' (using password: YES)

Comment: @OmarOmar ¿Le estás pasando a `mysql_connect` la contraseña? Si es así, ¿estás seguro de que la contraseña es correcta?

Comment: **NOTA: La extensión `mysql_*` ha sido declarada obsoleta, su uso no es recomendable.** [Ver esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967) para más detalles.

Comment: Hola @r84, es bueno tenerte aquí ayudando a la comunidad, veo que realizaste dos respuestas, recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/95356/edit) tu respuesta para agregar actualizaciones o más contenido a tu respuesta, saludos!