# ¿Por qué me sale el error "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()"?

Tags: mysql

Al querer generar un PDF con php y MySQL me sale este error, que no sé cómo solucionar:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\codigoresponsive\codigonuevoappfish\opnpdf\reporte3_pdf.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: Si tu versión PHP es 7+  no podrás usar `mysql_connect` porque ha sido declarado obsoleto y sacado de PHP 7. [Ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967) En cualquier caso, es recomendable actualizar el código, aunque estés en una versión de PHP inferior a la v. 7.

Comment: Gracias fue la solucion llevaba rato para dar con esto :D ........

Comment: Es obsoleta esta función pero en mi caso necesitaba usarla y ni con PHP 5.4 funcionaba. Así que en la configuración PHP he tenido que activar 'mysql' que estaba desactivado (servidor web laragon)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**`Mysql_connect`** esta obsoleto, tienes que utilizar **`mysqli`** en su lugar:

```
//Creas una variable de tipo objeto mysqli con los datos de la bd y el charset que quieras
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'basededatos1');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Y hacer las consultas de esta manera:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM personas");

while($f = $res->fetch_object()){
    echo $f->nombre.' <br/>';
}
```

Usando el método Query que tiene el objeto **`mysqli`** metes la cadena SQL y con **`fetch_object`** metes los datos de cada fila en una nuevo objeto **`$f`** para poder acceder a sus columnas de la manera que muestro en el ejemplo.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estas usando la extensión `mysql_connect()`, fue declarada obsoleta en **`PHP 5.5.0`** y eliminada en **`PHP 7.0.0`**. Y en su lugar debería utilizarse las extensiones **`MySQLi`** o **`PDO_MySQL`** .

**Ejemplo:**

```
 <?php
    $cons_usuario="root";
    $cons_contra="";
    $cons_base_datos="test";
    $cons_equipo="localhost";
    
    $obj_conexion = 
    mysqli_connect($cons_equipo,$cons_usuario,$cons_contra,$cons_base_datos);
    if(!$obj_conexion)
    {
        echo "<h3>No se ha podido conectar PHP - MySQL, verifique sus datos.</h3><hr><br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h3>Conexion Exitosa PHP - MySQL</h3><hr><br>";
    }
    
    /* ejemplo de una consulta */

    $var_consulta= "select * from tabla_prueba";
    $var_resultado = $obj_conexion->query($var_consulta);

    if($var_resultado->num_rows>0)
      {
        echo"<table border='1' align='center'>
         <tr bgcolor='#E6E6E6'>
            <th>Campo1</th>
            <th>Campo2</th>
            <th>Campo3</th>
            <th>Campo5</th>
            <th>Campo5</th>
        </tr>";
    
    while ($var_fila=$var_resultado->fetch_array())
    {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$var_fila["campo_uno"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$var_fila["campo_dos"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$var_fila["campo_tres"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$var_fila["campo_cuatro"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$var_fila["campo_cinco"]."</td></tr>";
     }
    }
    else
      {
        echo "No hay Registros";
      }

    ?>
```

Comment: Karla, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @karla kurosaki podrias describir mas como llegaste a esta solución

Comment: lo que pasa es que la extensión "mysql_connect()",  fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. Y en su lugar debería utilizarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL.