# no puedo conectar a mi sistemas por este error:

Tags: php

**Código:**

```
<?php function Conectarse() { 
// if (!($enlace=mysql_connect("localhost","root","274053"))) 
      if (!($enlace=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root", "ciievaluos")))
// if (!($enlace=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","may10ind_userbd","274053@2018"))) { 
      echo "ERROR EN LA CONEXION: NUEVOS ELEMENTOS HAN SIDO CREADOS"; exit(); } 
   if (!mysql_select_db("ciievaluos",$enlace)) { 
   // echo "ERROR EN LA CONEXION BD"; 
   echo "#1146 - Something is wrong in its syntax near 'JOIN' on line 1"; exit(); } 
   return $enlace; } ?>
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\avaluosyempenos\conectar.php:6
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\avaluosyempenos\login.php(5):
>   Conectarse() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\avaluosyempenos\conectar.php on line 6

Comment: este es mi codigo: <?php

function Conectarse()
{ 
 // if (!($enlace=mysql_connect("localhost","root","*274053*")))
 if (!($enlace=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root", "ciievaluos")))
 // if (!($enlace=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","may10ind_userbd","*274053@2018*")))
 {
 echo "ERROR EN LA CONEXION: NUEVOS ELEMENTOS HAN SIDO CREADOS";
 exit();
 }
 if (!mysql_select_db("ciievaluos",$enlace))
 {
 // echo "ERROR EN LA CONEXION BD";
 echo "#1146 - Something is wrong in its syntax near 'JOIN' on line 1";
 exit();
 }
return $enlace;
}
?>

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP usas?

Comment: Hola Franklin, edite la pregunta y coloque el código allí para que todos podamos verlo y poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Franklin. Por favor, tabula correctamente el código (es ilegible, hay comentarios por ahi en medio) ya que no queda claro que sea correcto... Sospecho que hay un } de más, y eso es debido a que el código es ilegible. Edita el post principal, pon el código bien tabulado y te podremos ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Quisa este link te pueda ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100239/por-qué-me-sale-el-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect#answer-100253 , el error puede ser por motivos de versiones de php.

Answer (score 2):

## Funciones obsoletas

La notificación de error obedece a que las funciones mencionadas en ella no existen y de acuerdo a lo explicado en la documentación oficial de PHP, las funciones [`mysql_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php) y [`mysql_select_db`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db) han sido declaradas obsoletas en **PHP 5.5.0** y eliminadas a partir de la **versión 7.0.0**.

En ese caso, podrías utilizar [`mysqli_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) en su lugar, implementando  el siguiente ejemplo:

```php
$enlace = mysqli_connect("host", "usuario", "contraseña", "base_de_datos");

if ( !$enlace ) {
  # Tus mensajes de errores

  exit();
}

// Se realiza una consulta SQL para obtener un recurso:
$recursos = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT * FROM `tabla`");

// Se almacena en un array la consulta anterior:
$registros = mysqli_fetch_array( $recursos ); 

// Se libera memoria:
mysqli_free_result( $recursos );

// Se cierra la conexión:
mysqli_close( $enlace );
```

O mediante *Programación Orientada a Objeto (POO, por sus siglas en inglés)* implementando el siguiente ejemplo:

```php
$enlace = new mysqli("host", "usuario", "contraseña", "base_de_datos");

if ( !$enlace ) {
  # Tus mensajes de errores, aunque no se recomienda en entornos de producción.

  # Terminar la ejecución del código si no se completa la conexión
  exit();
}

// Se realiza una consulta SQL para obtener un recurso:
$recursos = $enlace -> query("SELECT * FROM `tabla`");

// Se almacena en un array la consulta anterior:
$registros = $recursos -> fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );

// Se libera memoria:
$recursos -> free();

// Se cierra la conexión:
$enlace -> close();
```

Si desea ampliar sobre este tema puede consultar [Extensión MySQL mejorada](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)  desde la página oficial de PHP.

**Nota:** esta respuesta es orientativa sobre cómo conectarse a una base de datos `MySQL` con PHP utilizando la funcion `mysqli_connect()` o la clase `mysqli`. De ninguna manera, se puede considerar como una solución definitiva al problema planteado. Siempre existirán mejores soluciones.