# call to undefined function mysql_connect

Tags: php

**Hola chicos soy nuevo en esto de php y programacion en general y me estoy creando una tiendita online haber que sale pero me quede pegado por 2 horas en este error mirando la pantalla sin poder solucionarlo espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias de ante mano.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Todas las funciones `mysql_*` están obsoletas desde hace algunos años en PHP y desde la versión 7 de este han sido removidas, en tu caso seguro tienes una versión reciente del lenguaje y por eso no la reconoce, teclea en la consola `php -v` y agregalo a tu pregunta, del mismo modo sugiero te migres a MySQLi o PDO, ambos métodos nativos y funcionales para conectarte a bases de datos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué me sale el error "Call to undefined function mysql\_connect()"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100239/por-qu%c3%a9-me-sale-el-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect)

Answer (score 0):

Verifica la versión php que usas, el error dice que la variable mysql_connect no esta definida y facil es por que a partir de php 5.5 ya esta obsoleta, ahora es PDO o MysqlLi. puedes verificar eso desde tu consola colocando php -v o creando un archivo y colocando `phpinfo()` y luego lo abres y el mismo titulo te saldrá