# ejecutar un select enviando parametros via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código de AJAX que pasa variables de un formulario a otra página y muestra resultados.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form, #asigped').submit(function() {
      
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
    
            success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
                $('#result').html(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        })        
        return false;
    }); 
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" id="asigped" 
action="pedidos_clientes_asignapedidoscript.php" method="post" name="fo3">
<div class="form-title">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input name="pedidoid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ''.$pedidoid.'';?>">
  <label for="nropedidosistema">N&ordm; de Pedido del Sistema de 
   Tr&aacute;fico</label>
   <input type="text" name="nropedidosistema" class="form-control" 
   id="nropedidosistema" size="10">
   
   <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn label label-
    danger">Asignar</button></div>
    
   </div>
  </div>  
 </form>
 <div id="result"></div>
```

Esto funciona correctamente, pero lo que no logro es utilizar una variable para una query **`mySQL`**.

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$idpedido = $_POST['pedidoid'];

$p=mysql_query("SELECT id_pedido,id_pedido_trafico,id_cliente,id_sucursal,id_interno,emailconfirmacion 
                                  FROM pedidos_clientes WHERE id_pedido = '$idpedido'");
    while($rp= mysql_fetch_array($p)){
        $Email = $rp["emailconfirmacion"];
        $sucursal = $rp["id_sucursal"];
        $interno = $rp["id_interno"];
    }

?>
```

Es decir, no me devuelve ningún resultado.

Si hago `var_dump` a la variable `$idpedido` me muestra correctamente el resultado.

Comment: Prueba con `WHERE id_pedido = '".$idpedido."'");`

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en el formulario que pasas en el data del ajax?, De donde obtienes $id_pedido

Comment: Tengo un campo que contiene el valor que pasa como variable.
<input name="pedidoid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ''.$pedidoid.'';?>">

Comment: la mayoria de las veces que ocurre eso es netamente por errores en la consulta SQL, te recomiendo sacar los campos del SELECT y poner un * para probar si te envia algo, tambien es bueno probar la consulta directo en la DB para verificar que esta no contenga errores. Probaste haciendo un echo de la variable $id_pedido para ver si los datos llegan a la consulta?, es probable que se envien por ajax pero no se reciban

Comment: Ya probé eso. 
La variable pasa correctamente. 
Y la query también la revisé.

Comment: ¿Puede tener que ver algo con JSON?
Estoy leyendo y no entiendo demasiado.

Comment: veo en el php que no haces un echo de el html a regresar

Comment: Añade el código HTML del formulario, por favor. Si a los elementos no les pones el attributo name no serán incluidos en el POST.

Comment: Ya agregué el formulario en la pregunta.

Comment: La extensión `mysql_*`  es obsoleta. Es necesario actualizar tu código, usando PDO o MySQLi. Ver: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En **`AJAX`** si no haces un **`echo`** o un **`return`** desde php no estas "respondiendo" nada, es decir si el **PHP** que ejecuta el codigo no hace salida de lo que pides **`AJAX`** no te va a mostrar nada (Esto si el problema es que **`AJAX`** no muestra nada).

Yo te diría primero que hagas una variable donde guardes el query y luego lo muestras (para asegurarte que el query esta bien armado)

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT id_pedido,id_pedido_trafico,id_cliente,id_sucursal,id_interno,emailconfirmacion 
FROM pedidos_clientes WHERE id_pedido = '$idpedido'";
// Luego ejecutas el query, pero en tu caso hacemos echo del query para evaluar que esta bien armado.
echo $sql;
$p=mysql_query($sql);
//Si por aca todo esta bien simplemente sacas la data y la envias de regreso
while($rp= mysql_fetch_array($p)){
$Email = $rp["emailconfirmacion"];
$sucursal = $rp["id_sucursal"];
$interno = $rp["id_interno"];
}
//Podemos hacer un echo con todo o un arreglo (yo prefiero el arreglo se ve mas elegante y menos desordenado)
//El While cambiaria a:
$repuesta = array();
foreach ($rp as $key => $value) {
    $repuesta[$key]=$value;//asignamos todos los campos que te traes del select dentro de un arreglo
}
//enviamos el arreglo a ajax
print_r($repuesta);
?>
```

Cuando Ajax lo reciba haces lo que desees con los valores

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        success: function(data) {
        /* Si queremos solo el Email, o ponemos cada valor donde deseamos */
            $('#result').html(data.emailconfirmacion);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Funcionó! muchas gracias!

Comment: Sólo una cosa quería decir: no olvides escapar/sanear los datos recibidos desde el lado del cliente, para disminuir los riesgos.  

    `$sql=sprintf("SELECT id_pedido,
        id_pedido_trafico,
        id_cliente,
        id_sucursal,
        id_interno,
        emailconfirmacion 
    FROM pedidos_clientes 
    WHERE id_pedido = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($idpedido));`
  
Lo ideal sería que dejes de utilizar la extension <strike>mysql</strike>, que en php 7.x ya no existe, y migres hacia **mysqli** o **PDO**. 
Saludos

Comment: @Asero82 Muy cierto eso, solo que me limite a mi repuesta, mysql ya no es recomendable usarlo, en su caso mysqli, No recomiendo PDO porque PDO es un estándar bastante genérico, y quizás no abarque todas las posibilidades que puedes hacer utilizando la librería directa de MySQL (mysqli), y también es bastante recomendable limpiar los valores que se reciben de ajax para evitar filtrar data errónea o inyecciones de SQL, Gracias Asero!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que simplemente te falta entregar los resultados..
Si en javascript haces:

```
$('#result').html(data);
```

lo que te falta en php (al final) es hacer el "echo".. por ejemplo:

```
echo "Registro insertado, el email es " . $Email . " la sucursal " . $sucursal . "<br/>";
```

O algo así..

Comment: Eso ya lo hice y los valores son NULL.

Comment: Probá poner el echo antes del cierre de la ultima llave... agrega el id para verlo.. por ejemplo: echo "Busco id " . $idpedido . " y tengo  mail=" . $Email;

Answer (score 0):

Pues aparentemente no estas devolviendo nada de vuelta, sería algo así

```
echo $Email . ' ' . $sucursal . ' ' . $interno;
```

Con eso recibirías los resultados en el `data` que devuelve la función `success`

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Eso ya lo hice y los valores son NULL.

Comment: intenta colocar un try catch y ver si te devuelve el error probablemente hay algo mas

Comment: Donde colocaste el echo, dentro o fuera del while ? Si lo colocaste afuera intenta colocándolo adentro y prueba !

Comment: @CamiloVasquez intenta colocar el ejemplo lo mas completo y limpio posible