# Error al descargar el archivo xml

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // Datos de conexión a la base de datos
    require('mysql_connect.script.php');
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
    // PARAMETRO ENVIADO 
    $id        = $_GET['id'];
    $PDFtoDwnld = "file.xml";
    $consulta  = "SELECT * FROM detalle3 WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion, $consulta);
    $row       = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $contenido = $row["xml"];
    $row        = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $PDFtoDwnld = $row["ruc"] ."-". $row["tipdoc"] ."-". $row["serdoc"] ."-". 
 $row["numdoc"].".".substr($header,-3);
    $contenido  = $row[$PDFtoDwnld];
    header("Content-type: application/xml");
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$PDFtoDwnld.'"'); 
    echo $contenido;
?>
```

la idea es al descargar debe concadenar RUC-TIPO-SERIE-NUMERO FACTURA

Comment: Al parecer no incluiste el error; colocalo para que quien sepa del mismo te oriente.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error? ¿Te percataste de que estás perdiendo el valor `$contenido = $row["xml"];` porque aquí no concatenas: `$contenido  = $row[$PDFtoDwnld];`? Creo que debería ser: **`$contenido .= $row[$PDFtoDwnld];`**

Answer (score 0):

Por el momento tu código tiene algunos problemas:

1. **Estás mezclando dos extensiones diferentes**: `mysql_*` (la cual es obsoleta y su uso no se recomienda) y `mysqli`. (Ver [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967))
2. **Estás perdiendo el valor de la columna `xml`.** Al hacer primero: `$contenido = $row["xml"];` y luego `$contenido = $row[$PDFtoDwnld];` estás perdiendo los datos de la columna `xml`. Si quieres que esos datos estén en `$contenido` debes escribir esto: `$contenido .= $row[$PDFtoDwnld];`. En PHP se concatena poniendo **`.=`**. Si no pones el punto, la variable se inicializa y adquiere el nuevo valor, olvidando el anterior.
3. Como supongo que harás, pasa todo el código a MySQLi y usa **consultas preparadas**, pues esta consulta `$consulta  = "SELECT * FROM detalle3 WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";` es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. (Ver [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967))

Comment: al descargar el archivo lo hace vacio sin el contenido del xml y un posible error q me dices es en la variable contenido y me modifique mi consulta verdad

Comment: Por lo dicho en el punto `1` es imposible que tu código funcione, pues estás mezclando dos APIs diferentes: `mysql_` y `mysqli_`  no es lo mismo.  [Aquí tienes ejemplos](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) de cómo se usa `mysqli`, debes escribir todo el código en `mysqli` en primer lugar. Luego aplicar lo que digo en el punto `2`. Y cuando todo funcione, entonces piensa en aplicar la sugerencia del  punto `3` si no quieres que un hacker te inyecto código malicioso.