# Error de conexión en mi aplicacion

Tags: php

El código que estoy usando en el php es el siguiente:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("No se encuentra el servidor");
mysql_select_db("agenda");
```

El error que me bota es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\conexion.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\conexion.php on line 3

He revisado el archivo `config.inc.php` para verificar el usuario y el password de la bd y efectivamente están bien escritos.
Quisiera saber por qué no puede conectar estando bien el host, user y pass.

Comment: Porque estás usando una función obsoleta: `mysql*`. Se recomienda usar PDO o [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php). Ver: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)

Comment: Este error ocurre por una de dos: o no tienes activada la extensión de mysql o estás usando una versión de PHP en la que dicha extensión ha sido eliminada. En cualquier caso, como te dice A. Cedano, no deberías estar usando las funciones mysql_*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leyendo tu error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect()

Se puede comprender que ocurre lo que ya indica el [Manual de PHP sobre la extensión `mysql*`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php):

> **Advertencia** Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y **eliminada en PHP 7.0.0**. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL. Véase también la guía MySQL: elegir
>   una API y sus P+F relacionadas para más información.

El `undefined function` indica que tu versión de PHP ya no cuenta con esa extensión.

Como dice la advertencia, es recomendable usar PDO o MySQLi.

En el Manual de PHP encontrarás ejemplos de código para usar cualquiera de las dos, que te permitirán escribir código más seguro y robusto.

Por ejemplo, para conectar con MySQLi:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
```

Y para consultar:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM books ORDER BY id";   
$resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);
```

---

[Aquí tienes un ejemplo de uso](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ck5y-jc3j) en línea con comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar de esta manera que seria la forma correcta para conectarte

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("No se encuentra el servidor");
mysql_select_db($link, 'agenda');
```

Answer (score -3):

Trata de checar bien tus conexiones locales de xampp o similar y tus carpetas creadas en tu disco local y tratar de instalar bien tu phpmyadmin ya que por lo que veo no has hecho bien el procedimiento de instalación

Comment: Por favor, no escribas todo en mayúsculas, es más difícil de leer y en internet las mayúsculas se consideran gritos. Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones sobre cómo mejorar tus respuestas. Un saludo.