# Error con la conexion

Tags: php, mysql, json

introducir el código aquí estoy creando una búsqueda autocompletable con json, mysql y php pero me muestra este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Horarios\paginas\registro1.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Horarios\paginas\registro1.php on line 2

la consulta esta bien, agradezco su ayuda.

```
<?php
    $con  = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("cursos", $conxion);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE tipousuario='Docente' ORDER BY nombre ASC", $con);
    $array = array();
    if($result){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $equipo = utf8_encode($row['nombre']);
            array_push($array, $equipo);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error de conexión phpmyadmin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111470/error-de-conexi%c3%b3n-phpmyadmin). El error ***Call to undefined function mysql_connect()*** viene dado porque la extensión `mysql.*` no viene en el core a partir de  PHP 7, la misma fue declarada obsoleta por varios motivos graves y eliminada definitivamente de PHP 7+. Se recomienda migrar el código a mysqli o a PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te indica que ***la función no esta definida***.

Si la llamada a la función está bien escrita, y dado que es una función nativa, el problema puede ser debido a que la estás llamando bajo un espacio de nombres, cambia la llamada a:
$con = \mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

Otra posibilidad es que uses PHP 7 o superior, si miras la [documentación de PHP de la función](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php) tienes un mensaje que empieza así:

> Advertencia
>
> Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP
>   7.0.0.

Sigue las recomendaciones de la documentación y deja de usar ***mysql*** que lleva años deprecada y ya se eliminó.