# Conexión MySQL Workbench y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Tengo un proyecto en cual estoy trabajando con MySQL Workbench y PHP, pido su ayuda para revisar mi código ya que tengo problemas al realizar la conexión a mi Base de Datos.

Datos de BD:

- User: root
- Pass: ''
- BD: admin

Código:

```
<?php

$conect = mysql_connect('localhost','administracion','admin'):
$queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM mydb.administracion';
$query = mysql_query($queryStr);
$resultado = mysql_fetch_row($query);
mysql_close($conect);

?>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error de conexión phpmyadmin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111470/error-de-conexi%c3%b3n-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Esto es un fallo tipográfico. Tienes un `:` donde debería haber un `;`

Answer (score 1):

No conecta bien porque le estas pasando el nombre de la base de datos como usuario. Hay que meter el host y el nombre de la base de datos en el mismo campo.

```
<?php
    $conect = mysql_connect('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=administracion','root','admin');
    $queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM mydb.administracion';
    $query = mysql_query($queryStr);
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    mysql_close($conect);
?>
```

Utiliza mejor mysqli:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","administracion");
// Comprueba conexión
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//Aquí las querys
$result =  mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mydb.administracion");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo $row . "<br>";
        }
     } else {
        echo "0 resultados";
     }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, gracias por responder. El código aún me marca error en la linea 2

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\xampp\htdocs\concorde\connect_db.php on line 2

Comment: @Oscar_DR El error esta al final de la linea 2 en vez de ; he escrito :

Comment: Ya lo corregui, me percate de ese error pero aun asi  sale un error         Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\concorde\connect_db.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\concorde\connect_db.php on line 2

Comment: Si tu versión de PHP es mayor de 7 no puedes usar mysql_connect tienes que usar mysqli_connect