# No me conecta la página con la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo una página y cuando intento validar usuario y contraseña no me ingresa al menú.
Y aparte que no sea inyectable.

Voy a dejar los php en la pregunta.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apuestas</title>
    <!--Sensible a los dispositivos móviles, funcion de zoom táctil, añada el siguiente <meta>-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">-->
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#TxtNombreUsuario").keydown(function(){ $("#error").text(""); });
            $("#TxtContrasena").keydown(function(){ $("#error").text(""); });
            $("#BtnValidar").click(function(evento){
                if ( $.trim($("#TxtNombreUsuario").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#TxtContrasena").val()) == "" ){
                    $("#error").text("DEBE INGRESAR USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA");
                    evento.preventDefault();
                } 
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">

    <h1>Apuestas en línea</h1>
    <p>Para disfrutar todo el tiempo</p>    
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><label>Nombre de Usuario:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="TxtNombreUsuario" name="TxtNombreUsuario" autofocus size="20"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="right"><label>Contraseña:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" id="TxtContrasena" name="TxtContrasena" size="20"></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <label><span class="error" id="error"></span></label>

        <table>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="BtnValidar" name="BtnValidar" value="Validar"></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </center>           
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**validar.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'Conexion.php';
    // Esta estructura es un if, antes de ? la condicion, a continuacion la parte verdadera y despues de los dos puntos la parte falsa
    $usuario  = isset($_POST["TxtNombreUsuario"]) ? $_POST["TxtNombreUsuario"] : "";
    $contrasena = isset($_POST["TxtContrasena"]) ? $_POST["TxtContrasena"] : "";

    if ( $usuario == "" or $contrasena == "" )
        {
        //echo "Prueba";

        header("Location: index.php");
        } else 
            {
            //en este punto debo traer los el nombre de usuario y contraseña de la base de datos 

            include 'Conexion.php';

            $nombre = $_POST["Usuario"]; 
            $password = $_POST["Clave"]; 

            $consulta = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario = \''.$nombre.'\' AND Clave = \''.$password.'\'');

            if(!$consulta)
                { 
                echo "Usuario no existe"; 
                } 
            else{ 
                print "Bienvenido"; 
                } 
            }
?>
```

---

**Conexion.php**

```
<?php
    $host_db = "localhost";
    $user_db = "root";
    $pass_db = "";
    $db_name = "apuestas";
    $tbl_name = "usuarios";

    $form_pass = $_POST['password'];

    /*$hash = password_hash($form_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);*/ 

    $conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

    if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
    }

    $buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name
    WHERE Usuario = '$_POST[username]' ";

    $result = $conexion->query($buscarUsuario);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1) 
        {
        header("Location: menu.php");
        }
        else
            {
            header("Location: index.php");
            }
?>
```

---

**menu.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apuestas</title>
    <!--Sensible a los dispositivos móviles, funcion de zoom táctil, añada el siguiente <meta>-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php 
    echo'ÉSTE ES EL MENÚ';
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

En la base de datos tengo los siguientes datos:

Id_Usuario, Usuario, Clave, Nombres, Apellidos, Identificacion, Sexo, Telefono, Correo, Perfil, Estado.

Algún dato aparte que me haya faltado me pueden decir para agregarlo.

Comment: Si estás usando PHP 7, debes saber que la extensión `mysql*` que usas para consultar la base de datos no funcionará. Y aunque no tengas PHP 7 se recomienda migrar el código a `mysqli` o a PDO. Para más detalles consulta: **[¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)**

Comment: Listo, yo lo corrijo. ¿Es por eso que no funciona?

Comment: Si tu versión de PHP es la 7 no funcionará por eso seguro. Lo cual no quiere decir que pueda haber otros errores. Sería bueno que revises el log de errores (es una archivo que se suele llamar `error_log`). También  otra cosa, evita el uso de `@` en el código... es una mala práctica porque cuando ocurren errores no te los notifica, haciendo el programa difícil de depurar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No envias los datos a validar por que no tienes un `form`

```
<form method="POST" action="validar.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><label>Nombre de Usuario:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="TxtNombreUsuario" name="TxtNombreUsuario" autofocus size="20"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="right"><label>Contraseña:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" id="TxtContrasena" name="TxtContrasena" size="20"></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <label><span class="error" id="error"></span></label>

        <table>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="BtnValidar" name="BtnValidar" value="Validar"></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
```

Otra detalle es que tu consulta trae mas de un usuario por lo que si existe otro usuario con el mismo nombre podria tener otra contraseña y tu accidentalmente podrias comprar incorrectamente.

Comment: Ahora me sale éste error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\apuestas\Conexion.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\apuestas\validar.php(3): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\apuestas\Conexion.php on line 2`

Comment: No está habilitada la extención MySQL habilitala

Comment: @FOX ya te lo dije amigo, la extensión `mysql_*` no funciona en PHP 7. Debes migrar todo tu código de conexión y consultas a la BD a Mysqli o a PDO. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo con explicaciones](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ck5y-jc3j)

Comment: es cierto si usas php7  ese codigo no funcionara si es menor puedes habilitar la extencion

Comment: ¿Cómo la habilito? la verdad soy un poco nuevo en esto. ¿Me podrían ayudar por favor.?. Ya estoy leyendo lo que @A.Cedano dejó, pero poco voy entendiendo cómo.

Comment: @FOX creo que no tienes que habilitar nada, sino cambiar el código. En el enlace del comentario anterior tienes un ejemplo de cómo usar `mysqli`. El código está comentado, para que entiendas su uso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Listo, ya me pongo en eso. Cualquier duda los estaré molestando por acá. Gracias.

Comment: @FOX. No hay problema. Ese ejemplo no usa consultas preparadas, que es la práctica correcta para consultas con criterios tomados desde fuentes externas al código... pero será un buen comienzo. Luego será fácil implementar las consultas preparadas. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano , ya corregí la conexión, incluso me ingresó pero en validar me sacaba error, ahora corregí los errores pero no me deja ingresar.

Comment: Como quedo tu codigo ?

Comment: @SergioCauich , corregí la pregunta en la parte de `Conexion.php`, eso fue lo que corregí, la conexión.

Comment: pero en **validar.php** aun no usas mysqli a menos que ya lo estés haciendo y no has actualizado esa parte.

Comment: No, no lo he puesto, ¿es sólo poner `mysqli` o debo poner toda la sentencia de `mysqli -> etc...`?

Comment: Claro que si pero primero lee http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php y http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php y si tienes dudas con mucho gusto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67687/discussion-between-fox-and-sergio-cauich).