# Cargar elemento <select> con ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, select

Deseo realizar una consulta y recogerlo tanto en una caja de texto como en un select. Puedo capturar la consulta en una caja de texto, pero no en el select.

Index.php

```
<script>
function cargar_energia(){
  //var n =  document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var datos={
                "nombre": $("#nombre").val(),
              }

        $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'prueba_consulta.php',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',   
        //data: {nombre:n},
        success: function(d){
           $("#respa").val(d[0]);// ID de la 1era caja de texto
           $("#respa2").val(d[1]); // ID de la 2da caja de texto

            }

        });
        return false;
}
</script>


<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" size="30" name="" id="nombre">
  <input type="button" name="" value="enviar" onclick="cargar_energia()">

</form>


  <input type="text" id="respa"><br>
  <select id="respa2"></select>//Aca desearia cargar la otra opcion
```

prueba_consulta.php

```
<?php
//************ conexion a BD ***************
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("mantenimiento",$con);

 $filtro=$_POST["nombre"];
 $rs= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registro_energia_temp WHERE nombre_site like '%$filtro%' order by id_energia desc ;"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre_site'], $row['fecha_manto_energia']);
echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);

?>
```

Comment: Usa las etiquetas o es ilegible

Comment: ¿Qué te regresa tu consulta de ajax y que es lo que quieres capturar en el select, o qué pretendes hacer con el select una vez obtienes la respuesta del servidor?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te muestra en el select luego de ejecutar el ajax?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/250) y que te informes sobre [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10518/250) y [cómo evitarla en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/250). El código que compartes presenta vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad, puede sufrir de este tipo de ataques y no debería usarse en un entorno de producción.

Comment: quiero que al igual me recoge en en el input text y me lo muestra. me recoja tambien en el <select option> y que me lo muestre. Por ahora no muestra nada el <select> </select>. Esto es solo un ejemplo basico, de ahí lo llevaré a gran escala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para añadir contenido a un `select` debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<script>
function cargar_energia(){
  //var n =  document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var datos={
                "nombre": $("#nombre").val(),
              }

        $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'prueba_consulta.php',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',   
        //data: {nombre:n},
        success: function(d){
           $("#respa").val(d[0]);// ID de la 1era caja de texto
           $("#respa2").html('<option value="'+ d[1] +'">'+ d[1] +'</option>'); // ID de la 2da caja de texto

            }

        });
        return false;
}
</script>
```

Como puedes ver lo que debes hacer es agregar una etiqueta `option` al `select` con la información que deseas mostrar, que en este caso es la que te devuelve la petición `ajax`.

Comment: Excelente. Salio. gracias