# Cómo obtener la diferencia entre dos días

Tags: javascript

He seguido unos ejemplos que he encontrado pero no me ha dado resutado.
Lo que quiero obtener es la diferencia de dos fechas en días:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
    var fechares = resp[i].fecha_registro;
    console.log(fechares.diff(fecha, ' dias de diferencia')); // puse esto pero marca error fechares.diff is not a function

    html += '<tr><td data-id="' + resp[i].id + '">' + resp[i].fecha_registro +
        '</td><td data-id="' + resp[i].id + '">' + resp[i].contacto_nombre +
        '</td><td data-id="' + resp[i].id + '">' + resp[i].modelo +
        '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: te debe estar faltando la librería fijate https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114857/81450

Comment: <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
Esa es la libreria que puse

Comment: -86400000 eso me imprime en la consola cuando es del día de ayer

Comment: seguramente, es la cantidad de milisegundos. para pasarlos a horas o minutos fijate el manual de moment y ahi tenes varias opciones

Comment: grarcias amigo lo mejor que hice fue dividir esos milisegundos y ya me da los días

Answer (score 0):

con la libería [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) puedes manipular las fechas fácilmente, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
var fecha1 = moment('2018-01-01');
var fecha2 = moment('2018-01-04');

console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days'));
```

Recuerda que en el método **moment.diff** debes indicar el tipo de intervalo que quieres, en este caso es *'days'*.

No te olvides de importar la librería:

```
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```