# Error Php Comentarios

Tags: php, mysql

Hola chicos tengo este pequeno error podrian ayudarme a resolverlo

```
if ($conexion)
{
    $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT id, usuario, fecha, mensaje FROM comentarios ORDER BY id DESC", $conexion);
    while ($fila = mysql_fetch_row($resultado))
    {
        echo "<B>Mensaje</B> #" . $fila[0] . "; ";
        echo "<B>Escrito por:</B> " . $fila[1] . "; ";
        echo "<B>Fecha:</B> " . $fila[2] . "; ";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo $fila[3];
        echo "<HR>";
    }
}
```

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\comentarios.php on line 66

Comment: `boolean given`  te indica que al ejecutar la consulta estás obteniendo un booleano, no unos resultados, y por tanto el `fetch` fallará. El error puede deberse a algún error en tu consulta (algo mal escrito) o a un problema en la conexión. Ahora bien, la extensión `mysql_*`  que estás usando es obsoleta (Puedes leer: **[¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967))**. Pone en riesgo los datos y dejará de funcionar próximamente. Se recomienda pasar a `PDO` o a la extensión `mysqli`, que es muy parecida a esta, pero más moderna y más segura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resultado` es false. Significa que algo falló. Eso puedes debugguearlo como

```
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT id, usuario, fecha, mensaje FROM comentarios ORDER BY id DESC", $conexion);

if (!$resultado) {
    die('Consulta no válida: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Pero en vez de reparar ese código, yo te recomendaría mejor buscar un tutorial más moderno. El tiempo que inviertes en aprender a usar el antiguo y abandonado conector mysql es tiempo perdido.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta  pero cuando hice los cambios sucedio otro problema 
<quote>
if ($conexion)
{
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO comentarios (usuario, mensaje) VALUES ('".$_POST["usuario"]."', '".$_POST["mensaje"]."')", $conexion);
 header("Location: comentarios.php");
}

mysql_close($conexion);

?>
</quote>
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\procesar_mensaje.php:1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\procesar_mensaje.php on line 9

Comment: Ese código no se parece en nada al de tu pregunta. Pero efectivamente, no puedes tirar un header de redirección si se ha impreso un error en pantalla.

Comment: es que tengo dos comunicaciones dentro uno de comentarios con html y uno con conexion para insertar los datos quiero repararlo la rura esta correrta pero no se por que no lo publica le doy publicar y sale ese error lo siento voy empezando con php