# error al ingresar datos en PHP

Tags: php

Perdón por la molestia yo estoy comenzando a programar en PHP, tengo que ingresar datos a una base de datos MySQL, pero me salta un error de que los datos no pudieron ser ingresados. Les envío la parte del código donde me arroja el error.

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO registros(rut, nombre, apellido, email, contraseña) VALUES
('15342320K', 'Fabian', 'Ruiz', 'p.ruis@gmail.com', 'FR2016')";

$ejecutar = mysql_query($consulta,$conexion) or die('Error al insertar datos');
echo "Se insertaron los datos correctamente";
```

Hasta ahi todo funciona correctamente. Desde ya muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: El error que te despliega, es el mensaje que tienes en el "die" o es diferente? Ya revisaste los tipos de datos que estas insertando, contra el tipo de columna en la db?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP?, si es superior a la versión 7 tu código no va a funcionar, porque la extensión `mysql_*` fue sacada del core a partir de esa versión. Puedes leer al respecto: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967). En cualquier caso, deberías migrar a PDO o a MySQLi, y usar consultas preparadas, ya que como tienes ahora el código, es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL.

Comment: Está todo revisado, el problema está ahí, en esa parte del código, y ya me di por vencido. La versión de PHP es 5

Comment: A ver, no tienes por qué darte por vencido. Si quieres saber por qué no funciona prueba esto: **`if (!$conexion) {
    die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error());
}else{$ejecutar = mysql_query($consulta,$conexion) or die('Error al insertar datos: ' . mysql_error());
echo "Se insertaron los datos correctamente";}`**

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in H:\xampp\htdocs\Taller_PHP\sesion 5\error.php on line 3
No pudo conectarse:

Comment: <?php

if(!$conexion) { die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error()); 
}else{
 $ejecutar = mysql_query($consulta,$conexion) or die('Error al insertar datos: '. mysql_error());
echo "Se insertaron los datos correctamente";}
 
?>

Comment: Marcelo, por el mensaje de error que obtuviste, parece ser que no has declarado la variable $conexion. Otra posibilidad es que en alguna otra parte de tu codigo, posiblemente en la linea 3 del archivo error.php, hayas olvidado ponerle el signo de dolar ($) a la variable conexion. Es algo bastante comun.

Comment: Exacto, revisa la **línea 3** del archivo `error.php`. Te dice que la variable `$conexion` no está definida. ¿La habrás definido con otro nombre, habrás usado un acento? Como ves, el mensaje de error te dice dónde tienes que revisar.

Comment: No hay caso probé con todas las opciones que me enviaron y nada, no me hace la inserción de datos en la BD.