# Transacciones o consultas preparadas en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y de momento según viendo para trabajar con base de datos los podemos de hacer de dos maneras(según lo que me voy enterando, corregirme en cualquier caso):

-mysqli
      -Por procedimientos
      -Por objetos

-PDO

Mediante estos dos métodos podemos hacer conexión a la base de datos y una vez establecida la conexión podemos hacer CRUD (INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE), sobre la misma.

Este CRUD entiendo que lo podemos hacer de 3 maneras:
     -Forma directa
     -Por transacciones
     -Por consultas preparadas

La pregunta duda que tengo es. ¿Cuando y o en que casos se debería o seria conveniente usar una u otra forma?

A ver si alguien me puede aclarar un poco conceptos.
Gracias

Comment: Para que nos entendamos, vamos a agrupar lo que preguntas. **1.De forma directa**: Debes usar consultas preparadas **siempre** que en la consulta intervengan datos que provienen de fuentes externas, para protegerte de esa forma de la inyección de código. **2.  Transacciones** se usan generalmente cuando vas a operar con muchos datos o datos por lotes. Supongamos que estás haciendo `CRUD` sobre un lote de datos y por algún motivo el código falla sin concluir el proceso. ¿Cómo sabrás los datos entraron en la BD y los que no? La transacción revertirá todo lo que se ha hecho hasta el momento...

Comment: Pdo es el sustituto de mysqli está obsoleto  mysqli tiene muchas vulnerabilidades

Comment: ... si hay algún fallo, asegurando así consistencia en tu base de datos. He tratado de responder brevemente a tu pregunta y creo que responder con más detalles sería un tema muy amplio.

Comment: @JackNavaRow, el que está obsoleto es `mysql_*`, no `mysqli`. [Puedes ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967) para más detalles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a responder a tu pregunta tratando de ser objetivo y breve:

### ► a. De forma directa

Una consulta se debe pasar al manejador de base de datos de forma directa **únicamente** si en dicha consulta no interviene ningún dato desde el exterior, debido a que ese dato que introduce el usuario puede ser manipulado o modificado por un usuario mal intencionado para preparar un inyección de código malicioso.

Un ejemplo de consulta que se puede pasar sin riesgo directamente, debido a que el parámetro `5` viene escrito en la consulta sería:

```
SELECT id, nombre FROM tabla WHERE id=5;
```

Sin embargo, si el 5 es pasado en una variable, no puedes pasar la consulta directamente:

<s>`SELECT id, nombre FROM tabla WHERE id=$id;`</s>`//riesgo grave de inyección`

Esa inyección se podría producir no solamente a nivel de SQL, sino a otros niveles del sistema.

---

### ► b. Por medio de consultas preparadas

Inversamente a lo afirmado en ***a***, las consultas preparadas se deben usar **siempre** que en la consulta intervengan datos provenientes de fuentes externas. La API que estés usando como intermediario entre el programa y la base de datos (PDO o MySQLi) se encargará de eliminar el riesgo de inyección, **si usas bien esta metodología**.

Por ejemplo, esta es una consulta segura:

```
$strSQL="SELECT id, nombre FROM tabla WHERE id=?";
$stmt=$pdo->prepare($strSQL);
$arrParams=array($id);
$stmt->execute($arrParams);
```

En cambio esta consulta no es segura, ya podrás saber por qué:

```
$strSQL="SELECT id, nombre FROM tabla WHERE id=? OR id=$id";
$stmt=$pdo->prepare($strSQL);
$arrParams=array($id);
$stmt->execute($arrParams);
```

Eso quiere decir que no basta usar consultas preparadas, también hay que usarlas de la manera adecuada.

Además, en el caso de PDO, debes asegurarte que el atributo de emulación de consultas está apago (`FALSE`), porque de lo contrario te podrían colar una inyección emulando consultas preparadas.

---

### ► c. Transacciones

En pocas palabras, se usan cuando necesitas manejar lotes de datos en tu CRUD. Supongamos que vas a hacer una inserción o actualización de mil o un  millón de registros. Empiezas el proceso y en algún punto hay un fallo. ¿Cómo vas a saber los registros que se insertaron/actualizaron? Podrías perder semanas/meses comparando datos para saber los que tienes que insertar/actualizar y los que no. Las transacciones te permiten manejar ese proceso de forma segura y limpia, ya que si algo falla, puedes revertir todo lo que se ha hecho hasta ahora.

En la transacción tú le dices a la BD: *hazme todo esto, o no me hagas nada*.

Lo de las transacciones, el Manual de PHP te lo explica muy bien aquí: [Transacciones y autoconsigna ("auto-commit")](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.transactions.php)

De todo esto se puede hablar mucho más. Yo quise dar una respuesta breve, que de una idea de las diferencias de uso.

Comment: Muchas gracias A.Cedano. Me has aclaro la pregunta. Es la segunda vez que me contestas y muy buenas las repuestas. Gracias un saludo