# Contar y mostrar el número de registros que cumplen una condición

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo sería la forma correcta de saber y mostrar el número de registros que hay en una tabla que cumplan una determinada condición?

He probado con lo siguiente para mostrar el número de registros sin ninguna condición pero no muestra nada.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM avisos";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$numero = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $numero;
?>
```

Comment: Hay varias formas. Por lo general se hace la consulta así: `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM avisos`. Luego, no necesitas usar `num_rows`, que en este caso mostrará siempre `1`, sino que debes mostrar la columna `total`, que tendrá en este caso el total de filas encontradas. Con criterio sería lo mismo, lo único que cambiaría sería el criterio: `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM tabla WHERE columna=criterio`. Por otra parte, la extensión `mysql_*` que estás usando es obsoleta.

Comment: He probado esto y nada: $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM avisos";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $resultado;

Comment: Si tienes PHP 7 tu código no funcionará por lo que te dije al final de mi comentario. Y aunque no tengas PHP 7 recomendaría que cambies a `mysqli` ya que la extensión que usas está obsoleta. De todos modos prueba como te ha indicado @Marcos.

Comment: He probado como ha comentado @Marcos pero con mysqli_query y no lo consigo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Contar

Para contar los registros en una tabla según ciertas condiciones hay varias maneras de hacerlo. La más común es usando `COUNT(*)`.

Por ejemplo, si quieres contar todos los registros de una tabla:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM tabla;
```

Esta consulta arrojará una columna (a la cual le hemos dado el alias `total`), con la cantidad de filas que existen en la tabla.

El uso de criterios se aplica como se hace habitualmente, pues se trata de una consulta como cualquier otra.

Por ejemplo, si quieres contar los registros cuyo `id` sea mayor que `7`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM tabla WHERE id>7;
```

Se puede aplicar cualquier criterio, como se hace habitualmente.

---

## Código PHP

En cuanto al código PHP, respondo a tu pregunta indicando cómo se haría con la extensión `mysql_*`, a sabiendas de que la misma ha sido declarada obsoleta<sup>1</sup>. Se recomienda pasar a `mysqli` o a `PDO`, ya que con esta función la seguridad de los datos podría estar comprometida y porque este código no funcionará a partir de PHP 7.

### ► Usando `mysql`

Puedes valerte de `mysql_fetch_assoc`:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM avisos";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $fila['total'];
```

---

### ► Usando `mysqli`

El paso de `mysql` a `mysqli` es casi imperceptbile.

Crearías la conexión así:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
```

`$mysqli` sería un objeto conexión que usarás más adelante en el código.

Y para ejecutar el mismo código de más arriba, tienes dos posibilidades:

#### *A. Modo procedural*

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM avisos";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $fila['total'];
```

#### *B. Modo orientado a objetos*

Aunque el modo procedural es muy parecido a la manera acostumbrada de usar, debido a la antigua extensión, recomendaría que aprendas el estilo orientado a objetos. Es más moderno y adaptado a los tiempos actuales.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM avisos";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $fila['total'];
```

---

**NOTA:** Generalmente los resultados con los métodos `fetch` son leídos dentro de un bucle `while` en el que se va recorriendo el conjunto de resultados devuelto por la consulta. Aquí no se usa el bucle porque en los resultados se espera una sola fila y en esos casos se puede acceder a ella sin necesidad de recorrer los resultados en un bucle.

---

### ► Usando `PDO`

`PDO` cuenta con el método [`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), el cual podemos usar para casos en los que esperamos una sola columna como resultado.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM avisos";
$result = $pdo->query($sql); //$pdo sería el objeto conexión
$total = $result->fetchColumn();
echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $total;
```

---

#### Notas

1. Para más detalles puedes consultar la pregunta: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)

Comment: funciona correctamente, muchas gracias, la conexión normalmente la hago con PDO, como seria mysql_query y mysqli_fetch_assoc con PDO?

Comment: PDO, ¡qué maravilla! Es mucho mejor con PDO. Ahora edito la respuesta y te muestro el uso con PDO.

Comment: funciona a la perfeccion! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Considera la siguiente opción para contar por grupos, es decir si tienes una base de datos de ropa, contar cuanta ropa tienes por tipo de ropa, como playeras, pantalones, etc...

$sql = " select `ropa`, COUNT(*) from `inventario` group by `ropa`;