# Estoy creando un login y cuando intento logearme me aparece el msg de "no tiene acceso"

Tags: php

estoy creando un login y al verificar con la base de datos que el user esta registrado, se ve que algo no corre y en vez que salirme el mensaje de test diciendo "lograste acceder", me sale el de "no lograste acceder"

```
<?php
$msg="";
$email="";

if ( isset ($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
{
   if ($_POST['email']=="") {
    $msg="Debe ingresar un email<br>";
  }
  else if ($_POST['password']=="") {
    $msg.="Deberias ingresar pass";
  }
  else{
    $email=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password=sha1(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phptube");
    if ($mysqli==false) {
      echo " No pudo conectarse a la DB";
      die();
    }
    $resultado=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios_email`= '".$email."' AND `usuarios_password`='".$password."'");
    $usuarios=$resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//cuentos los elementos de mysql_list_tables
    $cantidad =count($usuarios);
    if ($cantidad == 1) {
      $hoy= date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
      $resultado=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `usuarios` SET`usuarios_ultimologin`= '".$hoy."' WHERE `usuarios_email`='".$email."'");
    $msg.="Lograste acceder!";
  }else{ $msg.="no tienes acceso";}

  }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: para validar si el query retorno valores es mas recomendable hacerlo con: $mysqli_result->num_rows; es decir: **$usuarios->num_rows**

Comment: Revisa qué datos está trayendo mediante un `var_dump($usuarios);`

Comment: Cedano, gracias por tu ayuda, al traer var_dump($usuarios); me aparece null una vez que completo el registro, y eso que en la DB aparece ok el registro...

Comment: @JeanCarlosGarcia eso reemplazaria a     $usuarios=$resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); .....................................................................x  $usuarios->num_rows o como seria la llamada?

Comment: Una cosa, en mysqli, `fetch_all` no te va a funcionar si no tienes instalado el drive `mysqlnd`. De todos modos puedes usar otros métodos para comprobar si ese usuario existe. Lo más efectivo, si no necesitas los datos, es hacer un `SELECT COUNT(*) ` y verificar si el total de filas es mayor que cero.

Comment: Lo que necesitaria seria comprobar que ese usuario existe, si es asi, el sistema lo deja entrar logeado, por eso necesitaria comprobar si el conteo de usuario es 1, en el if cantidad ==1, ya que eso demostraria que el user que puso su email, es un user y password que aparece en la base de datos, en caso de reemplazar el fetch_all, como seria ponerle el que usted me dijo? en que seccion de la linea de codigo? gracias

Comment: Sería algo como esto: **`$resultado=$mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios_email= '".$email."' AND usuarios_password ='".$password."'");
$fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
$cantidad =$fila['total'];
if ($cantidad > 0) {
    //código si hay registros
} else {
 //código si no hay registros    
}`** [Aquí hay más detalles sobre esto, en el apartado referente a `mysqli`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134237/29967)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Cedano, fue de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1):

prueba usando MySQLi:

```
    <?php
    $msg = "";
    $email = "";
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        if ($_POST['email'] == "") {
            $msg = "Debe ingresar un email<br>";
        } else if ($_POST['password'] == "") {
            $msg.="Deberias ingresar pass";
        } else {
            $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
            $password = sha1(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "phptube");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Falló la conexión failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
                exit();
            }
            $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios_email`= '{$email}' AND `usuarios_password`='{$password}'");
            $usuarios = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $cantidad = count($usuarios);
            if ($cantidad > 0) {
                $hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $resultado = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `usuarios` SET`usuarios_ultimologin`= '" . $hoy . "' WHERE `usuarios_email`='" . $email . "'");
                $msg.="Lograste acceder!";
            } else {
                $msg.="no tienes acceso";
            }
        }
    }
    echo $msg;
    ?>
```

Comment: De hecho si revisas el código, el OP ya esta usando mysqli

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Elias Fuentes! muy util el comentario

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 puntos importantes que deberías tener en cuenta a la hora de plantear un login:

- Las consultas deberían ser preparadas para evitar infección SQL, puedes revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)
- Las contraseñas en base de datos deberían estar cifradas, puedes revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166666/verificar-contrase%C3%B1a-con-php-y-db/166704#166704)

Ahora adaptemos el código, lo he comentado para que puedas entenderlo:

```
<?php
$msg="";
// $mail no es necesaria
/*$email="";*/

// con un isset es suficiente
if ( isset($_POST['email'], /*) && isset(*/ $_POST['password']) ) {
/*
   if ($_POST['email']=="") {
    $msg="Debe ingresar un email<br>";
  }
  else if ($_POST['password']=="") {
    $msg.="Deberías ingresar pass";
  } else {
*/
    // esto es innecesario
    //$email=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    //$password=sha1(strip_tags($_POST['password']));

    // cambiamos a interfaz OO que es lo que usas más adelante
    //$mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phptube");
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","phptube");

    // comprobamos si la conexión ha sido correcta
    /*if ($mysqli==false) {
      echo " No pudo conectarse a la DB";
      die();
    }*/
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error de Conexión (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    // Creamos una sentencia preparada solo con el email 
    // y añadimos LIMIT 1, para no seguir buscando cuando ya hemos encontrado un registro
    //$resultado=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios_email`= '".$email."' AND `usuarios_password`='".$password."'");
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios_email = ? LIMIT 1')) {
        // vinculamos los valores
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);

        // ejecutamos la sentencia
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            die("Falló la ejecución: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
        }

        // recuperamos los resultados
        if (!($resultado = $stmt->get_result())) {
            die("Falló la obtención del conjunto de resultados: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
        }

        // comprobamos si hay resultados y recuperamos la primera y unica fila
        /*usuarios=$resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);*/
        if (!$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $msg .= "No se encontró el usuario.";
        } else {
            // ahora comparamos las claves
            // aquí deberíamos utilizar password_verify si las claves son cifradas 
            if($row['usuarios_password'] == $_POST['password']){
                $msg.="Lograste acceder!";
                // actualizamos la fecha
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE usuarios SET usuarios_ultimologin = NOW() WHERE usuarios_email = '$row['usuarios_email']' ");
            } else {
                $msg.="Contraseña incorrecta!";
            }
        }
    } else {
        die('Error no se pudo preparar la consulta'); 
    }

    //cuentos los elementos de mysql_list_tables
    /*
    $cantidad =count($usuarios);
    if ($cantidad == 1) {
      $hoy= date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
      $resultado=$mysqli->query("UPDATE `usuarios` SET`usuarios_ultimologin`= '".$hoy."' WHERE `usuarios_email`='".$email."'");
      $msg.="Lograste acceder!";
    }else{ $msg.="no tienes acceso"; }
    */
/*  }*/
}
```

> Aunque he puesto varios `die()` para que te ayude a depurar estos deberían ser cambiados de forma que no se le muestre información al usuario sobre la base de datos para un entorno en producción

Documentación:

- [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)
- [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php)
- [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)
- [Sentencias Preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [die](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.die.php)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @xerif, me ha resultado muy util