# Login con sesiones para usuario y administrador no funciona

Tags: php, html5, login

La cuestión es que al dar clic en el botón Ingresar, me manda directamente al error de logueo sin hacer la comparación para saber qué tipo de usuario está iniciando sesión.
Alguna sugerencia

¡Ayuda please!

```
<form action="Login.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">  
   <label for="usuario" class="sr-only">Usuario</label>
    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" class="col-md-6" placeholder="Usuario">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">  
    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="col-md-6" placeholder="Password">
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login">Ingresar</button>
    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-danger"> Cancelar </a>
  </div>

</form>
```

Este es el archivo del Login que conecta con la Base de Datos:

```
<?php
 @session_start();
 require("Conectar.php");
 $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM usuarios 
            WHERE usuario='%s' and password = '%s'",
            $_POST['usuario'],
            sha1($_POST['password']));
 $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
 $encontrados = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($encontrados >= 1){
$_SESSION['nombre'] = $fila['nombre'];
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $fila['usuario'];
$_SESSION['nivel'] = $fila['nivel'];
if ($_SESSION['nivel']==3){
    header('Location:Panel_Administrador.php'); 
}
else if ($_SESSION['nivel']==2){
    header('Location:Panel_Colaborador.php');   
}
else if ($_SESSION['nivel']==1){
    header('Location:Panel_Usuario.php');   
}
}
else{
header('Location:Error_Sesion.php');
}
?>
```

¿Qué podrá ser? ¿Alguna sugerencia de corrección?

Comment: Que error te sale? deberias poner el error para analizarlo mejor

Comment: Si salta el `header('Location:Error_Sesion.php');` es por que no te esta retorando ningun usuario. Por cierto deberias utilizar `password_hash` y `password_verify` para cifrar la contraseña en lugar de sha1, tambien deberias utilizar consultas preparadas. Hay preguntas que ya abordan esto ejemplo: [Estoy creando un login...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/295462/estoy-creando-un-login-y-cuando-intento-logearme-me-aparece-el-msg-de-no-tiene/295537#295537) y [Verificar contraseña...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166666/verificar-contrase%C3%B1a-con-php-y-db/166704#166704)

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo Xerif, sería bueno que usaras consultas preparadas y además cifraras con password_hash().

Te reestructuro el código de conectar como lo tengo en una clase.

conexion.php

```
class Conectar
{
    public $usuario  = "usuario";
    public $clave    = "clave";
    public $servidor = "localhost";
    public $bd       = "BD";
    public $conexion = "";

    public function Conexion(){
        #Comentar linea de error_reporting para ver errores en el servidor.
        #error_reporting(0);
        try {
            $this->conexion = new mysqli($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->clave, $this->bd);
            return $this->conexion;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->e;
        }
    }
}
```

Para terminar tu código de búsqueda debería quedar algo como esto, ten en cuenta que las sentencias preparadas te evitan muchos dolores de cabeza con SQLInjection y te proporciona una mejor funcionalidad y seguridad frente a tus consultas.

LOGIN.PHP

```
$buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?";
try{
    $queryBuscarUsuario = $conexion->prepare($buscarUsuario);
    $queryBuscarUsuario->bind_param('s', $usuario); # la S es por ser tipo STRING el parametro que estas pasando
    $queryBuscarUsuario->execute();
    $queryBuscarUsuario->bind_result(AQUI OTORGAR UN NOMBRE DE VARIABLE A CADA CAMPO QUE ESTES TRAYENDO EJM: $campo1, $campo2, $campo3);
    $queryBuscarUsuario->store_result();
    if ($queryBuscarUsuario->num_rows() > 0){
      # Se encontró el usuario, realizar fetch para traer datos ordenados
      $queryBuscarUsuario->fetch();
      # Ten en cuenta que la instrucción del fetch no se coloco en un while
      # Debido a que estas trayendo 1 solo registro y no necesitas una lista de registros
      # Aquí ya empiezas a comprobar la clave digitada con la traída desde la BD
    } else {
      # NO SE ENCONTRÓ EL USUARIO RETORNAR MENSAJE DE ERROR
    }
}
```

Esto es sólo un ejemplo para que te guíes y trates de lo posible en reestructurar tu código, lee mucho sobre sentencias preparadas te ahorra muchas cosas y validaciones.

Mucha Suerte...