# ¿Es obsoleta la extensión PDO MySQL para Php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

He estado buscando en internet y sé que MySQL para conexión a base de datos como tal está obsoleta desde Php 7.0.0 y se debe usar MySQLi como reemplazo.

Sin embargo, me surge la gran duda: ¿esto cubre también la parte de PDO para MySQL?

Leí en php.net sobre [PDO MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) y no menciona que esté obsoleto, pero al tratar igual con conexión a base de datos me ha quedado la duda.

De no estar obsoleta, ¿puede que la descontinuen en el futuro próximo? ¿es recomendable seguirla usando o para nuevos proyectos uso todo con MySQLi?

Comment: El [enlace del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/migration55.deprecated.php) que indica que `mysql_*` está obsoleto te indica dos alternativas : `mysqli` o `PDO`. Cualquiera de las dos es totalmente válida. Incluso desde mi experiencia te recomendaría más `PDO` que `mysqli`. Con aquella algunos procesos son mucho más fáciles, mientras que esta depende de un driver adicional para algunas cosas, y ese driver no viene instalado en todos los servidores.

Comment: Entiendo. Muy agradecido por tu aporte @A.Cedano. Un saludo!

Comment: @A.Cedano Apoyando este comentario, igual yo lo utilizo en mis proyectos, el manejo es fácil y tiene muchos métodos útiles. Si quieres pásate por el canal de pildorasinformaticas en youtube tiene un curso muy completo de PHP que incluye PDO.

Comment: Agradecido por tu aporte @YoAlbert tendré en cuenta ese canal de youtube. Un saludo!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Respuesta corta

Tanto `MySQLi` como `PDO` son totalmente válidas para nuevos proyectos.

Lo podemos deducir de lo que se afirma aquí:

> #### *API recomendada*
>
> **Se recomienda usar las extensiones [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) o [`PDO_MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php). No se recomienda usar la extensión mysql antigua para nuevos
>   desarrollos**, ya que ha sido declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y
>   eliminada en PHP 7. Se proporciona una matriz detallada de comparación
>   de características más abajo. El rendimiento global de las tres
>   extensiones se considera que sea aproximadamente el mismo. Aunque el
>   rendimiento de la extensión aporta solamente una fracción del total
>   del tiempo de ejecución de una consulta web de PHP. A menudo, el
>   impacto es tan bajo como 0.1%.
>
> <sub>Fuente:
>   [Elegir una API para conexión a la base de datos](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) en el Manual de PHP</sub>

---

### Comparación de características

El Manual ofrece la siguiente tabla de comparación, en la cual podemos ver que tanto `PDO` como `mysqli` son válidas para usarlas en cualquier proyecto actual. En la comparación se incluye también a la extensión `mysql_*`<sup>1</sup>, la cual sí es obsoleta y no recomendada para futuros proyectos. Esta extensión ya no viene en el core de PHP 7.

[image: Comparación entre PDO, mysqli y mysql en el Manual de PHP]
<sub>[Comparación entre PDO, mysqli y mysql en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> El estado actual de la extensión `mysql_*` fue tratado en esta pregunta: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967) . Su uso aparece todavía un muchos ejemplos de código en la red... y aparece mucho también en preguntas planteadas en SO, por eso es importante subrayar siempre la obsolescencia de esa extensión, la cual además se suele confundir con `mysqli`.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me ha quedado totalmente claro por la tabla que adjuntaste. Un saludo!