# Error php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo me indica los errores:

> mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in
>   C:\AppServ\www\tablaentradaysalida\index.php on line 35

---

> mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in
>   C:\AppServ\www\tablaentradaysalida\index.php on line 35 database
>   error:

la linea 35 es esta:

```
$resultset = mysql_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysql_error($conn));
```

---

```
<tbody>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_email, emp_salary, emp_age FROM emp ORDER BY emp_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$resultset = mysql_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysql_error($conn));
if(mysql_num_rows($resultset)) {
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['emp_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['emp_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['emp_email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['emp_salary']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['emp_age']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } } else { ?>
<tr><td colspan="5">No records to display.....</td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Cual es el error.? me podrian ayudar por favor.

Comment: Primera: la funcion mysql para realizar consultas ya esta obsoleta, deberías utilizar mysqli o mucho mejor PDO. Segunda: debes mostrar el codigo de tu query para tener mejor idea en donde puede estar tu error.

Comment: Como dijo LuisYm, mysql esta obsoleta, usa mysqli, revista esta pregunta para mas información: [¿Es obsoleta la extensión PDO MySQL para Php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134983/es-obsoleta-la-extensi%C3%B3n-pdo-mysql-para-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer error te indica que el segundo parametro debe ser un resource, no una cadena. En tu caso, estas enviando los parametros a la funcion mysql_query en el orden incorrecto. El correcto seria:

```
$resultset = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die("database error:". mysql_error($conn));
```

Te he indicado la correccion para mysql_query porque supongo que estes trabajando en un proyecto antiguo, pero por otra parte, tal como te dicen en los comentarios, la funcion mysql_query esta obsoleta, deberias utilizar mysqli_query o pdo. El caso de mysqli_query es facil:

```
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysql_error($conn));
```

Comment: Si ese era el error ya lo solucione gracias Jakala.