# Actualizar consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy ejecutando esta consulta en mi base de datos con el método `mysql_query` de *PHP* y me dice que es obsoleta o algo así, ¿como seria esta consulta actualizada?

Gracias

```
    mysql_query("
ALTER TABLE `t_configuracion` 
ADD `tbas` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
ADD `tnar` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
ADD `tcban` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
ADD `tcdas` int(3) NOT NULL;
");
```

Comment: Y que lenguaje de programación usas?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, es php.

Comment: Tu problema es que usas las funciones mysql_* que están descontinuadas desde hace tiempo entonces te toca migrar eso a funciones de pdo o mysqli https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Solucionado, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @BetaM Al ser esa la respuesta, por que no la pones como respuesta ??

Comment: No tengo a la meno ahorita el enlace pero esta pregunta ya esta duplicada, en cuanto lo encuentre voto para cerrarla, además el OP no provee algún intento o haber hecho algo @Excorpion por eso es mejor aún no responder, pues ni siquiera sabemos si trabajará con mysqli o PDO

Comment: Revisa estas dos preguntas me parece que son algo similar a la tuya o al menos tienen relación: [primer enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166883/146637), [segundo enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92771/como-cambiar-de-mysql-query-a-mysqli-query)

Comment: Hola, perdonadme pero no se como puntuar mejor respuesta y cerrarla.