# Ayuda con un error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Quisiera preguntar por que me sale este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_result() in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\Laboratorios\Laboratorio 3\Parte 1\mostrarTuristas.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\Laboratorios\Laboratorio 3\Parte 1\mostrarTuristas.php on line 25

Estoy viendo programación en el colegio, uso MySQL Workbench, Xampp y Sublime Text. El problema me formula que debo mostrar en una página web los datos de una base de datos de MySQL, pero en el colegio me enseñan con las funciones mysql_* en vez de mysqli_* por lo tanto por mi cuenta estoy aprendiendo estas funciones debido a que son obsoletas en mi ordenador. Pero hay una función que no me funciona y me sale ese error. Si me pudieran ayudar a solucionarlo lo agradeceria

El código es el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Agencia de Viajes</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">LISTADO DE TURISTAS</h2>
<section>
 <table align="center">
  <tr>
   <td>Codigo</td>
   <td>Nombre</td>
   <td>Apellidos</td>
   <td>Direccion</td>
   <td>Movil</td>
   <td>Correo</td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  include('conexion.php');
  $rs=mysqli_query($cn,"select * From Turista");
  $n=mysqli_num_rows($rs);
  for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) { 
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'idTurista'); ?></td>
   <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'nombre_turista'); ?></td>
   <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'apellidos'); ?></td>
   <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'direccion'); ?></td>
   <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'movil'); ?></td>
   <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'correo'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  }
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="6">Total de Turistas Registrados: <?php echo $n; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Aparte esta el código de conexión pero con el que tengo problemas sería con este. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! lee tambien https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/324 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/134983/324 y dile a tu profesor que se actualice con urgencia

Comment: He tenido casos con gente que ganan dinero dictando cursos, con tecnologías demasiado viejas, obsoletas, vulnerables y por encima de eso, empleando malas prácticas. Los docentes también tienen que poner de su parte y actualizarse. La extensión `mysql_` fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5 (2013) y eliminada en PHP 7.0 (2015)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este codigo

```
  <?php

        include('conexion.php');
        $rs=mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT * FROM Turista");
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {  
             ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'idTurista'); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'nombre_turista'); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'apellidos'); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'direccion'); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'movil'); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo mysqli_result($rs,$i,'correo'); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Sinceramente no lo puedo probar en este momento, pero te puedo decir que como lo estabas haciendo se me ha enseñado que es una forma algo antigua y poco recomendable, es mas correcto hacer uso de  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()) ya que inclusive  te ahorras codigo

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Agencia de Viajes</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">LISTADO DE TURISTAS</h2>
<section>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Codigo</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Apellidos</td>
            <td>Direccion</td>
            <td>Movil</td>
            <td>Correo</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        include('conexion.php');
        $rs=mysqli_query($cn,"select * From Turista");
        $n=mysqli_num_rows($rs);
        while ($fila = $rs->fetch_assoc()){ 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $fila["idTurista"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila["nombre_turista"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila["apellidos"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila["direccion"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila["movil"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila["correo"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">Total de Turistas Registrados: <?php echo $n; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Prueba así, me comentas como te fue!