# BBDD no conecta con PHP 7

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un archivo dbcon.php el cual me hace la conexión a la base de datos y otros de sesión... por más que intento adaptar el código a php 7 no me hace la conexión y se vuelve a index.php

**dbcon.php**

```
mysql_select_db('base de datos',mysql_connect('localhost','usuario','pass'))or die(mysql_error());
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=base de datos", "usuario", "pass");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'")
```

**session.php**

```
session_start(); 
//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['id']) == '')) { ?>
<script>
window.location = "index.php";
</script>
<?php
}
$session_id=$_SESSION['id'];

$user_query = mysql_query("select * from users where user_id = '$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());
$user_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
$user_username = $user_row['username'];
```

**login.php**

```
include('dbcon.php');
    session_start();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysqli_error());
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $status = $row['status'];

    if ($count > 0 and $status == "Activated"){
        $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
            echo 'true'; }
```

Comment: `mysql`está obsoleto en la versión de PHP que usas. Aquí más [información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134983/es-obsoleta-la-extensi%C3%B3n-pdo-mysql-para-php) Prueba a cambiarlo por `mysqli`

Comment: Te refieres a poner mysqli_select_db ?

Comment: Sí, cambiar todo lo que tenga `mysql`por `mysqli`. Es decir: `mysqli_select_db`, `mysqli_query`, `mysqli_fetch_array`, etc

Comment: @Lucía el session.php lo ves bien?

Comment: Cambia todo lo que te dije anteriormente, veo `mysql` en el session.php, esos también los tienes que cambiar

Comment: @Lucía voy a ver que error tengo porque incluso cambiando esto no me deja entrar...

Comment: Acabo de incluir el login.php

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando una versión obsoleta de MySQL. Cambiando la extensión por `mysqli` debería empezar a funcionarte.

Quizá esta tabla te sirva de ayuda para entender mejor las diferencias.

[image: Tabla de diferencias]

[Sacado de aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

El resultado quedaría así:

**dbcon.php**

```
mysqli_select_db('base de datos',mysqli_connect('localhost','usuario','pass'))or die(mysqli_error());
$connect = new PDO("mysqli:host=localhost;dbname=base de datos", "usuario", "pass");
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'")
```

**session.php**

```
session_start(); 
//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['id']) == '')) { ?>
<script>
window.location = "index.php";
</script>
<?php
}
$session_id=$_SESSION['id'];

$user_query = mysqli_query("select * from users where user_id = '$session_id'")or die(mysqli_error());
$user_row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query);
$user_username = $user_row['username'];
```

Comment: Voy a comprobar que error es el que tengo porque cambiando esto no me deja tampoco entrar.

Comment: Hay mezcla de dos APIs de conexión. Una cosa es **mysqli**: `mysqli_select_db('base de datos',mysqli_connect('localhost','usuario','pass'))or die(mysqli_error());` y otra cosa es **PDO**: `$connect = new PDO("mysqli:host=localhost;dbname=base de datos", "usuario", "pass");`. No tiene sentido mezclar, hay que usar una u otra.