# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'... on line 5

Tags: php

quisiera saber en donde esta el error, ya que ando hace media hora tratando de resolverlo, muchas gracias.

Codigo:

```
mysql_pconnect('localhost','root';'');
```

Comment: Ese ; esta sobrando dentro de los paréntesis, solo se ponen ,

Comment: Debería ser: `mysql_pconnect('localhost','root','');`

Comment: Cuando sea posible lee esto por favor: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967). Si puedes evitar el uso de la extensión `mysql_*` evítalo.

Comment: Tu problema es el ; que tienes despues de 'root' debe ser una ,

Answer (score 3):

Los **parámetros** de un método o función en PHP (y en otros lenguajes de la la misma familia como C, JS, etc.) **se separan por comas**.

Un ***error de sintaxis*** indica que estas usando un carácter incorrecto en un determinado lugar y generalmente te indica correctamente el número de línea en que se produce, aunque puede venir de una línea precedente.

En el caso concreto de tu error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'… on
>   line 5

Se encuentra un carácter de punto y coma, cuando se espera una coma (signo de separación de parámetros) o un cierre de paréntesis, que indicaría que ya no vas a pasar más parámetros a la función. El analizador no va más allá de la sintaxis del lenguaje, es decir, el número de parámetros que espera recibir una función determinada no es analizado, solo que el código esté correctamente construido según las normas sintácticas del lenguaje PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es el `;` que tienes despues de `'root'` debe ser una `,`

```
mysql_pconnect('localhost','root','');
```

Ademas esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. Deberías utilizar las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL

Documentación:http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Comment: oooh con razon, probare eso, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si te ayudo favor marcarla como respuesta que resolvió tu problema.