# Estoy empezando a usar mysql y Php pero mi archivo PHP se muestra en blanco

Tags: php, html, mysql

A la hora de enviar mi formulario a través de php la página queda en blanco y no muestra ni el texto fuera del php, aquí les dejo el código

HTML:

```
<html>    
<head> 
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Guardar datos en una base de datos</title>    
</head>    
<body>
<form method="post" action="registra.php">
    <p>Nombre:
        <input type="text" name="nombre" size="20" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" >
    </p>    
    <p>E-mail:
        <input type="text" name="email" size="20" placeholder="email" >
    </p>    
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar datos" name="B1" >
    </p>    
</form>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Registra.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Datos guardados</title>
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');

include('abre_conexion.php');
$_GRABAR_SQL ="INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (nombre,email,fecha) VALUES ('$nombre','$email','$fecha')";
mysql_query($_GRABAR_SQL);
include("cierra_conexion.php");
echo "<p>Datos guardados</p><p><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>VOLVER ATRÁS</a></p>";
?>
<br><p>guardado</p>
</body>
</html>

Abre_conexion.php:
<?php
$hotsdb = "localhost";
$basededatos = "id5879099_prueba1";
$usuariodb = "id5879099_oliver977";
$clavedb = "mnbvcxz99";
$tabla_db1 = "Usuarios";

$conexion_db = mysql_connect("$hotsdb","$usuariodb","$clavedb")
    or die ("error");
    $db = mysql_connect_db("$basededatos",$conexion_db)
    or die ("La Base de datos <b>$basededatos</b> no existe");
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En este caso las imágenes sirven de muy poco, de hecho, es imposible verificar el código de forma íntegra, se trunca en muchas partes. Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/177320/edit) cambiando las imágenes por el texto. Y di el error que estás teniendo.

Comment: primeramente no uses mysql, esta obsoleta lo que puedo ver es que estas llamando el archivo de la conexion dos veces y estas poniendo puntos antes de las variables  en el insert osea esta estraño tu codigo

Comment: No uses mysql, está obsoleto y muchas veces no funciona, te recomiendo **mysqli**. Un saludo!

Comment: Puedes mostrar **temporalmente** tu versión de PHP agregando este código al principio del script: `echo 'La versión actual de PHP es: ' . phpversion();`. Si te muestra la versión `7`o superior el código no funcionará porque la extensión `mysql_*` fue sacada del core de PHP a partir de la versión 7 (ver la pregunta [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)). Deberías entonces migrar tu código a PDO (recomendado, es opinión mía) o a MySQLi. **Aunque no tengas todavía PHP se recomienda igualmente migrar, por seguridad**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta seria la manera correcta de ingrasar datos, aunque no se bien como funciona mysql, te recomiendo usar mysqli

```
$query="INSERT INTO $tabla_db1(nombre,email,fecha)VALUES("$nombre","$email","$fecha")";
```