# Evitar que se envíen datos vacíos en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Cuando se carga la página envía datos vacíos a mi base de datos.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/efectos.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/logo.png"/>
    <title>Busca amigos de free fire</title>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var txt = " Busca amigos de free fire " ; var espera = 140; var refresco =null ; function rotulo_title ()
    { document. title = txt; txt =
    txt. substring
    ( 1, txt . length )+ txt.
    charAt
    ( 0); refresco = setTimeout
    ( "rotulo_title()", espera );}
    rotulo_title (); </script>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <div>
                <h1 id="titulo" >Busca amigos de<br> Free &nbsp;F<span>g</span>re</h1>
            </div>
        </a>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html" ><div id="inicio">Inicio</div></a>
        <a href="buscar.php" ><div id="buscar">Buscar</div></a>
        <a href="publicar.php" ><div id="publicar">Publicar</div></a>
    </nav>
    <hr id="menu" >
    <section>
        <h1 id="ht" >Aquí puedes ponerte en contacto con nosotros.</h1>
        <br>
        <article>
            <p id="info" >
            Aquí puedes enviar tus comentarios sobre este proyecto, también sugerencias así como también puedes reportar alguna falla.
            </p>
            <br>
        </article>
        <h2 id="fd" >Solo llena este formulario</h2>
        <article id="contacto" >
            <table>
                <form method="post" action="" >
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Nombre:<span class="obligatorio" >* </span></label></td>
                    <td><input required="required" minlength="3" class="textof" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" value="" id="ctxt" ></td>
                <br>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Foma de contacto:<span class="obligatorio" >* </span></label></td>
                    <td><input required="required" class="textof" name="contacto" type="text" placeholder="correo electrónico o número de whatsapp" value="" id="ctxt" ></td>
                <br>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Asunto:<span class="obligatorio" >* </span></label></td>
                    <td><input required="required" class="textof" name="asunto" type="text" placeholder="Asunto" value="" id="ctxt" ></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                <center>
                    <td colspan="2" id="c" ><label>Mensaje:<span class="obligatorio" >*</span></label></td>
                <br>
                </center>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <center>
                    <td colspan="2" id="c" ><textarea required="required" class="textoarea" name="mensaje" placeholder="Deja tu mensaje" id="msj">
                    </textarea></td>
                </center>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="c" ><input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="envio2" ></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
            </table>
        </article>
    </section>
    <br>
    <footer>
        <div id="sugerencias">
            <span>Deja tus Comentarios, sugerencias o ponte en contacto con nosotros haciendo click <a href="contacto.php" id="sg" >aquí</a>
        </div>
        <div id="aclaracion" >
            <p>Este sitio no está asociado de ninguna manera con free fire</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$contacto = $_POST['contacto'];
$asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

include('abre_conexion.php');
$_GRABAR_SQL ="INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (nombre,contacto, asunto, mensaje, ip) VALUES ('$nombre','$contacto','$asunto','$mensaje','$ip')";
$res=mysql_query($_GRABAR_SQL);
if ($res) {
    echo "<script> alert('Tus comentarios se enviaron con éxito');</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script> alert('Ocurrio un error');</script>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A pesar de poner required en tus campos te deja mandar los datos del formulario??

Comment: Si los envía a mi base de datos en blanco, pero la IP de la línea en blanco es distinto a la mía

Comment: Que ip te muestra ::1 ????

Comment: por como lo estás programando si, se imprime un html y luego graba datos vacíos: `$_POST` no existe en la primera carga, así que habrá varios warnings y luego el insert vacío.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre conviene validar los datos que se reciben por POST o por GET.

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, te mostraré la que suelo usar, la cual consiste en:

- Usar un operador ternario para hacer dos operaciones al mismo tiempo: (a) Verificar que los datos no están vacíos. Si tienen información guardarla en una variable, la cual se usará en lo adelante donde hagan falta los datos. (b) Si no tienen información dar el valor `NULL` a la variable
- Antes de lanzar la inserción verificar el estado de las variables, aprovechando precisamente que le asignamos `NULL` cuando los datos estuvieran vacíos

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php 

    $nombre   = ( empty($_POST['nombre']) )   ? NULL : $_POST['nombre'];
    $contacto = ( empty($_POST['contacto']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['contacto'];
    $asunto   = ( empty($_POST['asunto']) )   ? NULL : $_POST['asunto'];
    $mensaje  = ( empty($_POST['mensaje']) )  ? NULL : $_POST['mensaje'];
    $ip       = ( empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) )  ? NULL : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if ( $nombre && $contacto && $asunto && mensaje && $ip ){
        include('abre_conexion.php');
        $_GRABAR_SQL ="INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (nombre,contacto, asunto, mensaje, ip) VALUES ('$nombre','$contacto','$asunto','$mensaje','$ip')";
        mysql_query($_GRABAR_SQL);

        if ( mysql_affected_rows()>0 ) {
            echo "<script> alert('Tus comentarios se enviaron con éxito');</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script> alert('Ocurrio un error');</script>";
        }
    }else{
    //Indicar que hay datos vacíos en el POST
    }

?>
```

Yo he cambiado la verificación que haces para indicar que se insertaron datos. Es más preciso verificar cuántas filas fueron afectadas usando `mysql_affected_rows`, que verificar el simple éxito de la consulta.

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> La extensión `mysql_` (no confundir con el sistema de base de datos MySQL) fue hace tiempo declarada obsoleta (ver más
>   detalles en la pregunta [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)).
>   Tu código presenta un grave riesgo de inyección SQL. Para prevenirlo,
>   deberías pasar si es posible a  mysqli, o a PDO y además de eso
>   implementar consultas preparadas.