# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

Ayuda, apenas estoy aprendiendo PHP y HTML no encuentro el error aunque ya busque como 1000 veces

el erro que me marca es en la linea 11 y es este:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Nombre' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\AppServ\www\insertadatos.php on line 11**

```
<head>
<title> Creacion de portal PHP y MySQL </title>
</head>
<h2> Formulario para insertar datos </h2>
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "root";
$password = 1;
$db = "Farmacia";

$Nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
$Accion = $_POST['Accion'];
$IDLab = $_POST['IDLab'];

$enlace = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db($db, $enlace);
$result = mysql_query("insert into Medicamentos(Nombre, Accion, IDLab) value 
('$Nombre','$Accion','$IDLab')", $enlace);
echo "Ha insertado los siguientes datos";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Nombre del medicamento.......................: $Nombre";
echo "<br>";
echo "Accion del medicamento.......................: $Accion";
echo "<br>";
echo "ID del Laboratorio...........................: $IDLab";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br><br>";
?>

<a href = "http://localhost/Formularioinserta.htm"> Volver
```

el nombre del archivo donde se adquieren las variables es: Formularioinserta.htm y contienes este codigo:
      
      Creacion de portal PHP y MySQL

```
    <form name = "form" action = "insertadatos.php" methos "post">
    <h2> Formulario para insertar datos </h2>
    <h5> Introduce el nombre del medicamento...........:
    <input name = "Nombre" type = "text" size = "45">
    <br><br>
    Introduce la accion del medicamento................:
    <input name = "Accion" type = "text" size = "45">
    <br><br>
    Introduce el ID del laboratorio....................:
    <input name = "IDLab" type = "text" size = "45">
    <br><br>
    </h5>
    <input name = "Enviar" type = "submit" value = "Enviar">
 </form>
```

Comment: No te entiendo, soy nuevo en esto, me podrias decir como es ya corregido

Comment: Un momento, falta un punto y coma aquí: `$db = "Farmacia"`, al menos ese es el error *`unexpected (T_VARIABLE)`*, debes escribirlo así: **`$db = "Farmacia";`**

Comment: @shadow, [el OP está usando la vieja API](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php), y la sintaxis en ella es al revés de `mysqli`, su código es correcto en ese sentido, en la vieja API la conexión va al final.

Comment: entiendo, bajo esa afirmación quito mis comentarios

Comment: Ya corregi esa parte en el codigo

Comment: ¿Y qué ocurre ahora, da más errores?¿Qué errores?

Comment: Ya edite la publicacion por los demas errores que salen

Comment: No hace la conexión, te dice esto: *`Advertencia : mysql_connect (): Acceso denegado para el usuario 'root' @ 'localhost' (usando la contraseña: YES) en C: \ AppServ \ www \ insertadatos.php en la línea 15`*. ¿Seguro que la password es `1`?, prueba con una password en blanco cambiando `$password = 1;` por `$password = "";`

Comment: Si, eso arreglo los problemas, ahora, en esta parte `echo "Ha insertado los siguientes datos";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Nombre del medicamento.......................: $Nombre";
echo "<br>";
echo "Accion del medicamento.......................: $Accion";
echo "<br>";
echo "ID del Laboratorio...........................: $IDLab";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br><br>";
?>` No muestra los valores de las variables que se habian introducido anteriormente

Comment: ¿Se insertaron?   ¿Seguro que se insertaron?  ¿?  Estás usando POST, para pasar la información, ¿cómo llamas a esa archivo, o sea, cómo escribes la dirección en el navegador para acceder a él?  ¿O lo llamas mediante Ajax (es poco probable si estás empezando)? Haz un `print_r($_POST);` y di lo que muestra.

Comment: Ya edite la publicacion.

Comment: Oooootro error en tu formulario, aquí: `methos "post"` debes corregirlo así: **`method="post"`**

Comment: Gracias eso lo soluciono...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propongo este código con todos los errores corregidos y algunas mejoras. Las variables del POST hay que controlarlas de alguna forma. Aquí uso un *operador ternario* combinado con `empty`.

#### PHP

```
<head>
<title> Creacion de portal PHP y MySQL </title>
</head>
<h2> Formulario para insertar datos </h2>
<?php
    $Nombre= ( empty($_POST['Nombre']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['Nombre'];
    $Accion= ( empty($_POST['Accion']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['Accion'];
    $IDLab=  ( empty($_POST['IDLab'])  ) ? NULL : $_POST['IDLab'];
    
    if ($Nombre && $Accion && $IDLab){
        $host = "127.0.0.1";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "";
        $db = "Farmacia";
    
        $enlace = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
        mysql_select_db($db, $enlace);
        $sql="insert into Medicamentos(Nombre, Accion, IDLab) values ('$Nombre','$Accion','$IDLab')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $enlace);
        $msg="Ha insertado los siguientes datos";
        $msg.="<br><br>";
        $msg.="Nombre del medicamento.......................: $Nombre";
        $msg.="<br>";
        $msg.="Accion del medicamento.......................: $Accion";
        $msg.="<br>";
        $msg.="ID del Laboratorio...........................: $IDLab";
        $msg.="<br>";
        $msg.="<br><br>";
    
    }else{
        
        $msg="Algunos de los datos POST están vacíos";    
        
    }
    echo $msg;
?>
```

---

#### HTML

Debes corregir el formulario así:

```
<form name = "form" action = "insertadatos.php" method="post">
```

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD**: La extensión `mysql_*` que usas ha sido declarada obsoleta. Deberías en cuanto sea posible pasar a PDO o a
> MySQLi. La inserción manejada de esa forma es insegura, te pueden
> colar código malicioso. Para más detalles consulta la siguiente
> pregunta: [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)

Comment: Esta línea `$Nombre= ( empty($_POST['Nombre']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['Nombre'];` también pudiera quedar así no? `$Nombre = (empty($_POST['Nombre']) ?? NULL);` usando el operador de fusión NULL

Comment: @shadow, me sorprendes con lo del *operador de fusión `NULL`*  :), voy a probar.

Comment: @shadow así no me coge el dato que hay en el POST, que es de lo que se trata, para luego usarlo en el `INSERT`... me crea sólo una variable booleana.

Comment: te dejo la referencia del operador, igual por escribirlo rápido lo puse mal http://php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php en la sección que dice operador de fusión NULL

Comment: @shadow te agradezco, porque es un descubrimiento interesantísimo, no siquiera hace falta `empty`, con ponerlo así bastaría: `$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'] ?? NULL;`  Pero, ¿no funciona en PHP 5, cierto?

Comment: asi es @A.Cedano es una de las características de PHP **pero** en su versión 7, tal como te lo decía lo puse mal, por que solo traslade tu instrucción pero no presté atención al detalle