# ¿Ayuda me da este error al hacer en consulta en Mysql Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error()?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, xampp

Hola no se porque me da ese error,por favor ayuda es urgente,lo que quiero hacer es enviar un archivo al servidor(si lo envía),pero no guarda los archivos en la base de datos Mysql,la versión de PHP es 7.3.0
este es mi codigo:

```
include 'config.php';

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'])) {
    $ruta = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/subir_archivo/uploads/';
    $nombrefinal= trim ($_FILES['archivo']['name']); //Eliminamos los espacios en blanco
    $nombrefinal= preg_replace ("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $nombrefinal);//Sustituye una expresión regular
    $upload= $ruta . $nombrefinal;  

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $upload)) { //movemos el archivo a su ubicacion 

                echo "<b>Upload exitoso!. Datos:</b><br>";  
                echo "Nombre: <i><a href=\"".$ruta . $nombrefinal."\">".$_FILES['archivo']['name']."</a></i><br>";  
                echo "Tipo MIME: <i>".$_FILES['archivo']['type']."</i><br>";  
                echo "Peso: <i>".$_FILES['archivo']['size']." bytes</i><br>";  
                echo "<br><hr><br>";

               $numCertificado  = $_POST["numeroCertificado"]; 
               $razonSocial  = $_POST["razonSocial"]; 
               //$fecha = $_POST["fecha_expedicion"];
               $direccion = $_POST["direccion"];

               $mysqli -> query = ("INSERT INTO Certificado (numeroCertificado,razonSocial,direccion,ruta) 
                VALUES ('$numCertificado','$razonSocial','$direccion', 
                        '".$numCertificado."',
                        '".$razonSocial."',
                        '".$direccion."')");

    }  

 }
```

el código de la conexión:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpwd = "";
$db = "csc_certificaciones";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpwd,$db);
    if(!$conexion)
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    else
        echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

la conexión si funciona porque hice otra prueba y si funciona y los guarda en la base de datos,que puedo probar?

Comment: Te marca la linea donde esta el error?

Comment: si la linea 39, no se si el INSERT este mal o me falte algo

Comment: `$mysqli_query -> query =($conexion, "INSERT....") ` , intenta cambiando esto añadiendo esto.

Comment: no,no funciona dice syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO certificado (numeroCertificado,razonSocial,direccion,ruta) 
            VALUES ('$numCertificado','$razonSocial','$direccion', 
                '".$numCertificado."',
                '".$razonSocial."',
                '".$direccion."')";                                                                         if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
         echo "New record created successfully";
          }else{
           echo "No se escribio en la base de datos";
           }//cambie la ultima parte asi y siempre entra al else

Comment: A.Palacio,tambien agregue el campo url pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Cámbialo por esto: La cantidad de parámetros debe de coincidir: `$sql = "INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (param_1,param_2) VALUES ('$valor_1','$valor_2')"; 

if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) { 
    echo "New record created successfully"; 
}else{
    echo "No se escribio en la base de datos"; 
}`

Comment: El mensaje de error que describes: *`Call to undefined function mysql_error()`* se refiere a que en alguna parte del programa estás usando una función que ya no existe en PHP 7, todas las funciones que empiecen por `mysql_` (nótese que no está la `i` final) darán ese error, porque la extensión `mysql_` fue definitivamente sacada del núcleo de PHP 7. [Ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967) para más detalles y el punto 3 en la [respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75140/29967).

Comment: gracias a todos por la ayuda,la solución fue cambiar la consulta como dijo A. Palacio,y también quite esa funcion mysl_.... y funciona ,postdata ¿como cierro la pregunta