# Por qué me sale este error? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqlconnector

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat1\myslq.php:3 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chat1\functions.php(221): require_once() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chat1\index.php(79): getreadyMesages() #2 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat1\myslq.php on line 3

Este es el código con el cual estoy teniendo problemas, trate de ordenarlo con `mysqli`, pero no he podido dar con el problema, agradecería su ayuda

```
  $connect = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  $selectDb = mysql_select_db("chat",$connect); 

  if($selectDb == false){
    die(mysql_error()); 
  } 

  function getUser($salt , $f){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT $f FROM users WHERE salt='$salt' ");


    if($query == false){
        die(mysql_error()."Error from getuser ");
    } 

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
    return $row[0]; 
  }
```

Comment: Necsitaríamos ver el error completo para poder ayudarte. Además estaría bien saber que versión de PHP utilizas.

Comment: Buenas noches, el error que me sale es este: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat1\myslq.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\chat1\functions.php(221): require_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\chat1\index.php(79): getreadyMesages() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\chat1\myslq.php on line 3

Comment: versión de PHP 7.2

Comment: En PHP 7 la función mysql_connet() esta deprecated, por ahí viene el error. Mira cómo crear la conexión con PHP 7.

Comment: Prueba algo así: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia `mysql_*` estaba *deprecated*  en PHP 5. En PHP 7 ya no existe, fue sacada del núcleo del lenguaje, por eso lo que antes era una advertencia (en PHP 5), ahora es una error fatal con el mensaje: *`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() ...`* Cualquier intento de uso de la extensión `mysql_*` en PHP 7 provocará por tanto un crash en el código.

Answer (score 3):

Bienvenido a SOes, de primeras estas utilizando `mysql_*` y está *deprecated* en la versión **PHP5**, en **PHP7** dicha extensión fue quitada del núcleo, por lo que utilizarla genera un error fatal.

En vez de eso utiliza `mysqli_*`.

Haciendo las modificaciones pertinentes tu código quedaría así:

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root",""); // utlizar mysqli_connect
 $selectDb = mysqli_select_db($connect,"chat"); // mysqli_select_db - primero la conexión, después el nombre de la BD.

  if($selectDb == false){
    die(mysqli_error()); //mysqli_error
  } 

  function getUser($salt , $f){
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT '$f' FROM users WHERE salt='$salt' "); //mysqli_query - poner '' a $f


    if($query == false){
        die(mysqli_error()."Error from getuser "); //mysqli_error
    } 

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query); //mysqli_fetch_row
    return $row[0]; 
  }
```

Comment: Sólo un apunte, en PHP 7 la extensión `mysql_*` no está deprecated, eso era en PHP 5. Dicha extensión **fue retirada del núcelo de PHP 7**, por tanto su uso conduce a un error fatal y a crash total del script. Creo que es importante indicar esa diferencia, porque es fundamental. Ver al respecto la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro a la pregunta *[`¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)*

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo @A.Cedano. Fallo mio, gracias por el aviso.

Comment: Me reservo el +1 a la espera de que ese dato aparezca claramente en tu respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: @JesusAlvarez te recomiendo también que evites enviar consultas de este tipo a ejecuación: `SELECT '$f' FROM users WHERE salt='$salt'` suponen un grave riesgo de seguridad. Un usuario mal intencionado podría modificar la variable `$salt`, creando código dañino que se ejecutaría sin más en la base de datos. Ese código puede ser desde la alteración / borrado / obtención de datos en las tablas, hasta introducir archivos dañinos en el sistema. ¡Sí! a través de SQL se pueden pasar archivos al sistema. Cuando sea posible lee sobre el tema ***Inyección SQL***. Deberías usar **consultas preparadas**.

Comment: Unido al comentario de @A.Cedano, te recomiendo que empieces a utilizar [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php), ya que es una versión mejorada y que además permite utilizar [bind-param](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) para añadir los párametros de forma segura y prevenir inyecciones sql.