# Una consulta a Mysql que parece que no quiere

Tags: php

de nuevo con estas cosas raras...hay algo que se me escapa en este asunto:

tabla "obra" en mysql

campo Codigo.. que es el codigo de la obra.

campo Descripcion.. que es lo que es... es evidente...

ahora preparo la consulta en PHP

la variable $Obra, viene por GET y su valor es 25

```
$resultadoObra=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo=".$Obra);
```

imprimo la consulta y el resultado es:

```
SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo=25
```

la ejecuto en phpmyAdmin con un resultado perfecto...

ahora quiero ver el resultado con este código:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoObra))
{

$descripcion=$row['Descripcion'];
  }
```

pero este error insiste en amargarme la noche..

```
**Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\InformeTotalObra.php on line 18**
```

la linea 18, corresponde al comienzo de WHILE

Este es el codigo completo:

```
$Obra=$_GET["obra"];
//*************Busca la OBRA ***********************
$resultadoObra=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo=".$Obra);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoObra))
{

$descripcion=$row['Descripcion'];
  }
```

el caso es que despues, en el mismo archivo, el codigo siguiente, si funciona perfectamente,

```
$query="SELECT * FROM ot where Obra=".$Obra;
$resultado=mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{

$idot=$row['idOrden'];
$otnumero=$row['Numero'];
$titulo=$row['titulo'];
}
```

no se, algo me pasa, pero no veo lo que falla...

codigo completo del archivo:

```
<?php
$salida="";
$total=0;
$Obra=$_GET["obra"];
//*************Busca la OBRA ***********************

$resultadoObra=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo=".$Obra);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoObra))
{

$descripcion=$row['Descripcion'];
  }



echo"INFORME GENERAL OBRA N: ".$Obra."</P>";


include('class.ezpdf.php');
include("datacon.php"); 
define('EURO', chr(128));
//***** Busca Precios de los Trabajos *********************
$queryP="SELECT * FROM preciostrabajos where id=1";
$resultadoP=mysql_query($queryP); 
echo $resultadoP;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoP))
{
$pchorrear=$row['Pchorrear'];
$ppintar=$row['Ppintar'];
$pcargar=$row['Pcarga'];
$pdescargar=$row['Pdescarga'];
$potros=$row['Potros'];
}


// Buscamos las OT correspondientes a la obra seleccionada.
$query="SELECT * FROM ot where Obra=".$Obra;
$resultado=mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{

$idot=$row['idOrden'];
$otnumero=$row['Numero'];
$titulo=$row['titulo'];
// Buscar contenido de la OT:
echo "</P>";
echo "Orden de trabajo Nº: ".$otnumero."  Descripcion:    ".$titulo."</p>";
$query1="SELECT sum(horasCarga) as horasCarga, sum(horasDescarga) as horasDescarga, sum(horasChorrear) as horasChorrear, sum(horasPintar)as horasPintar, sum(horasOtros) as horasOtros FROM otnew where idOt='".$otnumero."'"; 

echo "<table border = 1 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 2>";
  $lineas=mysql_query($query1); 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($lineas))
     {

$horasC=$row['horasCarga'];
$horasD=$row['horasDescarga'];
$horasCh=$row['horasChorrear'];
$horasP=$row['horasPintar'];
$horasO=$row['horasOtros'];





echo "<tr>"."<td width='500'>"."Total Horas carga: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasC*$pcargar."<tr>"."<td width='500'>"."Total Horas Descarga: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasD*$pdescargar."<tr>"."<td width='500'>"." horasChorrear: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasCh*$pchorrear."<tr>"."<td width='500'>"." Horas Pintar: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasP*$ppintar."<tr>"."<td width='500'>"." Horas Otros: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasO*$potros."</p>";
          }
    //*****Buscar el Producto utilizado ********************************
   $query2="SELECT * FROM lineasOtnew WHERE idOt='".$otnumero."'";      
   $lineasProducto=mysql_query($query2);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($lineasProducto))
     {
       $producto=trim($row['producto']);
       $cantidad=$row['cantidad'];
       // Busca precio del producto
       $query21="SELECT * FROM productostienda WHERE NombreComercial="."'".$producto."'";
       //echo $query21;
       $precioproducto=mysql_query($query21);
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($precioproducto))
             { 

              $precioP=$row['Precio'];
             }

       echo "<tr>"."<td width='500'>"."Producto: ".$producto."<td align='right' width='100'>".$cantidad*$precioP."</p>";

$total=$total+($cantidad*$precioP);

     }
$total=$total+($horasC*$pcargar);
$total=$total+($horasD*$pdescargar);
$total=$total+($horasCh*$pchorrear);
$total=$total+($horasP*$ppintar);
$total=$total+($horasO*$potros);
echo"</table>";

}// fin de Buscar OT


echo "<b>Coste Total de la Obra: ".$Obra."       </b>".$total;
      ?>
```

Todas las consultas, funcionan perfectamente excepto esa.

---

Pido Perdón al mundo entero,
niños, las yerbas........ para jugar al balón,

tenía el archivo de conexión debajo de la consulta, o sea que la consulta se hacía ántes de hacer la conexión con la base de datos.... fallo de primero de Agricultura.......

Lo siento.

---

Comment: Podrias colocar el codigo sompleto para una mejor comprención, lo que esta dentro del $_GET deveria ser con apostrofes ejemplo  : $Obra=$_GET['obra'];

Comment: Si hay datos como dices debería funcionar, a no ser que el dato del `GET` venga de otro modo, con espacios o cosas extrañas. Compártenos un `var_dump($_GET);` y el código completo para ver todo el contexto, no sea que estés haciendo algo raro que no se vea al mostrar el código a trozos.

Comment: Gracias Moises, como explico al final, hay otra consulta que igualmente utiliza la variable $Obra, y se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: gracias por responder A.Cedano, hay datos, si ejecuto la consulta en phpmyAdmin, me devuelve el registro correspondiente a la obra 25 perfectamente, no obstante modificare la pregunta y pongo el código de todo el archivo....

Comment: Pudes poner if (!$$resultadoObra) { die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());} abajo de $resultadoObra=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo=".$Obra); para ver si tiene error

Comment: Supongo que este es el archivo que gestiona la conexión a la base de datos: `include("datacon.php"); ` pero no lo incluyes antes de lanzar la primera consulta. Tienes que incluir al principio todo archivo que tenga que ver con la base de datos.

Comment: Proba asi: `$resultadoObra = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo = '".$Obra."'");`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar el código de la siguiente manera.

```
$Obra=$_GET["obra"];
    $Comando="SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo=".$Obra;
    $ResultadoObra=mysql_quey($Comando);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ResultadoObra))
    {
 $descripcion=$row['Descripcion'];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema se debe a que no le estas especificando el tipo de array, si es indexado, asociativo, etc.

En tu caso veo que es de tipo asociativo por lo cual tendrías que dejarlo de esta manera

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoObra, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

      $descripcion=$row['Descripcion'];
  }
```

Por otra parte te recomiendo que investigues acerca de **mysqli** que es el sucesor de **mysql**, ya que la libreria **mysql** quedo obsoleta desde la version de php 5.5.

Tambien veo que estas incluyendo estos archivos php despues de la primera consulta

```
include('class.ezpdf.php');
include("datacon.php");
```

Pero deberias incluirlos al principio de tu archivo ya que me imagino que el archivo **"datacon.php"** es en donde haces la conexion con la base de datos quedando el codigo con todas las correcciones de esta manera

```
<?php
include('class.ezpdf.php');
include("datacon.php"); 

$salida="";
$total=0;
$Obra=$_GET["obra"];
//*************Busca la OBRA ***********************

$resultadoObra=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo=".$Obra);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoObra, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

$descripcion=$row['Descripcion'];
  }



echo"INFORME GENERAL OBRA N: ".$Obra."</P>";



define('EURO', chr(128));
//***** Busca Precios de los Trabajos *********************
$queryP="SELECT * FROM preciostrabajos where id=1";
$resultadoP=mysql_query($queryP); 
echo $resultadoP;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoP, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$pchorrear=$row['Pchorrear'];
$ppintar=$row['Ppintar'];
$pcargar=$row['Pcarga'];
$pdescargar=$row['Pdescarga'];
$potros=$row['Potros'];
}


// Buscamos las OT correspondientes a la obra seleccionada.
$query="SELECT * FROM ot where Obra=".$Obra;
$resultado=mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

$idot=$row['idOrden'];
$otnumero=$row['Numero'];
$titulo=$row['titulo'];
// Buscar contenido de la OT:
echo "</P>";
echo "Orden de trabajo Nº: ".$otnumero."  Descripcion:    ".$titulo."</p>";
$query1="SELECT sum(horasCarga) as horasCarga, sum(horasDescarga) as horasDescarga, sum(horasChorrear) as horasChorrear, sum(horasPintar)as horasPintar, sum(horasOtros) as horasOtros FROM otnew where idOt='".$otnumero."'"; 

echo "<table border = 1 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 2>";
  $lineas=mysql_query($query1); 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($lineas, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {

$horasC=$row['horasCarga'];
$horasD=$row['horasDescarga'];
$horasCh=$row['horasChorrear'];
$horasP=$row['horasPintar'];
$horasO=$row['horasOtros'];





echo "<tr>"."<td width='500'>"."Total Horas carga: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasC*$pcargar."<tr>"."<td width='500'>"."Total Horas Descarga: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasD*$pdescargar."<tr>"."<td width='500'>"." horasChorrear: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasCh*$pchorrear."<tr>"."<td width='500'>"." Horas Pintar: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasP*$ppintar."<tr>"."<td width='500'>"." Horas Otros: "."<td align='right' width='100'>".$horasO*$potros."</p>";
          }
    //*****Buscar el Producto utilizado ********************************
   $query2="SELECT * FROM lineasOtnew WHERE idOt='".$otnumero."'";      
   $lineasProducto=mysql_query($query2);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($lineasProducto, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
       $producto=trim($row['producto']);
       $cantidad=$row['cantidad'];
       // Busca precio del producto
       $query21="SELECT * FROM productostienda WHERE NombreComercial="."'".$producto."'";
       //echo $query21;
       $precioproducto=mysql_query($query21);
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($precioproducto, MYSQL_ASSOC))
             { 

              $precioP=$row['Precio'];
             }

       echo "<tr>"."<td width='500'>"."Producto: ".$producto."<td align='right' width='100'>".$cantidad*$precioP."</p>";

$total=$total+($cantidad*$precioP);

     }
$total=$total+($horasC*$pcargar);
$total=$total+($horasD*$pdescargar);
$total=$total+($horasCh*$pchorrear);
$total=$total+($horasP*$ppintar);
$total=$total+($horasO*$potros);
echo"</table>";

}// fin de Buscar OT


echo "<b>Coste Total de la Obra: ".$Obra."       </b>".$total;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El error parece claro, luego de haber lanzado la primera consulta (la que no funciona) haces `include` de un archivo que parece ser el que gestiona la conexión a la base de datos:

```
include("datacon.php");
```

Hasta ese momento, la conexión no estaría en el contexto, por tanto, todo código que intente usarla arrojará `NULL` o `FALSE`.

Como norma general, pon los `include`, `require`, `define` siempre al principio, excepto aquellos que dependan de ciertas condiciones, los cuales debes incluir únicamente cuando esas condiciones se cumplan para optimizar el código.

Si lo pones así debería funcionar:

```
<?php
include('class.ezpdf.php');
include("datacon.php"); 
define('EURO', chr(128));

$salida="";
$total=0;
$Obra=$_GET["obra"];
//*************Busca la OBRA ***********************

$resultadoObra=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obra WHERE Codigo=".$Obra);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoObra))
{
    $descripcion=$row['Descripcion'];
}



echo"INFORME GENERAL OBRA N: ".$Obra."</P>";

//***** Busca Precios de los Trabajos *********************
// ...etc...
```

> ### Nota sobre actualización y seguridad
>
> Tu código es inseguro al usar la extensión `mysql_` con la cual no se
>   puede implementar consultas preparadas. Es una extensión antigua,
>   declarada obsoleta hace ya años y que de hecho fue sacada del núcleo
>   de PHP a partir de la versión 7. Todo tu código no funcionará si algún
>   día actualizas tu PHP a la versión 7 o superior. Si es posible
>   considera migrar el código a la nueva API `mysqli` o  a PDO. Usando
>   además consultas preparadas para casos como este.
>
> Para más detalles puedes consultar la pregunta:
>   [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)