# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\conexion.php:14

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un problema. No se por qué al registrar a un usuario me aparece error. Este es el código.

Lo que quiero es que se registre con el bóton enviar, ya que el *login* no me ha tomado el registro y aparece que no existe el usuario.

```
 <?php
    include ("configuracion.php");
    $conexion = new mysqli ($server,$user,$pass,$bd);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

        echo "no conectado",  mysqli_connect_error();
        exit ();
    }

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) { 
    if($_POST['usuario'] == '' or $_POST['password'] == '' or $_POST['repassword'] == '') { 
        echo 'Por favor llene todos los campos.'; 
    } else { 
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios'; 
        $rec = mysql_query($sql); 
        $verificar_usuario = 0; 
        while($result = mysql_fetch_object($rec)) { 
            if($result->usuario == $_POST['usuario']) { 
                $verificar_usuario = 1; 
            } 
        } 
        if($verificar_usuario) { 
            if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['repassword']) { 
                $usuario = $_POST['usuario']; 
                $password = $_POST['password']; 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password')"; 
                mysql_query($sql); 
                echo 'Usted se ha registrado correctamente.'; 
            } else { 
                echo 'Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente.'; 
            } 
        } else {
            echo 'Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.'; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Estas usando una conexión inicializada con el driver mysqli pero luego tratas de usar las funciones de mysql (que por cierto estan obsoletas), todas tus consultas deben usar mysqli_*

Comment: ya las reemplaze pero no lo conecta aun

Comment: Agrega con las correcciones hechas el nuevo error si es que hay uno nuevo

Comment: include ("configuracion.php");
$conexion = new mysql ($server,$user,$pass,$bd);


if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) { 
    if($_POST['usuario'] == '' or $_POST['password'] == '' or $_POST['repassword'] == '') { 
        echo 'Por favor llene todos los campos.'; 
    } else { 
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';

Comment: $rec = mysql_query($sql); 
        $verificar_usuario = 0; 
        while($result = mysql_fetch_object($rec)) { 
            if($result->usuario == $_POST['usuario']) { 
                $verificar_usuario = 1; 
            } 
        } 
        if($verificar_usuario) { 
            if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['repassword']) {

Comment: $usuario = $_POST['usuario']; 
                $password = $_POST['password']; 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password')"; 
                mysql_query($sql); 
                echo 'Usted se ha registrado correctamente.'; 
            } else { 
                echo 'Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente.'; 
            } 
        } else {
            echo 'Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.'; 
        }

Comment: verifica tu archivo php.ini y que tienes descomentada la siguiente linea ;extension=php_mysqli.dll, saludos

Comment: @KenThompson no lo mandes a modificar la configuración. En su código hay **una mezcla de la API `mysqli_` y de la API `mysql_`**, [ésta última es obsoleta y no existe en el núcleo de PHP 7+](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967). Si su versión de PHP es la 7 tendrá el error *`Call to undefined function mysql_query() `*  porque ya esas funciones no existen en PHP 7+.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un código que mezcla la API `mysqli_` con la API `mysql_`, esta última declarada obsoleta.

La lógica también es confusa y poco óptima (como podrás verificar en comentarios del código).

Te aporto esta respuesta para ayudar a corregir todas esas anomalías. Considera prestar atención a los comentarios e implementar un estilo de programación controlado y claro, de modo que te sea más fácil seguir las eventualidades, depurar errores, etc.

He puesto varios comentarios para que sea más fácil de entender. Si tienes dudas lo puedes decir en comentarios.

```
<?php
    /*
        Usamos un orden lógico:
        sin esta condición no haría falta la conexión
        por eso incluimos todo lo propio si se cumple este if
    */
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        include ("configuracion.php");
        $conexion = new mysqli ($server,$user,$pass,$bd);
        /*
            Aunque el Manual de PHP lo pone como ejemplo
            no conviene mostrar mensajes internos de la base de datos
            es mejor verificar la conexión y mostrar un mensaje personalizado
            Con if (!$conexion) preguntamos "si no se pudo conectar"
        */
        if (!$conexion) {
            /*
                Usaremos una variable que recoja lo que haya ocurrido
                y al final imprimimos esa variable
            */
            $msg="Conexión imposible. Revise las credenciales de conexión";    
        } else {
            /*
                Vamos a optar por un poco de claridad:
                mediante operadores ternarios verificaremos los datos del POST
                y al mismo tiempo los guardaremos en variables
                luego usaremos esas variables
            */
            $usuario=!empty($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
            $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;
            $repassword=!empty($_POST['repassword']) ? $_POST['repassword'] : NULL;
            /*
                Intentas insertar una variable $nombre 
                que no parece estar declarada
                imagino que está en el POST, por eso la defino aquí
                Considera si esta variable es también condición o no para el if
                que verifica si los datos fueron llenados
            */
            $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;

            if($usuario && $password && $repassword && $nombre) { 
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
                /*
                    Usaremos el estilo orientado a objetos de mysqli
                    que es el que usaste para crear la conexión
                    Además es un estilo más claro que el procedural
                    Puedes revisar las diferencias en el Manual de PHP
                */ 
                $rec = $conexion->query($sql); 
                /*
                    Es mejor usar un booleano directamente
                */
                $verificar_usuario = FALSE;
                /*
                     No es correcta la lógica que estás siguiendo,
                     porque obtienes todos los usuarios para luego ver si
                     alguno de ellos es igual a $_POST['usuario']
                     sería mejor hacer una consulta del tipo
                     SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = $_POST['usuario']
                     Dado que esto implicaría aplicar consultas preparadas y demás
                     te lo pongo en este comentario para que consideres modificar tu lógica
                     Uno de los problemas aquí es que si hay un millón de usuarios
                     tu consulta traería ese millón de usuarios a memoria
                     para luego buscar entre ese millón si está el usuario buscado
                     cuando lo puedes traer sólo a él con un WHERE ....
                */
                 while($result = $rec->fetch_object()) { 
                    if($result->usuario == $usuario) { 
                        $verificar_usuario = TRUE; 
                        /*
                             En caso de seguir con esta lógica, lo cual es ilógico
                             habría que salir del bucle con break cuando la condición se cumpla
                             sino seguirá leyendo las otras filas sin necesidad
                        */
                            break; 
                    }
                } 
            /*
                Esto también es un poco raro ...
                las claves en PHP deberían verificarse de otro modo, 
                pero ese es otro capítulo
            */
                 if($verificar_usuario) { 
                    if($password == $repassword) { 
                        /*
                            NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD: Esta consulta
                            es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL
                            considera informarte sobre el tema y usar consultas preparadas
                        */
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES
                                    ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password')";
                        /*
                            Verificamos si la consulta es exitosa
                            y si el número de filas afectadas es mayor que 0
                            condición que verifica una inserción real
                        */
                            if ($conexion->query($sql) && $conexion->affected_rows > 0) {
                            $msg="Usted se ha registrado correctamente.";
                        } else {
                            $msg="Error en la inserción";
                        }
                    } else { 
                        $msg="Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente."; 
                    } 
                } else {
                    /* 
                        No se entiende mucho esta parte de la lógica ¿?
                    */
                    $msg="Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente."; 
                } 

            } else {
                $msg="Por favor llene todos los campos. Faltan datos en el POST";
            }
        }

    } else {
        $msg="No hay POST enviar";  
    }
    /*
        Al final imprimimos $msg
    */
    echo $msg;
```

Comment: gracias e me ayudaste la mayor parte creo que esta invertido por que cuando hice dos ejemplos me dejo guardar uno repetido y otro nuevo me dice ya registrado

Comment: @robertomendoza traté de ayudarte en muchos aspectos que son fundamentales como el estilo de programación (que sea claro y controlado), así como en la mezcla de APIs que estabas usando: `mysql_` por un lado y `mysqli_` por otro lado. En cuanto a la lógica te puse comentarios en algunos puntos dudosos. Te recomendaría primero que trates de aprender cómo usar `mysqli` de forma correcta y que luego armes un programa con una lógica clara, porque la que sigues en tu código es demasiado confusa. Además el código no está optimizado (deberías filtrar con  `WHERE`) ...

Comment: ... y la parte de comprobar en segundo término una contraseña tampoco termino de entenderla. Repito: aprende primero cómo usar `mysqli` y luego céntrate en una lógica clara. Si en esa segunda etapa tienes dudas plantéalas aquí en otra pregunta y te ayudaremos. Si tienes dudas sobre `mysqli` también te ayudaremos. Otro consejo: usas tutoriales modernos, tu código parece inspirado en un tutorial del siglo pasado, hay muchos en la red que enseñan malas prácticas, como en este caso.

Comment: si lo vi en udemy ya que un cliente me pidio un login y registro de usuario

Comment: @robertomendoza en PHP se suele usar `password_verify` para verificar claves. Eso implica que la clave se guarda hasheada en la base de datos. Si es código para distribuir a alguien tienes que implementar muchas mejoras porque el código es pobre e inseguro tal y como lo tienes ahora. Una clave sin hashear puede ser capturada por hackers y hacer estragos en el sistema del cliente. Lo mismo ocurre con tu actual consulta `INSERT INTO`, es un grave agujero de seguridad, deberías usar consultas preparadas.