# Problema al conectar con PHP 7

Tags: php7

Tengo un archivo dbcon.php el cual me hace la conexión a la base de datos y otros de sesión... por más que intento adaptar el código a php 7 no me hace la conexión y se vuelve a index.php. El tipo de conexión que hago es PDO.

**dbcon.php**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contr", "bbdd");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

**login.php**

```
include('dbcon.php');
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= "'.$username.'" && password= "'.$password.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
        echo 'true';
        //echo 'true';

    }
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: Asi como duda, no tendrás guardada la contraseña como texto plano, ¿no? deberia de estar cifrada y si haces una comprobacion asi, no te la va encontrar ningun valor

Comment: Estás mezclando `mysqli` y `PDO`. Acabo de crear [una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336826/29967) en la pregunta sobre la API obsoleta, revísala, porque creo que te puede ayudar a aclarar conceptos y a decidirte por una u otra API.

Comment: No lo consigo... no sé lo que hago mal pero he visto la respuesta de @A.Cedano y me da fallo en la conexión

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el nuevo código indicando el tipo y estilo de conexión por el que optaste. Partiendo de ahí te podremos ayudar.

Comment: @A.Cedano editado... PDO.

Comment: Si has optado por PDO no tiene sentido tener funciones de `mysqli` en el archivo `dbcon.php` y en los otros archivos tampoco, tienes que escribir las consultas para PDO. Son dos cosas distintas.

Comment: El tema es que con ese código no conecto teniendo PHP 7... tengo que pasar a 5.6 para que me haga la conexión. No sé si me convendría pasar a funciones mysqli

Comment: Parece que no nos estamos entendiendo. Con PHP 7 puedes usar tanto PDO como mysqli. Si te decides por PDO tienes que quitar todo lo que refiera a mysqli  y escribir consultas con el estilo PDO. Si te decides por mysqli, tienes que quitar la conexión a PDO.

Comment: Pues me pierdo un poco con esto. Te explico, esto es una academia de alumnos y profesores... el tema es que últimamente la aplicación va bastante lenta (hace unas semanas iba bien) y los proveedores de hosting nos han comentado que es debido a la versión de php que tenemos instalada. Creo que podría adaptarla pero los conocimientos que tengo de php no llegan más allá de la 5.6... me gustaría poco a poco ir adaptando dicha aplicación a la versión 7 para ver si se soluciona el tema de la lentitud.

Comment: El tema de la lentitud depende de muchos factores. PHP 7 es mucho mejor, claro que sí. Pero si por ejemplo tu base de datos no está bien indexada y es grande, aunque pases a PHP 7 seguirá siendo lento. Lo mismo si tu código no está optimizado, si es redundante, si trae datos de sobra en la consultas, etc... O sea, hacer que algo vaya rápido a veces no se resuelve sólo con cambiar de versión de software. Sea como sea, di si te decimos por PDO o por mysqli y podemos ayudarte con el resto del código en este problema concreto. Por cualquiera que te decidas debes aprender cómo funciona.

Comment: Me estoy fijando en el navegador y se queda bastante tiempo en "Conectando..." hasta que carga la página.

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes toda la razón, Sea como sea debo de aprenderlo. me decanto por mysqli. miraré también la manera de hacerlo por PDO mas que nada por aprender.

Comment: Solucionado. He editado la pregunta con lo que me funciona... Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo!!