# ¿Como se hace un login?

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas me gustaria loguearme con ususarios que he creado previamente en una basew de datos , el problema es que al ingresar usuario y contraseña no me carga ninguno de los usuarios que he creado. Este es el codigo que llevo hasta el momento

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "datos";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    
    session_start();
     
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
     
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
     
        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM datos WHERE usuario=:username");
        $query->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
     
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     
        if (!$result) {
            echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
        } else {
            if (password_verify($password, $result['PASSWORD'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['ID'];
                echo '<p class="success">Congratulations, you are logged in!</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que no funciona, solo dices que no funciona.

Comment: La he editado mira a ver si ahora esta mejor explicado

Comment: Si no te trae usuarios la query, es por que o username no existe, o password no existe. Estas rescatando bien los parametros ? Como estas guardando el user y la password ?

Comment: Tienes una base de datos llamada datos y una tabla para los usuarios llamada datos?, cuando haces la consulta solo estas validando si un usuario existe dentro de la tabla datos, verificaste que esta bien colocado el nombre?

Comment: Lo más grave ahora mismo en tu código es que **estás mezclando código basado en la API `mysqli` y código basado en `PDO`**. Son dos cosas distintas, lo primero es que decidas en base a cuál de los dos vas a programar. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336826/29967) donde se explican algunos aspectos tanto de `mysqli` como de PDO.