# Inicio se de sesión en php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

buen día, tuve un problema de seguridad con una aplicación que se entrego con el usuario root sin contraseña y ahora me encuentro en la asignación de usuario para esta conexión. ya cree el respectivo usuario con sus permisos en mysql, ahora estoy configurando los archivos confing.php y session_init.php, pero me arroja error, agradezco cualquier comentario o ayuda para poder hacer esta modificación, gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código config.php

```
<?php

class Connection{
    
    //variables para los datos de la base de datos
    public $server;
    public $userdb;
    public $passdb;
    public $dbname;
    
    public function __construct(){
        
        //Iniciar las variables con los datos de la base de datos
        $this->server = 'localhost';
        $this->userdb = 'siat';
        $this->passdb = 'EusebioSi4t*';
        $this->dbname = 'doneusebio';
        
    }
    
    public function get_connected(){
        
        //Para conectarnos a MySQL
        $con = mysql_connect($this->server, $this->userdb, $this->passdb);
        //Nos conectamos a la base de datos que vamos a usar
        mysql_select_db($this->dbname, $con);
        
    }
    
}

?>
```

Código session_init.php

```
<?php

//llamado a la clase que hace la conexión a la base de datos
require'class/config.php';
//LLamado a la clase Usuarios para realizar el inicio de sesion
require'class/users.php';
//llamado a la clase que ejecutará los queries de Consulta, Adición y Eliminación
require'class/dbactions.php';
//llamado a la clase encargada de las sesiones
require'class/sessions.php';

//creación o instanciamiento de un objeto de la Clase Connection
$objConn = new Connection();
//objeto de la clase users
$objUser = new Users();

//llamamos la función que nos conecta a la base de datos
$objConn->get_connected();
//function que realiza la verificación de usuarios e inicio de sesion
$objUser->login_in();
?>
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\siat\class\config.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\siat\session_init.php(18): Connection->get_connected() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\siat\class\config.php on line 24

Comment: La librería `mysql` es obsoleta y ya no existen funciones `mysql_*()`. Debes migrar a [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli) o, mejor aún, a [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo)

Comment: Hora de actualizarse en PHP. En cada versión de PHP van agregando y removiendo cosas. `mysql_*` fue obsoleta en php 5.5 y removida en PHP 7.0 y ya vamos por PHP 8. [Por qué no se debe usar mysql_*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/80870)