# ¿Mysqli_connect esta obsoleto en php 8 para conectarse a la base de datos?

Tags: php

¿la funcion mysqli_connect no se puede usar en php 8 por que esta obsoleto? ¿Alguna otra funcion para conectar a la base de datos y que sea compatible con php 8?

Comment: Y yo diría que desde antes. Ya no es recomendable usar ese tipo de funciones. Usa PDO.

Comment: Hola, tienes varias preguntas cerradas por la comunidad por favor revisa [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 4):

La pregunta es interesante. La cito permitiéndome poner algunas negritas:

> ¿la **funcion** mysqli_connect **no se puede usar** en php 8 **por que
> esta obsoleto**? ¿Alguna otra **funcion** para conectar a la base de
> datos y que sea compatible con php 8?

En primer lugar, sí, `mysqli_connect()` pertenece a una [lista de *alias y funciones obsoletos*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.mysqli.php):

- mysqli_connect — Alias de mysqli::__construct
- mysqli_escape_string — Alias de mysqli_real_escape_string
- mysqli_execute — Alias para mysqli_stmt_execute
- mysqli_get_client_stats — Returns client per-process statistics
- mysqli_get_links_stats — Devolver información sobre enlaces abiertos y almacenados en caché
- mysqli_report — Alias de mysqli_driver->report_mode
- mysqli::set_opt — Alias de mysqli_options

<s>El Manual no explica a partir de qué versión de PHP `mysqli_connect`  es obsoleto</s>. [Esta nota de obsolescencia viene indicada ¡desde PHP 5!](https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php5/en/ref.mysqli)

### Algunas precisiones, para que no haya confusiones

- Realmente `mysqli_connect()` es un alias de [`mysqli::__construct`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php), el constructor de la clase `mysqli`, **lo que está obsoleto es el alias, no mysqli en sí misma que sigue siendo totalmente vigente**. De hecho, hoy día, si vas a usar `mysqli` se recomienda usar el estilo orientado a objetos. Por tanto, podrías usar [`new mysqli()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) para conectar. Y usa también el mismo estilo para todos los métodos y propiedades de la clase.
- Hay una anterior a `mysqli`, que es `mysql_` (sin la `i`). Esta API fue sacada del núcleo de PHP desde la versión 7 y ninguna de sus funciones se pueden usar desde dicha versión (para más detalles sobre esto puedes consulta la pregunta: *[¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql_* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)*).

Dicho eso, en teoría `mysqli_connect()` sí se puede usar en PHP 8, aunque esté obsoleta. Ahora bien, ¿conviene usarla? Cuando algo se declara **obsoleto** en programación significa que eso ha sido mejorado (porque tenía errores, problemas de rendimiento o por lo que sea) y que en la medida de lo posible **el código debería ser actualizado**.

Además, por lo general, algo **obsoleto** termina desapareciendo en futuras versiones del lenguaje, por lo que **algo que hoy es obsoleto mañana podría terminar siendo un error**. Un ejemplo es el controlador `mysql_` que fue declarado obsoleto en PHP 5 y fue sacado del núcleo en PHP 7. Hoy día todos los programas que usan `mysql_` terminan en un error faltal si se ejecutan en PHP 7+, así que todos los códigos que no se actualizaron en **esos años** transcurridos en PHP 5 y PHP 7 actualmente podrían ser programas erróneos.

Podríamos decir entonces que `mysqli_connect()` sí se puede usar en PHP 8, pero **no se debería usar**. No hay nada que justifique su uso, porque migrar el código es sumamente fácil.

Otra cosa: al citar la pregunta yo he puesto en negritas la palabra **función**, que es usada **dos veces**. Conviene olvidar el término *función* para el caso que nos ocupa (APIs de conexión a la base de datos), porque PHP está optando por el estilo **orientado a objetos**, que es distinto del estilo procedural. Ahora [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php) (y `PDO`) son **Clases** y para conectar se crean **instancias** de esas clases con los constructores de las mismas (de hecho `mysqli_connect()` es sólo un alias del constructor de la clase `mysqli`).

Así, `mysqli_connect()` no es en sí misma una *funcion* (aunque lo parezca) y en términos de programación orientada a objetos se habla de métodos y de constructores, el término *función* no se usa. Puede parecer una tontería, pero los términos son importantes para ayudarnos a cambiar el *chip* y escribir un código que sea coherente, también desde el punto de vista sintáctico.

¿Quieres evitar errores en el futuro? Migra tu código ahora y con respecto a `mysqli`, usa en todo el estilo orientado a objetos. Además, tendrás un código más claro, menos verboso y menos propenso a errores.

Comment: Excelente aporte, sobre todo la parte final de las presiciones ayudan mucho +1

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect es obsoleta desde la versión 5.5.0 y fue totalmente eliminada desde la versión 7.0.0. Puedes usar [Mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) Aunque recomendaría usar [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo)

Comment: El OP está hablando acerca de `mysqli` no sobre `mysql`