# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo el código

```
<?php
function conectarDB() {
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'bienes_raices');

    if($db) {
        echo 'conexión exitosa';
    } else {
        echo 'Error en la conexión a la base de datos';
    } } ?>
```

Pero en la salida del navegador me arroja el error
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bienesraices\includes\config\database.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bienesraices\admin\propiedades\crear.php(67): conectarDB() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bienesraices\includes\config\database.php on line 4**

He probado con Laragon también y me sigue arrojando el mismo error, agradecería que alguien me ayudara, he verificado incluso por consola, y la base de datos se encuentra cread de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

ya tienes corriendo SQL en Xampp?.
Revisa que mysqli este habilitado en PHP.
Puedes crear un archivo .php y agregas.

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Luego busca con "Ctrl+F" mysqi.

Creo que estas trabajando con Xampp.
Debes revisar tu archivo php.ini, lo puedes abrir desde Xampp en el botón config de Apache -> PHP (php.ini), luego buscar esta linea

extension=mysqli

Ojo, no debe tener ; "comentario", si es así remuévelo y reinicia Apache.

Cuando PHP te indica que una función es desconocida, es porque no la encuentra en sus librerías, por lo tanto no bedería ser el servicio MySQL, recuerda que una cosa es el modulo encargado de hacer correr "funcionar" PHP y otro es MySQL, totalmente diferentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo esta parte: *corriendo SQL*, ¿a qué te refieres?, tal vez le querías mencionar si verificó que la extensión mysqli esté habilitada

Comment: Tal como me lo indicaste cree el  archivo, y al validar mysqli, solamente me mostró el nombre de los autores del módulo, supongo que no está instalado en mi máquina; sin embargo no he encontrado información en la web que me permita hacer la instalación en windows 10.

Comment: Continúa igual... El error que me arroja por el getMessage() es que no se pudo encontrar el controlador

Answer (score 0):

Decidí no usar más Xampp... y en Laragón el problema era el mismo.

Encontré un problema con la carpeta que agregamos para la instalación de php desde https://www.php.net/downloads.php

Hay un archivo que configura toda la conexión llamada **php.ini**, en muchos foros se habla de ella pero no se mencionó que **en la descarga de la carpeta de php, este archivo hace falta**, y es sumamente importante para que pueda detectar los controladores de mysqli_connect() y PDO, así que dado que el archivo se puede visualizar en Laragon, pero no está en la carpeta de php, lo que hice ir a **Menú > PHP > php.ini en Laragon y abrirlo con el editor de texto**, revisé las líneas que comentaban con ; mysqli_connect() y PDO y estaban correctamente, por lo que fui al **administrador de archivos > C > Archivos de programa > php y busqué el archivo php.ini y NO ESTABA**, por lo que para darle el formato .ini correspondiente, lo que hice fue **copiar y pegar otro archivo dentro de la carpeta que tuviera la misma extensión, lo abrí con el editor de texto (usé Notepad++) y borré todo el contenido de ese archivo copia, copié el código completo del php.ini de Laragon y lo pegué en el archivo copia, que llamé de la misma manera para evitar errores (php.ini).**

*Después de Reiniciar Laragón la conexión fue exitosa.*

(Posible consecuencia)

Cabe mencionar que en medio del proceso, llegué a perder la base de datos, y debí volverla a crear, si en el navegador les aparece el error ERROR 1049 (42000), significa que la base de datos pudo ser borrada, pero en ese momento ya estará corriendo el servidor, será necesario volverla a crear, pero ya no se presentará el problema tan persistente de Error con Mysqli().

***Por mi parte ya no queda nada más que agregar, gracias por su apoyo comunidad.***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es extraño que hayas perdido la base de datos. ¿Revisaste directamente en el cliente de mysql? Tu problema era de configuración en PHP, lo cual no tiene nada que ver con la base de datos, simplemente PHP no estaba instalando el controlador que te permite interactuar con la base de datos, pero **ese controlador no es la base de datos**. Por poner un ejemplo, tú puedes conectar a la misma BD directamente, desde PHP, desde Java o desde otro lenguaje teniendo los controladores adecuados para cada uno, pero la BD es algo indepediente de ellos. Otra cosa, casi todas las funciones del controlador ...

Comment: ... mysqli son obsoletas. Te recomiendo que uses el estilo orientado a objetos. Lo digo porque en un futuro muchas de estas funciones podrían ser sacadas del núcleo de PHP y tu código empezará a fallar de nuevo con *`Undefined function`* [Ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/436317/29967) para más detalles sobre las funciones obsoletas de mysqli.