# mysql_fetch_array o mysqli_fetch_array no devuelve ningún valor

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

buenas tardes espero se encuentren bien.
les escribo por un error con php esta vez; resulta que soy nuevo en el lenguaje y estoy probando algunas funciones para manipular mi base de datos, el inconveniente está en cuando intento obtener los valores de mi tabla, aquí mi código php:

```
<?php
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuarios", "glX3Uzqg3b5BkkUq", "adrian1");
echo 'hasta acá todo bien';

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
echo 'sigue todo bien';

while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
echo 'listo';        //este no se envia//

echo $fila['a'];
}

 mysqli_close($conexion);
 ?>
```

He intentado con la variación **msqli_fetch_array()**, aunque tengo entendida esta deshabilitada por  obsoleta. también intente con  **$query2 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");** pero no solo no me funciona, sino que ya tengo código php que corre perfectamente sin necesidad del **mysqli_query()** ademas que ahí no lanza el error así que bueno.
Espero puedan ayudarme y gracias por su atención.

Comment: Las que están obsoletas son precisamente las que pones en el código de tu pregunta, **las que no tienen la `i`... al final** ([ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75123/29967)). Y, para obtener el resultado de las consultas `SELECT`  **es obligatorio ejecutarlas antes** con `mysqli_query` o con `query` si usas el estilo orientado a objetos.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array quedo obsoleta en php 5.0.0 y eliminada en php 7.0.0 en su lugar debes usar [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) Te falta pasar la query a tu conexión, de la siguiente manera te funcionará:

```
<?php
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuarios", "glX3Uzqg3b5BkkUq", "adrian1");

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios`";
$result = mysqli_query ($conexion, $query2); //pasas la query a la conexion

 while ($fila =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $fila['nombre de la columna'];
    echo "<br>";
}

 mysqli_close($conexion);
 ?>
```

Puedes obtener el resultado indicando el nombre de la columna:

```
echo $fila['nombre de la columna'];
```

O indicando el la posición de la columna en el array:

```
echo $fila[0];
```